# O que é um pato de borracha (rubber duck) e para que serve?

Tags: terminologia

Existe uma expressão utilizada de vez em quando no meio da programação que diz respeito a trabalhar sobre código com um patinho de borracha.

Como o tal pato ajuda a desenvolver software de uma forma melhor?

<sub>Relacionado: [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/70)</sub>

Comment: Como eu não tenho um pato de borracha, eu falo com o pessoal do [chat] ***=)***

Comment: Para quem for responder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging (além do termo "Rubber duck" pesquisem também o termo "Teddy Bear"), não entendo muito por isto não vou responder, mas fica a ajuda/referencias :)

Comment: Muitos programadores já tiveram a experiência de explicar um problema de programação para outra pessoa, possivelmente, até mesmo para alguém que não sabia nada sobre programação, e em seguida, encontrar com a solução no processo de explicar o problema.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>Patinho, patinho meu, existe código mais torto que o meu? Fonte: [Talk to the duck – debugging and resilience](https://mrcolley.com/2014/07/01/talk-to-the-duck-debugging-and-resilience/)</sup>

Apesar do nome estranho, **programação a pato de borracha** é uma técnica de engenharia de software que tenta eliminar a dissonância cognitiva entre a elaboração mental de um modelo de software e a solução para um problema.

A premissa é que, ao explicar para um agente externo (neste caso o pato de borracha) o seu problema, a organização necessária irá oferecer ao engenheiro pontos de vista usualmente não disponíveis apenas via modelo mental, auxiliando o processo de depuração.

Answer (score 14):

É um método de depuração de código, onde ao explicar como o código funciona a um terceiro qualquer incongruência entre o que o código deveria fazer e o que realmente faz ficaria mais aparente.

O termo faz referência a história de um livro `The Pragmatic Programmer` onde o programador explica linha por linha a um pato.

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210323/o-que-%C3%A9-um-pato-de-borracha-e-para-que-serve/210331#comment429931_210323)

Outra abordagem mais empírica pode ser o [método socrático](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method).