# O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?

Tags: algoritmo, testes, teste-de-mesa

É bastante comum lermos enquanto estudando algoritmos e lógica de programação que o Teste de Mesa é um meio de verificar o funcionamento de um algoritmo.

- O que é o Teste de Mesa?
- Como é possível aplicá-lo para fazer a verificação da lógica em um programa?
- Qual é o passo a passo para efetuar o Teste de Mesa?
- Existe um *software* que executa este teste?

Se possível, dê exemplos de como é feito a aplicação de um teste de mesa em um programa.

<sub>**Nota:** o objetivo da pergunta é criar um conteúdo objetivo e de qualidade sobre Teste de Mesa com a finalidade de auxiliar iniciantes a verificarem os erros em seus programas.</sub>

<sub>Postagens relacionadas:

[O que é um pato de borracha (rubber duck) e para que serve?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210323/70)

[Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/70)</sub>

Comment: Eu não costumo fazer teste de mesa na mão quando estou usando o VS, ele já me mostra tudo que esta na memória quando estou debugando. Se quer saber mais pode ver [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_table).

Comment: Teste de *tabela*?

Comment: @mari Que? Poderia detalhar melhor seu comentário?

Comment: Me parece que a tradução mais adequada para 'trace table' seria teste de tabela (de rastreamento), e não teste de mesa =)

Comment: @mari Não sei opinar sobre isso; o termo teste de mesa é o que eu conheço e vejo sendo altamente utilizado em português, nem foi questão de tradução. Nunca vi utilizarem "teste de tabela".

Comment: Eu entendo, mas veja pelo lado lógico: table é mesa e tb tabela. Você usa uma tabela no teste, mas não tem nada a ver com mesa. Logo... Pode ter sido uma tradução mal feita e ninguém  questionou e ficou assim,  tipo a estória dos macacos que não comem a banana e não sabem pq ;-)

Comment: Nos tempos de faculdade (1994), isso era conhecido como "chinês"! Teste de mesa = "fazer o chinês"!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**O que é o Teste de Mesa?**

O Teste de Mesa é um processo manual que é utilizado para validar a lógica de um determinado algoritmo. Ele é utilizado principalmente em algoritmos quando a linguagem utilizada não possui nenhuma ferramenta automatizada de depuração. Como as linguagens de programação costumam possuir tais ferramentas, é mais comum utilizá-las a fazer o teste de mesa propriamente dito, embora para quem ainda é iniciante, eu particularmente ainda recomendo utilizá-lo, visto que provavelmente não terá domínio sobre a ferramenta de depuração.

No livro [*Dicionário de Informática & Internet*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=pJAnIST_RY0C&pg=PA128&dq=teste%20de%20mesa&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=teste%20de%20mesa&f=false) há a definição:

> Teste de mesa: análise para saber se um programa funciona logicamente.

No livro [*Treinamento em Lógica de Programação*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GOAw0Lsdl-QC&pg=PA16&dq=teste%20de%20mesa&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=teste%20de%20mesa&f=false) há:

> Após o desenvolvimento de um algoritmo, é necessário verificar cada um dos passos que foram determinados, ou seja, efetuar um teste. Para isso, leia cada uma das instruções e anote o resultado de cada tarefa/passo, verificando possíveis erros ou outras formas de solucionar o problema. Este teste é mais conhecido como Teste de Mesa.

No livro [*Técnicas de Programação - Uma Abordagem Moderna*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=H8A0lZtqaXsC&pg=PA60&dq=teste%20de%20mesa&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=teste%20de%20mesa&f=false) há:

> Uma das ferramentas muito empregadas para verificar se um pseudocódigo (ou algoritmo de um modo geral) está sendo executado corretamente é o chamado Teste de Bancada (sinônimo de Teste de Mesa). Esse teste retrata fielmente o que o pseudocódigo está executando, passo a passo, mostrando ao programador as etapas previstas no algoritmo.

**Como é possível aplicá-lo para fazer a verificação da lógica em um programa?**

Não há uma forma canônica para a elaboração de um Teste de Mesa, pois dependerá muito do que pretende verificar no algoritmo e do seu nível de entendimento. No geral, você deverá criar no papel uma tabela com todas as variáveis do programa e executar passo a passo seu código, anotando sempre os valores das variáveis. Assim você será capaz de identificar se os valores condizem com o esperado ou localizar a exata linha de código onde o valor da variável passa a ficar errado.

O livro *Técnicas de Programação - Uma Abordagem Moderna* supracitado apresenta também um procedimento de quatro passos que descrevem a execução do Teste de Mesa:

1. Elaborar uma tabela onde cada coluna se refere a cada variável envolvida e o resultado de uma operação em particular (ou observação pertinente);
2. Executar os passos previstos no algoritmo;
3. Verificar se os resultados obtidos são coerentes com os previstos;
4. Encerrar o teste após um número razoável de resultados corretos obtidos;

Ou seja, identifique todas as variáveis do seu programa e verifique os valores das mesmas a cada linha de código executada.

**Qual é o passo a passo para efetuar o Teste de Mesa?**

Como dito, não há uma sequências de passos definitiva, mas as que eu costumo seguir e que sempre tiveram uma boa aceitação por iniciantes em programação é:

1. Identifique todas as variáveis no seu programa;
2. Crie uma tabela onde a primeira coluna se chama "Passo", a segunda de chama "Linha". A partir disto, crie uma coluna para cada variável do programa;
3. Na primeira linha da tabela, preencha a coluna "Passo" com "Início", pode deixar a coluna "Linha" em branco e preencha cada coluna das variáveis com os respectivos valores iniciais;
4. Percorra seu código linha a linha, preenchendo a tabela. A coluna "Passo" deverá ser incrementada a cada nova linha na tabela; a coluna "Linha" deve indicar o número da linha no código que está sendo analisada e em cada coluna das variáveis deve constar o respectivo valor para cada variável após a linha de código ser executada;
5. Execute o passo 4 até o programa finalizar;

Por exemplo, vamos considerar um programa que praticamente todos os iniciantes fazem no início dos estudos: cálculo do fatorial. Um algoritmo para pseudocódigo de cálculo do fatorial é:

```
 1    numero <- 0;
 2    resultado <- 1;
 3
 4    leia(numero);
 5
 6    se (numero < 0) então
 7        imprima("O número não pode ser negativo");
 8    senão
 9        enquanto (numero > 0) faça
10            resultado <- resultado * numero;
11            numero <- numero - 1;
12        fim
13
14        imprima("O fatorial de vale", resultado);
15    fim
```

**Passo 1**: Identificar todas as variáveis do programa;

As variáveis do programa são `numero`, que receberá o valor do qual desejamos calcular o fatorial, e `resultado`, que armazenará o resultado do cálculo.

**Passo 2**: Criar a tabela;

Lembrando que a primeira coluna se chama "Passo", a segunda "Linha" e as outras representam as variáveis do programa.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|           |           |            |               |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

**Passo 3**: Preencher a primeira linha da tabela;

Na coluna "Passo" coloque "Início", na coluna "Linha" não precisa valor e nas colunas das variáveis os valores iniciais de cada.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

**Passo 4**: percorrer cada linha do programa, preenchendo a tabela;

As linhas de definição das variáveis já foram consideradas no passo 3, quando já preenchemos a tabela com os valores iniciais. Portanto, começamos analisar o programa a partir da linha 4. Vamos supor que desejamos calcular o fatorial de 3, portanto, quando a função `leia(numero)` solicitar ao usuário um número, ele entrará com o valor 3, sendo armazenado na variável `numero`. A variável `resultado` não varia, então mantemos o seu valor.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Na linha 6 é verificado se o valor entrado pelo usuário é menor do que zero. Como 3 é maior que zero, a condição é falsa e, assim, pulamos para a linha 8. Na linha 9, criamos um laço de repetição que durará enquanto o valor de `numero` for maior que zero. Neste momento o valor é 3 (veja a tabela acima), então devemos executar o laço, partindo para a linha 10. Nesta linha, o valor de `resultado` é atualizado para o valor `resultado * numero`, ou seja, o novo valor de `resultado` será o valor atual multiplicado pelo valor de `numero`. Então:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Naturalmente passamos para a linha 11, onde o valor de `numero` passa a ser o seu valor atual decrementado em uma unidade, então:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     3     |    11     | 3 - 1 = 2  |       3       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Terminado o código dentro do laço de repetição devemos voltar a linha 9 e verificar novamente a condição para determinar se o laço de repetição deve continuar ou não. Neste momento, `numero` vale 2 e, portanto, ainda é maior que 0, então partimos para a linha 10 novamente. O valor de `resultado` será o atual multiplicado pelo valor de `numero`, então:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     3     |    11     | 3 - 1 = 2  |       3       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     4     |    10     |     2      |   3 * 2 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Na linha 11, novamente o valor de `numero` receberá o valor atual decrementado em uma unidade, então:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     3     |    11     | 3 - 1 = 2  |       3       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     4     |    10     |     2      |   3 * 2 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     5     |    11     | 2 - 1 = 1  |       6       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Voltamos para a linha 9, analisando novamente a condição do laço. Como 1 ainda é maior que zero, então passamos para a linha 10, onde novamente o valor de `resultado` será modificado:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     3     |    11     | 3 - 1 = 2  |       3       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     4     |    10     |     2      |   3 * 2 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     5     |    11     | 2 - 1 = 1  |       6       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     6     |    10     |     1      |   6 * 1 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

E na linha 11 o valor de `numero` será atualizado:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Passo   |   Linha   |   numero   |   resultado   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   Início  |     -     |     0      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     1     |     4     |     3      |       1       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     2     |    10     |     3      |   1 * 3 = 3   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     3     |    11     | 3 - 1 = 2  |       3       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     4     |    10     |     2      |   3 * 2 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     5     |    11     | 2 - 1 = 1  |       6       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     6     |    10     |     1      |   6 * 1 = 6   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|     7     |    11     | 1 - 1 = 0  |       6       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Após, voltamos a linha 9 para verificar novamente a condição do laço, mas agora o valor de `numero` é 0 e não satisfaz a condição de ser maior que zero, portanto passamos para a linha 14, onde é exibida a mensagem "O fatorial vale 6", pois o valor atual de `resultado` é 6.

Embora o Teste de Mesa seja muito utilizado para testar laços de repetição ele não é limitado apenas a isso. Qualquer algoritmo pode ser testado utilizando o Teste de Mesa. Por exemplo, na pergunta [Como fazer Teste de Mesa para determinado algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136393/5878) é apresentado um exemplo de Teste de Mesa em um algoritmo simples, com apenas operações matemáticas. Na pergunta [Funções Recursivas em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202514/5878) eu respondi sobre como funciona a recursividade no cálculo de fatorial utilizando Teste de Mesa. Já na pergunta [Recursividade em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209187/5878) eu expliquei como funciona a recursividade para o cálculo da série de Fibonacci também utilizando Teste de Mesa.

**Existe um software que executa este teste?**

Não conheço algum que tenha tal propósito. Como comentei no início da resposta, se estiver utilizando alguma linguagem de programação é bem provável que exista alguma ferramenta de depuração (*debug*) que faça tal serviço para você. O Teste de Mesa basicamente tem esse nome porque demandará você ter papel, caneta e uma mesa para efetuá-lo. Com certeza efetuar o Teste de Mesa demanda muita disposição, mas, principalmente para quem está iniciando, vale muito a pena. Muitos dos erros de lógica (idealmente todos) no código podem ser identificados ao efetuar o Teste de Mesa.

Answer (score 23):

Existem basicamente duas formas de fazer verificação se um algoritmo está fazendo o que se espera. Um deles é o [método formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) onde se "prova" matematicamente que ele faz o que deseja.

Também existem os **métodos informais**, onde se faz algum tipo de inspeção para verificar se um código está correto. Uma destas verificações é o teste de mesa ou [*desk checking*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/18825/desk-check) como é chamado em inglês. Ele é tão informal que não se acha informações acadêmicas ou literatura confiável que fale sobre ele. É quase uma lenda urbana que se passa à frente, embora ele seja real.

Teve época que ele foi muito útil, hoje menos porque os depuradores são sofisticados para fazer isso por você, dá para ir acompanhando a execução de forma intuitiva, automática e sem riscos de se perder no que está fazendo, afinal humanos perdem a atenção fácil em tarefas enfadonhas como esta. Não é que usar um *debugger* seja o teste de mesa, mas ele é substituído pelo mecanismo computadorizado existente em todo IDE ou mesmo em linha de comando.

O teste de mesa não deixa de ser um processo de [*debuging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging).

Hoje eu considero ele um método de aprendizado mais do que algo para se usar no dia a dia. Acho que todo desenvolver deveria fazer testes de mesa para entender o que acontece no código até dominar o funcionamento da execução.

Em geral usamos uma [*trace table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_table) ou tabela de rastreamento para acompanhar os estados do algoritmo que vão se modificando. Estado é um enorme problema na computação e sua mutação sempre causa efeitos na aplicação. Quase todos os problemas são causados por mudança de estado equivocada, mesmo que o motivo de fazer errado seja um fluxo errado.

Muitas vezes controla-se também o que é executado, o que não deixa de ser uma mudança de estado, mesmo que não esteja em variáveis. Não é apenas sobre mudança de valores em variáveis.

Dá pra fazer no Excel, embora seja mais fácil se estiver um outra máquina ou monitor. Ou pode usá-lo só pra montar as tabelas. Mas é comum fazer em papel em branco, talvez pelo menos com linhas. Exemplos:

[image: Teste de mesa]

Esta é uma forma em mostra que linha está sendo executada. Outras focam só na mudança do estado.

É possível fazer até com SQL:

[image: Teste de mesa em SQL]

## Minha técnica

A técnica exata de se fazer depende da pessoa, não tem regra. Eu já respondi sobre o processo que eu uso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/136396/101):

Crio uma tabela com as variáveis declaradas, cada uma em uma coluna. Cada linha da coluna servirá para anotar o novo valor da variável sempre que houver uma nova atribuição. Algumas pessoas gostam de riscar o valor anterior para evitar confusão e só deixar visível o última mesmo, que é o que vale.

Também é possível ter colunas para sub-expressões, o que pode ajudar achar erros nelas.

Então à partir da terceira linha começo a anotação ma coluna de `n1`. Vou anotar um valor que desejo testar.

Em seguida anoto o resultado do cálculo do valor de `n1` (é sempre o último valor disponível na coluna) vezes 3.

Aí faço o mesmo pegando o último valor de `n1` menos 1 mais o último valor de `n2`.

Aí anoto em separado o que deve aparecer na tela (uma página só para demonstração de tela), no caso O resultado final será `n3=` e o último valor de n3.

Se fosse algo mais complexo continuaria. Se tivesse um laço iria mantendo as anotações.

Eu testaria com vários valores, com 0, positivo, negativo, alguns números altos, tentaria por um texto, em fim tentaria criar situações que provoquem erro no algoritmo.

Algumas pessoas gostam de colocar colunas para as sub-expressões também. É uma boa ideia.

Para fazer um teste de mesa fácil é importante o algoritmo não ser grande demais.

Em alguns casos pode haver algumas especificidades de como proceder.

Algumas pessoas gostam de criar uma linha de dados para cada linha ou sub-expressão executada copiando os dados anteriores. Eu acho exagero, mas pode ser útil em alguns casos. Só faço algo quando muda o estado.

## Complemento

Tem uma [videoaula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lNCLHzTVIE) no Youtube, por falta de opção melhor, ela ajuda entender. Tem outras sugeridas que pode acompanhar.

Tem [*slides* bem interessantes](https://www.slideshare.net/henriquecarmona/aula-4-teste-de-mesa) que mostram o processo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 21):

> O que é o Teste de Mesa?

O Teste de Mesa ou Trace Table como pode ser chamado. É uma técnica usada para testar algoritmos ou programas de computador, com o intuito de checar se há algum erro na logica durante a execução do algoritmo ou programa. Ele também simula o fluxo de execução de uma parte de um programa ou o programa todo. As declarações são executadas passo a passo, e os valores das variáveis mudam conforme a declaração é executada.

Esta técnica é tipicamente usada por programadores iniciantes, para ajuda-los a visualizar como um algoritmo ou programa em particular funciona. Programadores com mais experiência também pode usar o teste de mesa para detectar erros, embora as IDEs provê ótimos recursos para esta finalidade.

> Como é possível aplicá-lo para fazer a verificação da lógica em um programa?

Vamos considerar este programa em C#, veja:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x, y, z;

    x = 10;
    y = 15;
    z = x * y;
    z++;

    Console.WriteLine(z);            
}
```

Com base neste código, podemos construir uma tabela para checar a execução deste programa:

[image: tabela para teste de mesa]

É nesta tabela que é possível aplicar o teste de mesa para verificar a lógica do programa. É claro que a tabela pode ter mais colunas ou menos dependendo do código do programa.

> Qual é o passo a passo para efetuar o Teste de Mesa?

Com base na tabela que foi criada, basta preencher as colunas correspondente a cada passo do programa, desta forma será possível visualizar o fluxo de execução dele.

Veja a tabela preenchida:

[image: tabela preenchida para o teste de mesa]

Para cada passo de execução, colocamos a declaração correspondente seguido de um comentário a respeito da declaração, e por fim, o valor que foi atribuído a variável correspondente a declaração até o passo final que é a exibição do valor da variável `z` no console.

Desta forma, é possível visualizar o fluxo de execução do programa ou algoritmo, e esta técnica para quem esta iniciando no mundo da programação, é ótima. Devido aos erros que são cometidos com mais frequência por programadores iniciantes, fica mais fácil de identifica-los e corrigi-los com o Teste de Mesa.

> Existe um software que executa este teste?

Em C eu costumo usar um programa chamado [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (Data Display Debugger) para fazer o teste de mesa (ele não é como o teste de mesa tradicional, mas o objetivo é o mesmo). As IDEs provê ótimos recursos para esta finalidade também.

## Conclusão

É muito importante que iniciantes aprendam Teste de Mesa, e até programadores avançados pode utilizar de vez em quando, pois com ele, fica mais fácil de identificar os erros e ajuda a fixar melhor o que esta sendo aprendido. Pode até ser um pouco massante fazer o teste de mesa, dependendo do código, más, devido os resultados que serão adquiridos, compensa muito o esforço. Este é os primeiros passos para aprender a debugar um programa de computador ou algoritmo.

Fontes:
[What is a Trace table?](http://www.bouraspage.com/repository/algorithmic-thinking/what-is-a-trace-table)
[Trace table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_table)

Answer (score 7):

Teste de mesa é um teste de lógica de programação, é geralmente usado em sistemas de repetição, exemplo:

```
A=1;
B=10;
While(A!=B) {
  A++;
  B--;
}
```

Teste de Mesa:

```
1° Loop: Valor A inicial=1, Valor B inicial=10 Valor A final= 2, Valor B final=9    
2° Loop: Valor A inicial=2, Valor B inicial=9 Valor A final=3, Valor B final=8
3° Loop: Valor A inicial=3, Valor B Inicial=7 Valor A final=4, Valor B final=6
4° Loop: Valor A inicial= 4, Valor B inicial= 7 Valor A Final=5, Valor B final=5

FIM LOOP, A==B
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Teste de mesa da função *Reduce*.**

**Suponha o seguinte uso de reduce tenha ocorrido:**

```js
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(Acumulador, valorAtual, indice, array) {
  return Acumulador + valorAtual;
});
// 10
```

> O callback será invocado quatro vezes com os argumentos e retorna os
>   valores em cada chamada, como sendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**REFERÊNCIA:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Como_funciona_o_reduce()