# recursividade para encontrar numeros impares em uma lista python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como usar a recursividade em Python para fazer uma função que percorra todos os impares de uma lista e acrescente-os em uma nova lista

Testado o código obtive uma saída nula. Rodei o debugger e mesmo assim não encontrei o motivo. Ele parou na linha 14 (últma linha) e retornou nulo, abaixo do código está a saída

Meu código até o momento:

```
def encontra_impares(lista):
    lis = []
    if len(lista) == 1 and lista[0] % 2 == 0:
        if not lista[0] % 2 == 0:
            return lis
        return lista
    else:
        if lista[0] % 2 == 0:
            return lista[0] + encontra_impares(lista[1:])
```

Saída:

```
>>> encontra_impares([1,2,3])

[DEBUG ON]

>>>
```

Saída esperada:

```
>>> encontra_impares([1,2,3])


>>> '[1,3]'
```

Debugger:

```
>'_main_'.encontra_impares(), line 14 if lista[0] % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: E qual é o problema com o seu código? Você esqueceu de descrever isso na pergunta. Deu erro? Qual? Não deu erro mas não funciona? Como testou? Qual foi a entrada testada? Qual foi a saída? Qual deveria ser a saída?

Comment: eu havia testado, a saída é nula, ou seja não resulta em nada esse código

Comment: Exatamente. Edite a pergunta e adicione qual foi o teste que você fez explicando que a saída foi nula e coloque qual deveria ter sido a saída.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo o [Teste de Mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878):

```
def encontra_impares(lista):
    lis = []
    if len(lista) == 1 and lista[0] % 2 == 0:
        if not lista[0] % 2 == 0:
            return lis
        return lista
    else:
        if lista[0] % 2 == 0:
            return lista[0] + encontra_impares(lista[1:])

encontra_impares([1,2,3])
```

1. A função `encontra_impares` é chamada com `lista = [1, 2, 3]`;
2. Define-se uma variável local `lis = []`;
3. Verifica-se se o comprimento de `lista` é 1 e se o valor é par. O comprimento é 3, então executa o `else`;
4. Verifica se o valor na posição 0 é par. Não, pois na posição 0 está o 1, que é ímpar, então não é executado o `if`;
5. Fim do programa?

Agora entendeu por quê seu programa aparentemente travou e a saída é nula? Uma solução ao problema:

```
def encontra_impares(lista):

    # Define a lista que armazenará os números ímpares:
    lis = []

    # Verifica se há elementos na lista:
    if len(lista) > 0:

        # Retira o primeiro elemento da lista:
        numero = lista.pop(0)

        # Verifica se o número é ímpar:
        if numero % 2 != 0:

            # Sim, então adiciona-o à lista de ímpares:
            lis.append(numero)

        # Faz a união do resultado atual com o retorno para o resto da lista:
        lis = lis + encontra_impares(lista)

    # Retorna a lista final:
    return lis
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QazXix).

Comment: putz, eu esqueci do not. if not lista[0] % 2 == 0

Comment: obrigado amigo, agora faz sentido. Recursão é um tanto quanto dificil de se entender

Comment: @l.martini então leia sobre o teste de mesa e busque fazê-los em seus códigos. Ficará bem mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score 2):

```
def impares(l, i=0, lst_impares=[]):
    try:
        e = l[i] if l[i]%2!=0 else None
        i+=1
        if e:
            lst_impares.append(e)
        return impares(l,i,lst_impares) 
    except:
        return lst_impares

print(impares([1,2,3,4,5,19,10]))
[1, 3, 5, 19]
```

[Execute no repl.it](https://repl.it/J5nK/1)