# PHP Duvidas como otimizar o Session

Tags: php, html

Hoje utilizo o seguinte código para iniciar uma Sessão em PHP

```
 //verificação se o id de sessão ja existe, se não existir, cria
if (!session_id()){
   // iniciando a sessão
   session_start();   
   // buffer para evitar o erro ao acionar o headlocation
   ob_start();

}
```

Como sou novo em PHP, gostaria saber...
Preciso realizar configurações adicionais para evitar problemas de acesso futuro? ou seja, quero evitar que o site que desenvolvi fique sobrecarregado.

Também percebi que a sessão só é finalizada quando eu fecho o navegador, qual é o tempo de expiração da sessão do php e é necessário mudar isso?

Dicas?

Estou utilizando a versão 5.6

Comment: A sessão não é uma coisa que tem grande impacto sobre a performance do servidor, o que mexe com performance em larga escala que se não tomar cuidado dá problema é o uso do banco de dados e uso desenfreado sem necessidade e sem nenhum teste de mesa de loops.

Comment: então eu criei classes e pdo e foreach para os laços (Abro uma unica conexão) para obter as informações da pagina. Pelos testes que fiz tudo funciona normalmente, como faria esses testes de mesa que vc falou?

Comment: Veja como fazer teste de mesa [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-é-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplicá-lo/220505#220505)

Comment: Este código em si não tem problema, os problemas podem vir é na manipulação da sessão, no momento de adicionar valores e remover, o código acima só inicia a sessão e nada mais.

Comment: entendi, mas e na parte de requisições? toda vez que alguém acessar o site, haverá uma requisição correto? como eu sei o limite estipulado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem muito que fazer em relação a isso,

Mas tenta aplicar este pequeno *script* que vai guardar a ultima requisição, com tempo de espera, vai prevenir ataques **DDoS**

```
// vou assumir que ja tens a sessão iniciada...
$uri = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$exp = 3; // 3 segundos
$hash = $uri .'|'. time();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $hash;
}

list($_uri, $_exp) = explode('|', $_SESSION['user']);
if ($_uri == $uri && time() - $_exp < $exp) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
    die;
}

// guardar a ultima requisição
$_SESSION['user'] = $hash;
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica! coloquei logo depois do if do session start! abraços!

Comment: só um detalhe, se entendi bem esse código vai retornar "Serviço indisponível se o mesmo usuário tentar acessar mais de uma vez em um curto período de tempo correto?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Comment: fiquei com uma duvida, tenho esse código <meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='3.0;URL=produto.php'>   em alguns botões de excluir, como o script executa muito rápido acaba retornando o erro de 503 service Unavailabe, como resolver?