# Utilizando lower() em uma lista de listas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se eu tenho uma lista assim:

```
Lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR']]
```

e quero deixar ela assim:

```
Lista = [['de','do','ou'],['ae','yhh','oo'],['ow','la','for']]
```

como faço? pensei que se fizesse só isso conseguiria:

```
for sublist in Lista:
   for itens in sublist:
      itens.lower()
```

mas não deu certo...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usei o exemplo [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540718/how-to-convert-elements-in-a-list-of-list-to-lowercase) onde é usado [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR']]
[print([w.lower() for w in line]) for line in lista]
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6M5BBp)

Usando `list comprehension` você cria uma nova lista ou substitui a anterior:

```
lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR']]

lista_lower = [[w.lower() for w in line] for line in lista]
print(lista_lower)
```

> saída : `[['de', 'do', 'ou'], ['ae', 'yhh', 'oo'], ['ow', 'la', 'for']]`

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/2Nzf0Q)

Comment: A `list comprehension`que possui o `print()` não retorna a saída apresentada, e se for atribuída a uma variável de lista, sempre retorna `[ None, None, None ]`.

Comment: @Lacobus acei que tínhamos superado esse equívoco : https://ideone.com/2Nzf0Q , espero ao final disso ter conquistado seu +1, ficarei mto feliz, pois gosto das sua observações e abordagens.

Comment: Estou falando desse aqui: https://ideone.com/6M5BBp

Comment: Que que tem esse? @Lacobus

Comment: Não é a mesma saída que vc apresentou na sua resposta. Ambos possuem saídas diferentes.

Comment: Por exemplo: https://ideone.com/z8gt6k

Comment: Veja,  minha resposta contém 2 exemplos, na 1º a `list comprehension`, apresenta como resultada uma lista criada à partir de `lista`, entretanto o que está sendo impresso não é a nova lista criada e sim os itens, no 2º exemplo eu atribuo a nova lista criada sob o nome de `lista_lower` e então madno `lista_lower` para a saída... Para entender o resultado do teu exemplo (https://ideone.com/z8gt6k), é necessário realizar um teste de mesa : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo ... Tá no pique?

Comment: O que acontece é que `print()` retorna `None` sempre. Como a lista de entrada contém 3 listas aninhadas, `print()` é chamado 3 vezes, resultando em uma lista contendo 3 elementos `None`.

Comment: @Lacobus Qual exatamente o ponto em questão ao qual se refere? O que está querendo dizer? No exemplo em que uso o `print` ele retorna os valores desejados...Depois eu atribui a uma variável que poderia ser o mesmo nome da lista original... Minha resposta contém algum erro? Cara estou sendo paciente, para tentar compreendê-lo, mas de fato, você não está sendo compreensível...Qual parte da resposta não te agrada, como eu falei a 1º saída é o resultado do loop pois o `print` está no loop, para printar a lista você deve jogar o print fora do loop na lista...

Answer (score 9):

Uma forma de utilizar o **lower** neste lista de lista, é usar a função `map()` e passar uma expressão *lambda* para ela `lambda x:x.lower()`, que usara a função `lower()` para fazer o trabalho.

Entretanto, é necessário juntar as listas em uma lista só com a função `chain()` do módulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) e obtendo uma lista temporária com a função `list()`, e logo em seguida obter o retorno no formato de uma lista unica usando novamente a função `list()` para gerar sua nova lista. Caso contrário a função `map()` vai emitir um resultado inesperado.

Veja o código de exemplo:

```
import itertools

Lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR']]

novaLista = list(map(lambda x:x.lower(), list(itertools.chain(*Lista))))

print(novaLista)
```

Saída:

> `['de', 'do', 'ou', 'ae', 'yhh', 'oo', 'ow', 'la', 'for']`

Veja o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/MS12/0).

## Edição

Não foi especificado na pergunta que deseja manter a estrutura da lista. Se você deseja **manter a estrutura da lista**, basta fazer a interação em um `for` para obter as sub-listas e em seguida adicionar cada sub-lista na sua nova lista.

Veja como ficou:

```
Lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR']]

novaLista = []

for reg in Lista:
  novaLista.append(list(map(lambda x:x.lower(), reg)))

print(novaLista)
```

Saída:

> `[['de', 'do', 'ou'], ['ae', 'yhh', 'oo'], ['ow', 'la', 'for']]`

Não foi mais necessário utilizar o modulo *itertools* nesta nova versão do código.

Veja a nova versão funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/MUvm/0).

Leia mais:
[Convert a Python list with strings all to lowercase or uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801676/5429980)
[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/5429980)

Comment: Lembrando que a lista foi "achatada" durante a conversão e perdeu as dimensões originais.

Comment: Exatamente...  a estrutura de lista de listas foi perdida.

Comment: @WilliamHenrique você não deixou explicito na pergunta que desejaria manter a estrutura, pois o foco foi utilizar a função `lower()` para converter os caracteres. Depois edito a resposta e coloco na estrutura mencionada.

Comment: Há algo mais que eu possa fazer? Não compreendi o motivo do negativo.

Comment: @gato eu deixei explicito sim na pergunta...  olha la linha que diz SAIDA. O motivo do negativo eu já tirei.. devo ter clicado na seta de baixo e nem percebi! De qualquer modo agradeço ajuda!! toda ajuda é bem vinda! :)

Comment: Tudo bem @WilliamHenrique

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o pacote `NumPy` para converter listas multidimensionais sem perder as dimensões originais da lista:

```
import numpy as np

def list_lower( lst ):
    aux = np.array(lst)
    for i, v in np.ndenumerate( aux ):
        aux[i] = v.lower()
    return np.array(aux)

Lista = [['DE','DO','OU'],['AE','YHH','OO'],['OW','LA','FOR'],['X','K','N']]

print( list_lower(Lista) )
```

Saída:

```
[['de' 'do' 'ou']
 ['ae' 'yhh' 'oo']
 ['ow' 'la' 'for']
 ['x' 'k' 'n']]
```