# Execução ou não do incremento em loops for

Tags: javascript, loop, for

**Código 1**:

```js
var x = 1; 
  
for( ; x<6 ; x+=2 ){ 
    x=x*x; 
} 

console.log(x);
```

No código acima mesmo se a condição é falsa a parte que incrementa é executada pela última vez.

**Código 2:**

```js
 var x = 0; 

for( ; x<8 ; x++ ){} 
console.log(x); 

for( ; x>4 ; x-=2 ){} 
console.log(x);
```

No código acima mesmo que a condição seja falsa a parte que incrementa não é executada.

Por que acontece isso ou estou cometendo alguem erro?

Comment: Sabe fazer [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)? Se sim, tente fazer em ambos os códigos. Eu particularmente não entendi os questionamentos.

Comment: @Lucas Costa, é simples, no primeiro código mesmo x sendo maior que 6 a parte do incremento do for(;;(esta parte aqui)) ela é executada, ou seja, há o incremento de x e ele se torna 11 no final. Já no segundo código quando x < 8 a parte do incremento do x não é executada, da mesma forma acontece com o segundo for, ou seja, quando o x é 8 a parte x++ não é executada, tanto é que o valor do x é 8 no final do código. A dúvida é: por que a lógica é diferente para os dois for?

Comment: O depurador é seu amigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na primeira parte ele entra no for com x = 1 e faz x = x * x e da 1, depois entra com x = 3 e faz x = x * x que da 9, isso ocorre dentro do loop, agora ele sai do loop e faz x+=2 então x = 11, volta pra ver se x < 6 da false e printa 11;

Mesma lógica no segundo.

é mais ou menos assim:

`x = 1
x < 6? true
x = x * x
x = 1
x += 2
x = 3
x < 6? true
x = x * x
x = 9
x += 2
x = 11
x < 6? false`

Comment: é aí que tá o 'Q' da questão, @Hiogo, o resultado que eu esperava era 9, mas dá 11. Roda aí p ver ;)

Comment: Agora entendi sua dúvida, o `x=x*x` está dentro do for, quando o loop acaba ele executa `x+=2` quando `x = 9`

Comment: mas a lógica do for que você desenvolveu está falha, seria assim,não: x=3; x<6=True; x=x*x; x=9; x< 6=False. Ou eu estou errado? Por que ele incrementa com mais 2 sem antes checar a condição?(segundo a lógica que demonstrou acima)

Comment: ele está entrando no loop pela 2 vez, quando acabar ele faz o x+=2, editei a resposta para ficar mais claro

Comment: A sua dúvida não é realmente sobre javascript, você está confuso em alguns conceitos de lógica de programação, principalmente **escopo**.

Comment: Estava pensando na sequência do for de maneira errada, na verdade é assim: variável é inicializada / verificação da condição / execução do que está no corpo do for / depois incremento da variável. Resolveu minha dúvida. Valeu a todos!

Answer (score 5):

Cara o **For** funciona igual nos 2 casos, o problema é que sua comparação foi **falha** pois em um local você inciou com **0** e no outro com **1**.

Com excessão da inicialização o [For](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) incrementa antes de comparar.
[image: For]

Então mesmo 9 sendo maior que 6 ele ainda vai incrementar 2 para depois comparar.

Veja o exemplo abaixo exibindo passo a passo:

```js
var x = 1; 
for( ; x<6 ; x+=2 ){ 
    x=x*x; 
    console.log('x:' + x);
} 
console.log('Final x:' + x);

var y = 1; 
for( ; y<8 ; y++ ){
  console.log('y: ' + y); 
} 
console.log('Final y: ' + y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de a instrução sobre o incremento vir no início do loop `for`, dá pra considerar que esse incremento na verdade é executado logo após o corpo do loop, antes da próxima verificação sobre a condição de parada. Assim:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   // corpo do loop

   // incremento executado aqui
   // sai do loop com i === 10
}
```

Agora, se a condição de parada for falsa desde o início, nem o corpo do loop nem o incremento serão executados:

```
var i = 10;
for( ; i<10; i++) {
    // nunca executa nem o corpo nem o incremento
}
// aqui, ainda temos i === 10
```