# Função que some os valores dentro da lista

Tags: python

Estou com um problema e preciso criar uma função que some os valores que estão dentro de uma lista. Já fiz isso e o código está abaixo, entretanto, o Python me retorna o valor 3 como resultado, quando na verdade o valor deveria ser 103. Não consigo achar o erro de jeito nenhum, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Código abaixo:

```
def soma(x):

    total = 0
    for i in x:
        total += i
        return total
l1 = [3,7,1,90,2]

print(soma(l1))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O seu erro está na indentação da expressão `return total`; você colocou o retorno dentro do laço de repetição `for`, assim a função se encerrará sempre na primeira iteração, retornando o valor referente ao primeiro elemento da lista. Para corrigir, basta você remover a indentação:

```
def soma(x):

    total = 0
    for i in x:
        total += i
    return total

l1 = [3,7,1,90,2]

print(soma(l1))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YZdRMQ) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nqo0/0)</sup>

Você pode tentar reconhecer o erro elaborando o teste de mesa para o seu código: [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)

Além disso, o Python já possui uma função nativa, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), que calcula a soma de listas.

```
l1 = [3,7,1,90,2]

print(sum(l1))  # Exibe 103
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/czsE1G) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nqop/0)</sup>