# Duvida - Java algoritmo

Tags: java

Estou tentando resolver um algoritmo em java que é assim.

> Escreva um programa para imprimir o seguinte:
>
> ```
>      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>            0 1 2 3 4 5 6
>              0 1 2 3 4 5
>                0 1 2 3 4
>                  0 1 2 3
>                    0 1 2
>                      0 1
>                        0
> ```

Tentando fazer o código acabou saindo assim

```
int coluna = 0;
    while(coluna < 10){
        System.out.println(" ");
        int linha = 0;
        while(linha < coluna){
            System.out.print(linha+" ");
            linha++;
        }
        coluna++;
   }
```

Mas eu queria saber no que eu estou errando.

Comment: Tente escrever um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código.

Comment: Como ficou a saída de seu código? Ficou um triângulo invertido, confere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido fazendo uma associação com uma matriz. Imagine uma matriz generica:

```
a11 a12 a13 a14
a21 a22 a23 a24
a31 a32 a33 a34
a41 a42 a43 a44
```

Onde `aij`, significa linha e coluna. Basicamente ao fazer `coluna - linha` obtem-se a solução para o seu problema. Veja (por comodidade tornei i negativo):

```
-1+1 -1+2 -1+3 -1+4
-2+1 -2+2 -2+3 -2+4
-3+1 -3+2 -3+3 -3+4
-4+1 -4+2 -4+3 -4+4
```

Ficando assim:

```
 0  1  2  3
-1  0  1  2
-2 -1  0  1
-3 -2 -1  0
```

Então basta, no seu codigo, verificar se `coluna - linha` é maior ou igual a 0.

Voltando ao seu codigo. Ele funciona parcialmente, pois conforme a variavel linha vai aumentando não são adicionados espaços em branco equivalentes ao recuo deixado pelos números negativos (da operação `coluna - linha`).
Isso pode ser corrigido assim:

```
import java.util.*;
public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int coluna = 10;
        while(coluna > 0){
            System.out.println(" ");
            int linha = 0;

            //adicionar espacos (10 - coluna, comeca com 0 espaços e 
            //termina com 9 espacos em cada linha)
            int espaco = 1;
            while(espaco <= (10-coluna)){
                //um espaco para o numero (ausente) e outro para 
                //separar os numeros
                System.out.print("  ");
                espaco++;
            }
            while(linha < coluna){
                System.out.print(linha+" ");
                linha++;
            }
            coluna--;
        }   
    }
}
```

Ou você pode resolver considerando a ideia de matriz. Ficando assim:

```
import java.util.*;
public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        /**
        a[linha][coluna]
        matriz a =  a11 a12 a13 a14 a15
                    a21 a22 a23 a24 a25
                    a31 a32 a33 a34 a35     
        coluna-linha=numero     
        */
        int linha= 0;
        while(linha < 10){
            System.out.println();
            int coluna = 0;
            while(coluna < 10){
                if((coluna-linha) >= 0){
                    System.out.print((coluna-linha) + " ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("  ");             
                }

                coluna++;
            }
            linha++;
        }        
    }
}
```

Usando laço for:

```
import java.util.*;
public class b{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        /**
        a[linha][coluna]
        matriz a =  a11 a12 a13 a14 a15
                    a21 a22 a23 a24 a25
                    a31 a32 a33 a34 a35     
        coluna-linha=numero     
        */
        for(int linha = 0; linha < 10; linha++){
            for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 10; coluna++){
                if((coluna-linha) >= 0){
                    System.out.print((coluna-linha) + " ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("  ");             
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }        
    }
}
```

Em ambos os casos citados sai o resultado esperado:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
        0 1 2 3 4 5 
          0 1 2 3 4 
            0 1 2 3 
              0 1 2 
                0 1 
                  0
```

Diferente do que acontecia antes:

```
0  
0 1  
0 1 2  
0 1 2 3  
0 1 2 3 4  
0 1 2 3 4 5  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você precisa preencher os espaços que vão se aumentando a medida que se aumenta as linhas, pra depois incrementar os valores da linha. Crie uma terceira variável para controlar esse espaço.

```
int linha, space, coluna;

for(linha = 10;linha > 0; linha--){

    for(space = 10; space > linha; space--){
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    for(coluna = 0; coluna < linha; coluna++){
        System.out.print(coluna+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Perceba que no código, eu utilizei a variável `linha` como ponto de controle para o numero de espaços e para a quantidade de algarismos. Foi preciso adicionar dois espaços no segundo laço pra compensar o que você adicionou entre cada algarismo.

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/IEuc8k).