# Como incrementar uma div usando For JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, for

eu to com esse código porém não está pegando. Eu quero incrementar a cada clique no botão "Incrementar".

Código:

```js
function incrementar(){
  for (let i =0; i<10; i++){
     document.getElementById("incrementar2").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <button onClick="incrementar()">
    Incrementar
  </button>
  <div id="incrementar2"> 0
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Porém não está indo de jeito algum, ele vai direto pro número 9. Alguem pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Consegue fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código?

Comment: Quer que substitua o número por intervalos ou que acrescente conteudo?

Comment: @RpgBoss acrescente ao conteúdo. Exemplo, o numero ta 0, quando eu clicar no botão, ele ir pro 1 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Agora sim entendi, mas o @Valdeir Psr já postou a solução e explicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você utiliza a estrutura de repetição `for`, você está dizendo para ir do número 0 até 9 (no seu caso), e a cada repetição adicionar o número atual na `div` indicada. Como o processo é extremamente rápido, você não ver essa atualização ocorrendo.

Como você quer apenas incrementar quando houver uma ação de clique, esse `for` se torna desnecessário. O que você deve fazer nesse caso é capturar o número que já está na `div` e somar com 1.

```js
const divInc = document.getElementById("incrementar2");

function incrementar(){
  divInc.innerHTML = parseInt(divInc.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <button onClick="incrementar()">
    Incrementar
  </button>
  <div id="incrementar2"> 0
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Durante o processo você não pode esquecer de utilizar o `parseInt`. Ele servirá para transformar o conteúdo da `div` em um valor numérico. Caso você **não utilize** essa função, a sua `div` ficará com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```