# Erro no código - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
int[][] A = {{11, 7},{-20,-22}};
     int[][] B = {{A[0].length},{A.length}};

    for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i ++){

        for(int j = 0; j < A[0].length;j ++){
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");


        }
    System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i ++){                 
        for(int j = 0; j < A[0].length;j ++){
            B[i][j] = A[j][i];             

        }
    }
```

O erro é este :

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1       
> at j.pkg1.J1.ex31(J1.java:132)
>
> C:\*******************************\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
> ```

A linha 132 é `B[i][j] = A[j][i];`

Comment: Nosso idioma oficial é o **Português**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: O índice `A[j][i]` do *array*, não existe.

Comment: estou a transpor o A no B

Comment: Sabe fazer teste de mesa? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878. Julgando que o erro está na linha 132, enquanto o exemplo tem nem 20 linhas, o erro não acontece neste código. Provavelmente você tentou criar um [mcve], que é uma boa prática ao perguntar, mas que o exemplo não reproduz o erro.

Comment: No código que deu o erro, a matriz não é quadrada, correto?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é a forma como você está inicializando a matriz B. Tente substituir:

`int[][] B = {{A[0].length},{A.length}};`

por

`int[][] B = new int[A[0].length][A.length];`

Answer (score 1):

O vetor *B* é uma matriz *2x1* e o vetor *A* é uma matriz *2x2*

Nessa parte do codigo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i ++){

    for(int j = 0; j < A[0].length;j ++){
        System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
    }

System.out.println();

}
```

Você está tentando manipular um vetor *2x1* como se ele fosse um vetor *2x2*, aí dar estouro de índice, que é o erro que você está tendo.

Nessa parte do código

```
int[][] B = {{A[0].length},{A.length}};
```

Você não esta copiando o tamanho do vetor *A* para o *B*, você esta atribuindo o valor de comprimento do vetor (que é 2) para um índice do vetor que é inteiro.