# Como pegar o maior valor em um array com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Olá, criei uma função que deveria iterar por um array e retornar o maior valor. Ela até funciona em alguns casos, mas dependendo da ordem do array ela retorna o valor errado.

Sei que posso usar o método max do objeto Math, mas queria saber o que está errado na lógica dessa função?

```
function encontraMaior(array) {
    //Variavel que armazena o maior valor encontrado
    var maior;

    //Se o array for vazio lança um erro
    if(array.length < 1) {
       throw new Error('Empty array');
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let a, b;

        a = array[i];
        b = array[i+1];

        //Caso o array tenha apenas um numero
        if (!b) {
            b = 0;
        }

        /*Compara a variavel "a" com "b" e atribui o maior valor
        a variavel "maior"*/

        if (a > b) {
            maior = a;
        } 

        else if (b > a) {
            maior = b;
        }

        else if(a === b) {
            maior = a;
        }
    }

    return maior;
}
```

Comment: Faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) na sua função e entenderá o que está errado.

Comment: pra começar, esse código vai dar erro no último item do array: `b = array[i+1]`. Você está tentando ler o próximo elemento, isso vai dar erro, você só precisa olhar o elemento atual (índice `i`)

Comment: @RicardoPontual Não irá dar erro no ultimo elemento mas sim devolver `undefined` em relação a `b = array[i+1]` o que será apanhado pelo `if (!b) {`. O problema está mesmo na lógica em si.

Comment: @Isac quando disse erro não foi no sentido de *exception*, mas vai gerar um erro de comparação que pode invalidar se o penúltimo número for o maior, porque por exemplo um número qualquer, 10. Se comparar `10 < undefined` ou `10 > undefined` ou ainda `10 === undefined` todos retornarão `false` invalidando a lógica

Comment: Eu entendi a sua pergunta, mas se você der um array sort em seu array antes de começar as comparações, creio que dará mais certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está na logica em si que está a utilizar. Não pode construir o maior apenas com base nos dois elementos que analisa, pois os que foram analisados para trás irão ser desconsiderados.

Coloquei o seu código com uns `console.log` pelo meio de forma a ver as comparações e atribuições que ele faz:

```js
function encontraMaior(array) {
    var maior;
    if(array.length < 1) {
       throw new Error('Empty array');
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let a, b;
        a = array[i];
        b = array[i+1];

        if (!b) {
            b = 0;
        }

        console.log(`A comparar ${a} com ${b}`);

        if (a > b) {
            maior = a;
        } 
        else if (b > a) {
            maior = b;
        }
        else if(a === b) {
            maior = a;
        } 
        console.log(`O maior é agora ${maior}`);
    }
    return maior;
}

let arr = [10,3,1,6,7,2];
console.log(encontraMaior(arr));
```

Repare que para o array:

```
[10,3,1,6,7,2]
```

- Compara o `10` com `3` para descobrir que o maior é o `10`
- Mas logo de seguida compara o `3` com o `1` e diz que o maior é `3`.

Isto acontece porque no seu código apenas os dois números correntes interessam, o que significa que apenas irá prevalecer ultima comparação. No entanto quando está no ultimo elemento ao fazer:

```
b = array[i+1];
```

`i+1` já estará fora das posições validas e `b` ficará com `undefined`. Assim com o `if` que vem a seguir:

```
if (!b) { 
    b = 0;
}
```

Como `b` tem `undefined` entra no `if` e fica com `0` fazendo com que o `a` seja maior (a menos que seja negativo). Consegue ver isso na ultima comparação que é mostrada no *snippet* anterior, o `"A comparar 2 com 0"`. Concluindo, a sua função `encontraMaior` devolve sempre o ultimo elemento, que pode coincidentemente ser de facto o maior.

Não há forma de corrigir sem alterar mesmo a lógica. Uma vez que quer implementar à mão faça o normal que é bem mais simples:

```js
function encontraMaior(array) {
    if(array.length < 1) {
       throw new Error('Empty array');
    }
    var maior = array[0]; //mais alto iniciado como o primeiro elemento
    
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; ++i){
    //           ^--- Começa no segundo pois o primeiro já foi considerado

        //se o valor que tem no momento é maior que o mais alto
        if (array[i] > maior){ 
            maior = array[i]; //atualiza o mais alto
        }
    }
    
    return maior;
}

let arr = [10,3,1,6,7,2];
console.log(encontraMaior(arr));
```

Em situações reais não reinvente a roda e utilize as funções que já existem para o efeito, neste caso o [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) que mencionou:

```js
function encontraMaior(array){
    return Math.max(...array);
}

let arr = [10,3,1,6,7,2];
console.log(encontraMaior(arr));
```

Neste ultimo exemplo utilizei o [*`spread operator`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) para expandir os elementos para a função `max`.

Comment: Explicação sensacional, muito obrigado, entendi o por que da lógica estar errada. O fato de sempre a função comparar o atual e o anterior e retornar o maior, ela sempre fazia a comparação entre esses dois numeros, não do array inteiro. E obrigado pela dia para não "reinventar a roda".

Answer (score 0):

Porque a sua lógica apresenta vários pontos de falha. Basicamente em seu script você tenta comparar o item atual com o próximo.

```
 a = array[i];
 b = array[i+1];
```

Sendo que na atribuição de `b`, se o ponteiro já estiver no último elemento do array, você está extrapolando o tamanho do mesmo e tentando acessar um elemento que não existe.

Logo após você faz comparações equivocadas para armazenar o maior valor.

```
    if (a > b) {
        maior = a;
    } 

    else if (b > a) {
        maior = b;
    }

    else if(a === b) {
        maior = a;
    }
```

Além de redundantes e irrelevantes, em nenhum momento você está verificando se o valor que está atribuindo é maior do que já armazenado na variável `maior` e sempre está substituindo por `a` ou `b`, que são os dois valores que estão sendo comparados nessa iteração.

Abaixo segue um exemplo da forma mais comum de se resolver o problema.

```
function encontraMaior(array) {    
    //Se o array for vazio lança um erro
    if(array.length < 1) {
       throw new Error('Empty array');
    }

    //Recebe o primeiro elemento do array
    var maior = array[0];

    //Faz o loop a partir do segundo elemento para fazer as comparações
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        var atual = array[i];
        if( atual > maior)
         maior = atual;
    }

    return maior;
}
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss faltou algum ponto?

Comment: Muito obrigado, deixei a pergunta aqui hoje de manhã e fui ver agora, antes disso quebrei um pouco a cabeça e vi que o maior problema era que eu não estava armazenando o maior valor, estava apenas comparando entre a e b como vc disse. O que resultou em duas opções, uma usando o a função max da classe Math, e outra um pouco mais longa melhorando a minha lógica. Mas o exemplo acima simplifica muito as coisas, obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns erros de lógica na sua função (utilizei comentários no seu próprio código para destacá-los):

```
function encontraMaior(array) {

var maior;


if(array.length < 1) {
   throw new Error('Empty array');
}

//Você pode percorrer incrementando os índices em 2, pois já está comparando
// dois índices a cada iteração (a e b)
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    let a, b;

    a = array[i];

   //Checa se a posição (i+1) existe e considera b como 0 caso negativo
    if (i + 1 > array.length - 1) {
        b = 0;
    }
    else {
        b = array[i+1];
    }

    //Conferir se maior não foi inicializado ainda, para atribuir um valor
    // inicial que será comparado posteriormente (inclusive dentro do mesmo
    // laço que inicializou, possibilitando que b seja considerado o maior
    if(maior == null){
       maior = a;
    }

    //Deve comparar as variáveis a e b também com o valor de maior, pois no
    // no algoritmo original o valor de maior é perdido em cada iteração
    if (a > b && a > maior) {
        maior = a;
    } 

    else if (b > a && b > maior) {
        maior = b;
    }

    else if(a === b && a > maior) {
        maior = a;
    }
}    

return maior;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A função Math.max já retorna o maior entre dois:

```
Math.max(10, 20);   //  20
Math.max(-10, -20); // -10
Math.max(-10, 20);  //  20
```

Com reduce vc conseguiria usar num array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
});
```

Comment: Ou simplesmente passe o array todo, usando a [sintaxe de *spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): `var max = Math.max(...arr)`