# Pegar o menor valor de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho este arrary de objetos, como posso fazer para me retornar o objeto com o menor valor em currentTasks

```
"programmers":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Eduardo Candido",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": "João Lemos",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": "Antonio Bond",
        "currentTasks": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: No caso é os menores objetos? por que você pode ter mais que um menor, igual o exemplo, você quer apenas os dois primeiros se fosse o caso, já que eles são 1.

Comment: Exato, ou qualquer um dos dois primeiros

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285005/como-pegar-o-maior-valor-em-um-array-com-javascript

Da uma olhada nessa solução aqui, então só é alterar de maior para menos e no lugar de comprar cada valor do array você compara apenas os CurrentTasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes passar uma array em spread ao `Math.min` para te dar o valor mais baixo.

Por exemplo:

```
const valores = object.programmers.map(({currentTasks}) => currentTasks)
const menorValor = Math.min(...valores);
```

E depois podes usar o `.filter(` para selecionar os elementos dessa array que têm o valor que procuras.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const object = {
  "programmers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Eduardo Candido",
      "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "João Lemos",
      "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Antonio Bond",
      "currentTasks": 2
    }
  ]
};

const menorValor = Math.min(...object.programmers.map(({
  currentTasks
}) => currentTasks));
console.log('Menor valor', menorValor);
const menoresValores = object.programmers.filter(({
  currentTasks
}) => currentTasks === menorValor);
console.log('Menores', menoresValores);
```

Answer (score 4):

Com `.reduce()` você encontra o objeto com o menor valor na chave `currentTasks`:

```js
const obj = { "programmers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Eduardo Candido",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": "João Lemos",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": "Antonio Bond",
        "currentTasks": 2
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "Fulano",
        "currentTasks": 3
    }
]}

const min = obj.programmers.reduce((a,b)=>{
   if(b.currentTasks < a.currentTasks) a = b;
   return a;
});

console.log(min);
```

> No caso de haver mais de um objeto com a chave `currentTasks` com o
>   mesmo valor, irá retornar o primeiro.

Outro exemplo com um valor `0`:

```js
const obj = { "programmers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Eduardo Candido",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": "João Lemos",
        "currentTasks": 1
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": "Antonio Bond",
        "currentTasks": 0
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": "Fulano",
        "currentTasks": 2
    }
]}

const min = obj.programmers.reduce((a,b)=>{
   if(b.currentTasks < a.currentTasks) a = b;
   return a;
});

console.log(min);
```

**Referência:**

- [`.reduce()` no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)