# como posso fazer uma roleta russa em python simples

Tags: python, python-3.x

eu queria um scrip simples onde ele conta ate 6 usando while ou outro método de repetição. e vai ter uma lista com 5 falho e 1 morreu  e ele vai contando ate 6 sorteando essa lista e quando ele fala morreu queria que ela parece. porem no meu script  ele continua falando ate completar 6 loops

```
    def russa(self, message, name_sender, to=''):
     list_morte = ['Morreu','falho','falho','falho','falho','falho',]
     self.post(message='Vamos nós matar hehehe') 
     self.post(message='Go.!') 
     contador =0
     while (contador<6):
       time.sleep(3) #delay de 5 segundos
       self.post(message='/roll')
       list_morte = random.choice(list_morte)
       self.post('/me %s' % list_morte)
     contador =contador+1 
     if list_morte == 'Morreu':
        self.post(message='Morreu')
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o seu código?

Comment: como e disse acima não sei como fazer ele parar quando ele fala morreu e algo bem simples, mas útil pra um iniciante

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você deseja que a repetição pare quando é sorteado o valor "morreu", basta fazer uma estrutura condicional:

```
while contador < 6:
    print('atirando...')
    acao = random.choice(list_morte)
    print(acao)
    if acao == 'Morreu':
        break  # Aqui para o laço
    contador += 1
```

Se o número de tentativas foi indefinido, desde que pare quando sair a ação "morreu", o melhor seria colocar em um laço *infinito*, utilizando:

```
while True:
    acao = random.choice(list_morte)
    print(acao)
    if acao == 'Morreu':
        break
```

Assim, o programa ficará executando até que saia a ação "morreu".

> **Nota:** você estava sobrescrevendo o valor de `list_morte` ao fazer `list_morte = random.choice(list_morte)`, o que gerava uma saída bem diferente da esperada, por isso chamei de `acao` o retorno de `choice`.

Comment: acabei de edita o código e testar ele como você sugerio

porem quando executo ele entra em loop e fica retornando a a a a a . e se eu não colocar list_morte = random.choice(list_morte) ele retorna toda a lista e não um único item.

![erro](https://i.imgur.com/Fjgr1zb.png)
![loop](https://i.imgur.com/vZxis7e.png)

Comment: @Londarks preciso que você arrume a indentação do seu código na pergunta para ter certeza do que fez.

Comment: o código esta certo eu usei oque está ali em cima por favor verifique denovo

Comment: @Londarks se assim for, seu código faz menos sentido do que o inicial, então recomendo que elabore um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código e entenda o que está errado.

Answer (score 1):

Veja, logo abaixo, a minha versão da `Roleta Russa`, utilizando o laço de repetição `for`.

```
# Jogo roleta russa

from time import sleep
from random import choice

print('=' * 30)
print(f'\033[34m{f"Roleta Russa":^30}\033[m')
print('=' * 30)

valores = ['Falhou', 'Falhou', 'Falhou', 'Falhou', 'Falhou', 'Morreu']

cont = 0
for c in range(1, 7):
    print('Girando!')
    for i in range(30):
        sleep(0.1)
        print(f'{chr(46)}', end='')
    print()
    x = choice(valores)
    cont += 1
    if x != valores[-1]:
        print(f'\033[32m{cont}º disparo {x}!\033[m')
        if cont == 6:
            print(f'\033[34mVocê é muito Sortudo! Continua Vivo!\033[m')
    else:
        print(f'\033[31m{x}! No {cont}º disparo!\033[m')
        break
```