# Função que retorne o elemento com mais caracteres de uma lista

Tags: python

cheguei na seguinte função:

```
def func6a(lista):
    maior = 0
    for el in lista:
        if type(el) == list:
            maior  = func6a(el)
        else:
            if len(el) > maior:
                maior = el

    return maior
```

Mas,infelizmente,to tendo o seguinte erro:

> *if len(el) > maior:
>
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'*

Minha pergunta é; como posso fazer para escapar desse erro ? 
Já o esperava, mas não sei como fazer para escapar!

Obs:os parâmetros devem ser strings ou lista aninhadas contendo strings!

Answer (score 5):

As outras respostas já apresentam o código corrigido/a funcionar, e alternativas interessantes, mas não detalham o problema, que é importante para conseguir evitar/corrigir futuros erros similares.

Repare na mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'*

Esta diz-lhe que está a comparar um inteiro com uma string, que não pode fazer.

E acontece nesta linha:

```
if len(el) > maior:
```

Agora pode-se estar a questionar qual o tipo de cada coisa para gerar este erro ? Algo que consegue responder se fizer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo), e que é importante para quando não está a visualizar o problema. Mas eu ajudo-lhe a perceber melhor o problema sem ser necessário fazer um teste de mesa completo, e analisando apenas os valores das variáveis so nos primeiros dois passos.

Acontece que você definiu `maior` lá no topo como `0`, por isso ao passar um lista de strings simples como `func6a(["abcd","cdf","gh"])` a primeira comparação irá ser entre `4`(tamanho do `"abcd"`) e `0` funcionando perfeitamente. Mas nesse caso entra dentro do `if` e troca o valor de maior:

```
if len(el) > maior:
    maior = el
```

Agora o `maior` passou a ser `"abcd"` pois você atribuiu a string nele, o que significa que de seguida a comparação irá ser entre `3`(tamanho do `"cdf"`) e `"abcd"` resultando no erro, pois está a comparar `3`, que é um `int`, com `"cdf"` que é uma string.

Também se retornar um `int` no final da função nunca irá obter a resposta que pretende de "elemento com mais caracteres de uma lista", pois o retorno é o tamanho do elemento e não o elemento.

Answer (score 2):

Considerando titulo da sua pergunta

**Função que retorne o elemento com mais caracteres de uma lista**

A função built-in `max` do python faz o que você precisa.

```
l = ['A', 'ABCDEFG', 'ABC']
max(l, key=len)
'ABCDEFG'
```

---

Considerando a observação que fez na pergunta

**Obs:os parâmetros devem ser strings ou lista aninhadas contendo strings!**

A função abaixo com pequenos ajustes para casos em que os items das lista não sejam strings, acredito ser útil.

```
def max_in_list(l):
    max_value = ''

    for _ in l:
        if isinstance(_, list):
            max_value = max_in_list(_)

        if len(_) > len(max_value):
            max_value = _

    return(max_value)
```

A execução deve retornar o item com maior numero de caracter, esteja ele dentro de uma lista aninhada ou fora.

```
ll = [ ['asas', 'sasas', 'a'], [ ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'a'  ] ] ]

max_in_list(ll)
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

ll = [ ['asas', 'sasas', 'a'], ['ssasas', 's', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'], 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']

max_in_list(ll)
        'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Comment: `max(['A', 'ABCDEFG', 'ABC', 'B'])` retorna `'B'`, então a primeira parte da sua resposta está errada. A função `max` retorna a maior *string* por ordem alfabética, sem considerar o tamanho das mesmas.

Comment: Adinanp,obrigado pela explicação,acontece que a ideia é não usar as funções nativas no python.O professor não permite,erro meu não pontuar isso no enunciado,mas mesmo assim agradeço!

Comment: Anderson, você tem razão. Vi que na sua resposta você faz  o uso correto do `max` com o argumento `key`. Editei minha resposta, obrigado pelo apontamento do erro.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acredito que você esta comparando tamanho das listas sendo assim tem que pegar o tamanho da variavel maior len(maior):

```
def func6a(lista):
    maior = 0
    for el in lista:
        if type(el) == list:
            maior  = func6a(el)
        else:
            if len(el) > len(maior):
                maior = el

    return maior
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de se trabalhar com listas de multiníveis, isto é, permitir possuir listas de listas de listas de listas de... de *string*, é representar todos esses dados de maneira plana, como se estivessem apenas em um nível. É possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
def flatten(data):
    """ Representa uma lista|tupla multiníveis de maneira plana.

    Parâmetros:
        data (list|tuple): Iterável com as informações a serem planificadas.

    Retorno:
        Retorna um gerador com os dados de entrada em sua forma plana.

    Exemplo:

    >>> data = ['anderson', ['carlos', ['woss']]]
    >>> list(flatten(data))
    ['anderson', 'carlos', 'woss']
    """
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

Assim, basta utilizar a função nativa `max`, definindo corretamente o parâmetro `key` para buscar a *string* com maior número de caracteres:

```
maior_string = max(data, key=len)
```

Assim, o retorno será a *string* com maior número de caracteres, como esperado.

```
strings = [
    'anderson',
    [
        'carlos',
        [
            'woss',
            'stackoverflow'
        ]
    ]
]

maior_string = max(flatten(strings), key=len)

print(f'O maior texto encontrado foi: {maior_string}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HeavenlyLightCensorware) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UNnpfu) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/a23289faaac514f2f480e18bf60a7e3c)</sup>

Comment: Anderson,obrigado pela explicação e realmente seu código é ótimo.Entretanto,eu sou iniciante e esse exercício é de uma aula,o professor restringiu para que façamos da forma mais simples possível,portanto,agradeço a sua explicação e código,mas preciso de uma maneira mais simples.Abraço!