# Dúvida na lógica do script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Galera, queria saber porque o número 2 não é o primeiro a ser impresso neste script, eu não estou entendendo a lógica.

```
altura = 5
linha = 1

while linha <= altura:
    print ('1', end = '')
    coluna = 2

    while coluna < altura:

        if linha == 1 or linha == altura:
            print ('2')

        else:
            print(end = '')
        coluna = coluna + 1

    print ('3')
    linha = linha + 1
```

Comment: Conhece o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)?

Comment: não amigo, estudo por conta

Comment: Leia sobre e tente aplicá-lo. Ficará mais fácil entender o que o código faz;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leandro, para entender esse script é bom entender como funciona o loop do while.

O primeiro while só será executado caso sua condição seja atendida,logo:

```
while linha <= altura: #linha(1) é de fato menor que altura(5) 
print ('1', end = '')
coluna = 2
```

Quando há um laço dentro de outro, o laço subsequente também e executado e somente após seu fim o laço externo retorna a sua execução normal, logo:

```
    while coluna < altura:

    if linha == 1 or linha == altura:
        print ('2')

    else:
        print(end = '')
    coluna = coluna + 1
```

O seu segundo while tem de ser executado ate que sua condição seja satisfeita para posteriormente cair novamente no loop exterior.

A dica do Anderson é valida, testes de mesa podem te ajudar a depurar esses erros mais simples de código, mas um bom entendimento da lógica de programação também é necessário, continue estudando.

Answer (score 1):

No seu código você tem dois `while`. O `while` de fora é executado antes e o conteúdo dele é executado também. O código não começa pelo `while` interno, creio que isto que tenha lhe confundido.

Portanto, fazendo uma simulação da primeira execução e dos valores:

```
altura = 5                                   # altura = 5
linha = 1                                    # linha = 1

while linha <= altura:                       # 1 <= 5
    print ('1', end = '')                    # imprime 1, aqui já explica o motivo
    coluna = 2                               # coluna = 2

    while coluna < altura:                   # 2 < 5

        if linha == 1 or linha == altura:    # 1 == 1 or 1 == 5
            print ('2')                      # imprime 2, formando 12, o primeiro valor
```