# Entendimento de exercício do livro Use a Cabeça Java

Tags: java, lógica

Não entendi o funcionamento do código abaixo, talvez mais adiante no livro tenha melhores explicações ou deixei passar algo mesmo na revisão.

Vou detalhar os pontos no próprio código em que tenho dúvidas.

```
    package qb5;

    public class Qb5 {

    static class Mix4{

    int counter = 0;

    public int maybeNew(int index){

        if (index < 7 ){

            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();

            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;

            return 1; //Sempre retornará 1, aqui entendi
    } 
        return 0; //Não achei o porque do return 0 neste ponto
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        int x = 0;

        while (x < 7 ){
        m4a[x] = new Mix4();
        m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;  
        count += 1;
        count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x); 

        x +=1;
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter); //Porque m4a[1]?
    }
}
```

Aqui tenho a dúvida maior:

Entendi que `maybeNew(x)`, envia o valor para a variável *index* no método `maybeNew` para fazer a comparação, mas esse mesmo `maybeNew(x)` afeta de alguma forma a atribuição da própria variável `count` do começo da linha?

A saída deste exercício seria 14 1, mas fiquei perdido e não consigo enxergar como chegou a 14, o 1 o próprio `return` indica o valor.

EDIT:
Esse código realmente tem pegadinha, assim como outro anterior, mas o próprio livro diz que tem coisas que vão ser esclarecidas a frente, sujerindo que passe para frente caso não entenda, mas preferi bater cabeça.
Pelo o que entendi, a variável `counter` só entra pra confundir mesmo, ela sempre será 1.

Já na sáida `m4a[1].counter` aquele index 1 tá de enfeite, porque coloquei 2 e também retornou resultado 1 do counter.

@Edjane clareou a mente explicando da instância zerar a variável.

Fiz um debug manual adicionando alguns prints a mais no código e ver a saída, e junto ao teste de mesa sujerido pelo @Maniero vi que não batiam os resultados, então consegui entender.

Fiz um loop de 3 apenas para não ficar grande a imagem, porque na saída do `m4` imprimiu 2 vezes, não achei a causa disso, é coisa banal mas para finalizar, restou essa dúvida.

[image: Lógica java]

Comment: Favor estruturar melhor a sua duvida,  o código está misturado com a duvida. Favor colocar a duvida em um parágrafo e logo apos o código, ou vice versa para fácil a leitura, e utilize duas barras para sinalizar comentário no código:  " //COMENTARIO "

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta para ficar mais claro. Bom estudo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estudei muito exercícios desse tipo para tirar a certificação OCJP, ele abrange instanciação de classes e passagem de valores, por exemplo, porque essa linha,

```
m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
```

contida no método **public int maybeNew(int index)** sempre retorna 1? Simplesmente pelo fato de sempre que o método é invocado no main esse valor é reiniciado, quando você instancia a classe.

```
 Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
```

> Isso é para te testar e tentar te induzir ao erro, caso você não
>   domine isso, você pode deduzir que **m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;** sempre esta
>   incrementando 1 ao valor anterior, o que daria uma resposta diferente.

Nesse caso você pode até colocar o retorno do if como **m4.counter** que sempre vai retornar 1.

Outro ponto importante, veja os comentários no código

```
    while (x < 7 ){
            m4a[x] = new Mix4(); //aqui nova instancia, ou seja, sempre é inicializado
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1; //por ser inicializado sempre soma 0+1, ou seja aqui sempre vai ser 1
            count += 1; //aqui ele pega o valor anterior do count que não é inicializado e acrescenta 1
            //nesse ponto você percebe que a variável não instanciada continua com o seu valor anterior
            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x); //soma o valor anterior com o valor passado pelo método, como você esta indo ate 7 ele passa 1, caso você faça um while maior que 7 ele passa 0

       x +=1;
    }
```

> A saída deste exercício seria 14 1, mas fiquei perdido e não consigo
>   enchergar como chegou a 14

Porque o resultado é 14 1 vamos colocar no ciclo ok?

> ```
> 1° ciclo:
> m4a[x].counter = 1;
> count += 1;
> count = 1;
> count = 1 + 1; // count = 2
>
> 2° ciclo:
> m4a[x].counter = 1;
> count += 1; //valor anterior = 2 + 1 = 3
> count = 3;
> count = 3 + 1; // count = 4
>
> ...
> 7° ciclo:
> m4a[x].counter = 1;
> count += 1;
> count = 13;
> count = 13 + 1; // count = 14
> ```
>
> Resultado 14 1

E se você ultrapassar 7 no while fazendo com que o if retorne 0? Exemplo:

```
while (x < 8 )
```

> ```
> 8° ciclo:
> m4a[x].counter = 1;
> count += 1;
> count = 15;
> count = 15 + 0; // count = 15
> ```
>
> > Seu resultado final seria 15 0

Continuando...

> Já na sáida m4a[1].counter aquele index 1 tá de enfeite, porque
>   coloquei 2 e também retornou resultado 1 do counter

Na verdade esse valor não esta de enfeite, ele sempre dá o mesmo valor porque sempre é criada uma nova instância, isso é mais uma intenção de você ser induzido que esse valor sofreu um incremento, o que não acontece, pra você entender melhor, vamos pegar esse trecho do seu código:

```
static class Mix4{
  int counter = 0;
  ...
```

Agora, pegamos esse trecho:

```
if (index < 7 ){
    Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); //nova instância de Mix4
    m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; // isso é a mesma coisa que ***m4.counter = 0+1***
```

Nesse caso o valor recebido para soma m4.counter é 0, porque ele pegou o valor de counter definido na classe Mix4. Enquanto você não instanciar novamente essa classe esse valor dentro desse if será 1 *(m4.counter = 0+1 => 1)*

Exemplo:

```
if (index < 7 ){
    Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
    m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; //m4.counter = 0 + 1
    System.out.println(m4.counter + " = m4"); //m4.counter 1
    m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; //m4.counter = 1 + 1
    System.out.println(m4.counter + " = m4"); //m4.counter 2
```

Outro teste pra ficar mais claro, e se o valor de counter fosse 4

```
static class Mix4{
      int counter = 4;
      ...
```

Resultado:

```
if (index < 7 ){
    Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
    m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;  //m4.counter = 4 + 1
    System.out.println(m4.counter + " = m4"); //m4.counter 5
    m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; //m4.counter = 5 + 1
    System.out.println(m4.counter + " = m4"); //m4.counter 6
```

Trabalhando com Java, você jamais vai escrever ou ver um código desse tipo, *"a não ser que você seja um professor"* mas esses ensinamentos são fundamentais para um bom dsenvolvedor.

> ...porque na saída do m4 imprimiu 2 vezes

Não vi o motivo de estar sendo impresso 2 vezes

Comment: Fiz o teste de adionar 8, na saída final fica 15 1, porque é a counter, mas no print de debug que fiz onde peguei esse trecho `m4a[x].maybeNew(x)` realmente saiu 0.
Editei meu tópico com uma imagem e uma dúvida final.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> return 1; //Sempre retornará 1, aqui entendi
> ```

Nem sempre, retornará apenas se `index` for menor que 7.

> ```
> return 0; //Não achei o porque do return 0 neste ponto
> ```

Ele executará sempre que `index` não for menor que 7. A função precisa ter um retorno em qualquer circunstância, não pode retornar algo apenas em alguns casos e em outro não.

> esse mesmo `maybeNew(x)` afeta de alguma forma a atribuição da própria variável count do começo da linha?

Ele em si não, mas a linha toda está afetando `count`, afinal esta linha está dizendo para guardar em `count`, e isto por si só já afeta alguma coisa, um valor que no caso é o próprio `count` adicionado de uma expressão

> ```
> System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter); //Porque m4a[1]?
> ```

Não temos como saber pelo que está na pergunta, mas por alguma razão ele precisa pegar o segundo elemento deste *array*.

> A saída deste exercício seria 14 1, mas fiquei perdido e não consigo enxergar como chegou a 14, o 1 o próprio `return` indica o valor.

Ele foi seguindo o algoritmo. Eu poderia explicar linha por linha, mas o melhor é você mesmo fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101) e identificar. Porém, **em um código confuso assim o melhor é nem tentar**. Aprenda com algo mais significativo. Entender isto será prejudicial para seu aprendizado.

Raramente o `main()` deve estar junto de uma classe que precisa ser instanciada. Isto confunde tudo. Não há motivo para cada parte desta classe existir e se começar trabalhar com coisas sem sentido irá se acostumar com isso. Note que em cada passo há a acumulação de 2. A primeira acumulação é bem explícita e em seguida a outra acontece porque `maybeNew()` sempre retorna 1, isto poderia ter sido escrito em uma linha.

Não é culpa sua ter dificuldade de entender, é culpa do código.

O código é bem mal escrito e pouco didático. Ensina fazer coisas estranhas, confusas e provavelmente erradas, por isso eu questionaria o livro. Essa série de livros era bem conceituada, então não sei se piorou com o tempo ou esse especificamente foi mal escrito.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do teste de mesa.

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um código bastante confuso e como o @Maneiro disse é questionável como código para estar em um livro, mas vou tentar explicar o que está acontecendo tendo como base que este seja o único código do projeto.

Tudo começa no seu `main`, onde vem nominados e instanciados os atributos da classe:

```
int count = 0;
Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
int x = 0;
```

Depois faz um *loop* que vai iterar 7 vezes aumentando o valor de *x* a cada iteração

```
while (x < 7 ) // itera 7 vezes de x=0 até x=6

x +=1; //aumenta o valor de x a cada iteração
```

Bom vamos as quatro linhas de código dentro do loop ( analisar o que o código esta fazendo =) )

```
    m4a[x] = new Mix4();                   //linha 1
    m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;   //linha 2
    count += 1;                            //linha 3
    count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);    //linha 4
```

Na **linha 1** o `main` cria uma instancia de `Mix4` e a coloca na lista `m4a`

Na **linha 2** o código esta pegando essa instancia que agora esta na lista e adicionando o valor 1 ao atributo daquele objeto, no caso o `counter`, que era 0 e agora é 1

Na **linha 3** o código adiciona o valor 1 à variável `count`, uma vez que esse código é executado 7 vezes podemos dizer que essa linha é responsável por adicionar o valor 7 à variável `count`

Na **linha 4** o código esta pegando o valor de `count` *adicionando um valor a ele* * e salvando essa soma a própria variável `count`, podemos dizer que está acrescentando um valor ao valor que já tinha antes.

**Vamos analisar esse valor adicionado:**

O código esta chamando o método `maybeNew` do objeto que foi apenas salvada na lista, o que sabemos dele?

-> Sabemos que o valor do seu atributo `counter` é igual a 1, e que o parâmetro passado ( x ) é sempre menor que 7

Analisando o método `maybeNew`:

o método tem como primeira linha um `if` que verifica se o parâmetro passado é menor que 7 ( o que sabemos que sempre é) e faz uma serie de coisa se essa condição é verdadeira.

```
 Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
 m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
 return 1;
```

Primeiramente cria uma nova instancia e a atribui a um objeto chamado `m4`, depois modifica o valor do atributo do objeto `m4` e por fim retorna o valor 1

então sabemos que retornará sempre 1 e sabemos agora o quanto vem somado ao `count` na **linha 4**

Sabendo que na **linha 4** vem somado sempre 1 temos que ao final da 7 iteração será adicionado o valor 7.

```
System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
```

Chegamos ao resultado do 14

O valor 1 de `m4a[1].counter` é aquele que o código tinha adicionado na **linha 2**

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida deixe um comentário