# Certos números de entrada da looping infinito

Tags: c#

Quando colco o número 14 na entrada ele entra em looping infinito, como posso resolver esse problema?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ex14
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int taxa_dada, total, s, qs;
        s = 5;
        qs = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Qual é a taxa:");
        taxa_dada = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (taxa_dada >= 8)
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (taxa_dada >= s)
                {
                    taxa_dada -= s;
                    qs++;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (qs > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Total de {0}  selos: {1}", qs, s);
                    }
                    if (s == 5)
                    {
                        s = 3;
                        qs = 0;
                    }
                    if (taxa_dada == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taxa minima de 8 centavo!");

        }




        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: O ideal nestes casos simples é você fazer [um teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo) que rápidamente acha o problema. A sua logica dentro do `for` não está de facto correta e não permite que o *loop* termine a menos que a entrada seja multipla de 5.

Comment: esse seu for (; ; ) funcionar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui entender direito o que seu código quer fazer (quer contar a quantidade de selos de 5centavos dado uma taxa?), mas para sanar o problema do loop infinito eu recomendo fazer a seguinte abordagem:

- Um loop infinito (for(;;)) nesse caso é meio que bem propenso a erros desse tipo que está acontencendo com o 14. Eu recomendo nesse caso aí usar o while mais ou menos como:

  ```
  while(taxa_dada >= s)
      {
          if (taxa_dada >= s)
          {
              taxa_dada -= s;
              qs++;
          }
      }
  ```

Dessa forma você já eliminaria o primeiro if e já não correria o risco de um loop infinito. Todas as outras condições você pode colocar a baixo desse while ainda dentro do if, no final resultaria em algo assim:

```
    if (taxa_dada >= 8)
    {
        while(taxa_dada >= s)
        {
            if (taxa_dada >= s)
            {
                taxa_dada -= s;
                qs++;
            }
        }

        if (qs > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Total de {0}  selos: {1}", qs, s);

        if (s == 5) {
            s = 3;
            qs = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Taxa minima de 8 centavo!");
    }
```

Como eu disse não entendi direito o que você quer com seu código, mas espero ter ajudado :D