# Determinar cálculo recursivo de derivada em Python

Tags: python, matemática

Eu preciso criar um algoritmo para que determina em N vezes a derivada de uma função X.

Entretanto eu ainda tenho alguns problemas para implementar funções recursivas, ainda não consegui me inteirar bem da lógica.

Para determinar a derivada da função eu estou usando:

```
diff(função)
```

Eu tinha pensando em colocar um

```
for(x = 0; x < VezesUsuario; x++){ derivar }
```

Mas não sei bem como faria pra retornar o resultado do cálculo anterior e calcular a derivada dele. Eu tenho a exigência de faze-lo recursivo, esse é meu problema na verdade.

Comment: O que precisa fazer é calcular a n-ésima derivada?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso! De forma que seja recursivo, eu tinha a ideia de fazer um IF, mas não atendia as exigências.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das formas que você pode fazer é:

- Receber em uma função `diff` a função a ser derivada, f,  e a ordem de derivação, N;
- Calcular a derivada g de ordem 1 da função f;
- Se ordem de derivação N for igual a 1, retornar a função g;
- Caso contrário, retornar a derivada de ordem N-1 da função g;

Assim, o código ficaria parecido com:

```
def diff(func, N=1):
    # Calcula a derivada de ordem 1
    # g = func'

    return g if N == 1 else diff(g, N-1)
```

Assim, se precisar a segunda derivada, será:

- Será calculada a derivada de ordem 1;
- Como N é maior que 1, será retornado o valor da derivada de ordem 1 da derivada;
- Ao calcular a derivada da derivada, N será 1 e a própria derivada será retornada;
- O valor final será a derivada de ordem 2 da função de entrada;

Deixo para você o desafio de escrever um [Teste de Mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para calcular a derivada de ordem 5 ou superior.

---

Por exemplo, considerando um monômio composto de coeficiente e expoente:

```
class Monomial:

    coefficient: float
    exponent: int

    def __init__(self, coefficient, exponent):
        self.coefficient = coefficient
        self.exponent = exponent

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.coefficient}x^{self.exponent}'

    def __diff__(self):
        coefficient = self.coefficient * self.exponent
        exponent = self.exponent - 1

        return Monomial(coefficient, exponent)
```

Podemos definir o monômio `2x^5` fazendo:

```
p = Monomial(2, 5)

print('Monômio:', p)  # Monômio: 2x^5
```

Definir a função `diff` como:

```
def diff(func, N=1):
    g = func.__diff__()

    return g if N == 1 else diff(g, N-1)
```

Assim, para calcular a derivada terceira de `p`, basta fazer `q = diff(p, 3)`, obtendo `120x^2`

```
p = Monomial(2, 5)

print('Polinômio:', p)  # Polinômio: 2x^5

print('Derivada de ordem 1:', diff(p, 1))  # Derivada de ordem 1: 10x^4
print('Derivada de ordem 2:', diff(p, 2))  # Derivada de ordem 2: 40x^3
print('Derivada de ordem 3:', diff(p, 3))  # Derivada de ordem 3: 120x^2
print('Derivada de ordem 4:', diff(p, 4))  # Derivada de ordem 4: 240x^1
print('Derivada de ordem 5:', diff(p, 5))  # Derivada de ordem 5: 240x^0
print('Derivada de ordem 6:', diff(p, 6))  # Derivada de ordem 6: 0x^-1
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/Derivada-recursiva-de-monomio)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, consegui resolver meus exercícios, sua demonstração me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Eu vi esse monômio surgindo de um polinômio...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Shhhh, ninguém viu nada...