# Chamada de funções pelo shell

Tags: python

Escreva a função `maior_primo` que recebe um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve o maior número primo menor ou igual ao número passado à função.

Exemplos de execução no shell do Python:

```
>>> maior_primo(100)
97

>>> maior_primo(7)
7
```

Dica: escreva uma função `éPrimo(k)` e faça um laço percorrendo os números até o número dado checando se o número é primo ou não; se for, guarde numa variável. Ao fim do laço, o valor armazenado na variável é o maior primo encontrado.

Pela IDE eu fiz de um jeito e deu certo, porém o exercício obriga que seja pelo *shell* e não dá certo.

Meu código está assim:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------
def eh_primo(n):

    primo = True
    i = 2
    while i <= n/2 and primo:
        if n % i == 0:
            primo = False
            n = int(input("Digite um inteiro: "))
        i += 1

    return primo

#-----------------------------------------------------

def maior_primo(x, y):
    if eh_primo(x > y):
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "chamada pelo shell"? Na sua função `maior_primo`, a expressão `eh_primo(x > y)` não faz sentido; o que queria fazer aqui? E perceba que a função `maior_primo` deveria receber apenas um parâmetro, por que definiu com dois? Quem são `x` e `y` nesse contexto?

Comment: O exercício propõe comparar dois números inteiros que sejam primos e precisa de duas funções, uma para checar se o número e primo e uma outra entre qual é o maior, seria executar o script pelo shell do python padrão, e fazer uma chamada dela por exemplo: maior_primo(11, 23), e ele deve checar se ambos os parâmetros são primos e qual dentre eles é o maior e se um dos parâmetros nao for primo o usuário deve inserir um novo valor até que ele seja primo e depois que virar primo ele checar qual é o maior

Comment: Acho que você entendeu errado o problema. Ele pede que a entrada seja um número inteiro e que o retorno seja o maior número primo que seja menor ou igual ao valor de entrada. Não precisa comparar dois números primos. As duas funções precisam, de fato, mas recomendo que faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878); parece que você não entendeu direito nem o que seu próprio código faz, quem sabe o teste lhe ajude nisso. Outra coisa que não fez sentido foi ler o valor de `n` dentro da função `eh_primo`. Se recebe ele por parâmetro, por que precisa lê-lo novamente?