# Chamar um objeto de uma matriz pelo índice em um laço

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa matriz:

```
r = {
    br : {x:2, y:0, z:4},
    pr : {x:2, y:1, z:5},
    ou : {x:1, y:1, z:6},
    pl : {x:1, y:1, z:7},
    di : {x:1, y:1, z:7}
    }

w = 0.5
```

E esse laço que faz um cálculo:

```
for (var t = 0; t < r.length; t++) {
    p = p + (r. *** .x * w) - (r. *** .y * (1-w));  
    console.log(p);
}
```

Qual a forma correta ali no `***`? Não estou sabendo referenciar o objeto corretamente com o índice percorrido. Estou perguntando isso, porque por exemplo se eu chamar o objeto `r.br.x` ele traz o resultado 2 (mas não sei se ali pode dessa forma também ou o jeito certo).

Fazer isso com `forEach` seria mais adequado e melhor? Se possível também alguém poderia me mostrar um exemplo como ficaria nesse caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você tem não é uma matriz, e sim um objeto: um [conjunto de pares "chave/valor"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-type), delimitado por chaves (`{` e `}`).

No caso, as chaves são `br`, `pr`, etc. E o respectivo valor de cada uma dessas chaves é outro objeto (cujas chaves são `x`, `y` e z`,` cada uma com um valor numérico).

Para iterar pelo objeto `r`, você pode usar [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e em seguida usar um [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para percorrer as chaves. Para acessar o valor de cada chave, use colchetes (`r[chave]`):

```js
let r = {
    br : {x:2, y:0, z:4},
    pr : {x:2, y:1, z:5},
    ou : {x:1, y:1, z:6},
    pl : {x:1, y:1, z:7},
    di : {x:1, y:1, z:7}
};

let w = 0.5;
let p = 0;
Object.keys(r).forEach(k => {
    p = p + (r[k].x * w) - (r[k].y * (1-w));  
    console.log(p);
});
```

Se bem que neste caso você só parece estar interessado no valor e não na chave, então pode usar [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), que obtém cada valor diretamente:

```js
let r = {
    br : {x:2, y:0, z:4},
    pr : {x:2, y:1, z:5},
    ou : {x:1, y:1, z:6},
    pl : {x:1, y:1, z:7},
    di : {x:1, y:1, z:7}
};

let w = 0.5;
let p = 0;
Object.values(r).forEach(v => {
    p = p + (v.x * w) - (v.y * (1-w));  
    console.log(p);
});
```

---

Em JavaScript não existem matrizes de fato, o que se faz geralmente é usar um [array de arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/966225) (embora [existam bibliotecas para trabalhar com matrizes](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html)).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu queria que incrementasse, é a lógica do meu código está errada?

Comment: @Pedro O código incrementa o valor de `p`, mas se vc fizer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) irá perceber que quando x e y são iguais a 1, o valor de `(v.x * w) - (v.y * (1-w))` é igual a zero (a expressão fica `(1 * 0.5) - (1 * (1 - 0.5))`, que é zero). Então para as chaves `ou`,  `pl` e `di` (que possuem x e y iguais a 1), o valor somado a `p` será zero. Se é essa conta mesmo que era pra fazer, então está certo. Senão, basta mudar a conta, pois o restante do código (para percorrer todos os valores e ir somando em `p`) está certo

Comment: Na verdade, sempre que x e y forem iguais, o valor de `(v.x * w) - (v.y * (1-w))` será zero - isso acontece porque `w` é 0.5, então `1 - w` também é 0.5, por isso quando x e y são iguais, a expressão fica `(valor * 0.5) - (valor * 0.5)`, que sempre será zero. Não sei se é esse mesmo o seu problema, mas enfim, o código fornecido percorre todos os valores do objeto e vai somando em `p`. Se as contas deveriam dar zero ou não, é outra história...

Answer (score 0):

Seu objeto não parece ser uma matriz, visto que possui atributos nomeados. Portanto para conseguir iterá-lo você precisará obter suas chaves com o [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ou seus valores com [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) e com realizar o cálculo:

```
const calcular = (acumulador, x, y, w) => acumulador + (x * w) - (y * (1 - w));

const percorrer = (r, w) => Object.values(r).reduce((acumulador, { x, y }) => calcular(acumulador, x, y, w), 0);
```

Aplicando a seus valores:

```js
const calcular = (acumulador, x, y, w) => acumulador + (x * w) - (y * (1 - w));

const percorrer = (r, w) => Object.values(r).reduce((acumulador, { x, y }) => calcular(acumulador, x, y, w), 0);

// Exemplo de chamada das funções
const r = {
  br : {x:2, y:0, z:4},
  pr : {x:2, y:1, z:5},
  ou : {x:1, y:1, z:6},
  pl : {x:1, y:1, z:7},
  di : {x:1, y:1, z:7}
};

const w = 0.5;

console.log(percorrer(r, w));
```

> [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
>
> O método `Object.keys()` retorna um array de propriedades enumeráveis de um determinado objeto, na mesma ordem em que é fornecida por um laço [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (a diferença é que um laço for-in  enumera propriedades que estejam na cadeia de protótipos).

---

> [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> O método `Object.values()` retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem provida pelo [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) laço (sendo a diferença que o laço for-in também enumera as propriedades na cadeia protótipos).

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```