# Função fatorial passada com referencia

Tags: c, ponteiro, recursão, fatorial

Boa tarde senhores

Eu preciso fazer um algoritmo com um procedimento que receba uma variável por referência e depois atualize o valor da variável para o seu fatorial correspondente.

Esse é o algoritmo que eu fiz:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fatorial(int *n){
    if ((*n==1) || (*n==0)) return 1;               
    else return fatorial(*n-1)*n;
}
int main(){
    int n = 5;
    printf("%d\n",fatorial (&n));
}
```

Porém está dando erro na linha:

```
else return fatorial(*n-1)*n;
```

Erro:

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'fatorial' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
[Error] invalid operands to binary * (have 'int' and 'int *')
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Comment: o argumento precisa ser um ponteiro?

Comment: sim... Precisa passar o endereço de memória do n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua pergunta há muito bem descrito justamente aquilo que você não implementou:

> ... receba uma variável por referência e depois **atualize o valor da variável**...

Se está recebendo por referência e precisa alterar a própria referência, a função não retornará o resultado, mas sim deve atribuir o resultado no próprio ponteiro.

```
void fatorial(int* n) {
    int temp, resultado = 1;

    if (*n > 1) {
        temp = *n - 1;
        fatorial(&temp);
        resultado = (*n) * temp;
    }

    *n = resultado;
}
```

Assim, ao fazer, por exemplo:

```
int n = 5;
fatorial(&n);

printf("%d", n);
```

Será exibido o valor 120, referente ao valor de 5! calculado.

A ideia do código é:

1. Define as variáveis `temp`, que armazenará o resultado de `fatorial(n-1)` se necessário, e `resultado`, que armazenará o resultado final;
2. Se o valor de `n` for maior que 1, calcula o fatorial de maneira recursiva;
3. Define o valor de `temp` como sendo o valor de `n` decrementado em 1;
4. Chama a função de `fatorial` passando a referência de `temp`, assim `temp` possuirá o valor do fatorial de `n-1`;
5. Define o valor do resultado como o valor de `n` multiplicado pelo valor de `temp`;
6. Atualiza o valor da referência com o valor de `resultado`;

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu mas, eu nao entendi direito como esse algoritmo funciona, poderia me explicar?

Comment: @Arthur Qual parte não entendeu?

Comment: você chama a função fatorial passando o &temp?

Comment: e o *n se torna o &temp 

no final o temp vai valer 0 pq vai ficar -1 até o n for > 1 o que nao faz sentido, pq ai o *n vai valer 1, result vai ser 1*0 .............................. como chegou a 120?

Comment: @Arthur Sim, pois defini que `temp` é `n-1`, assim ele calculará o valor de `fatorial(n-1)`.

Comment: mas a linha resultado = (*n) * temp; nunca sera executada

Comment: pois antes dela sempre chamara a funcao fatorial

Comment: vai ficar chamando a funcao fatorial ate o *n ser menor que 1
quando for menor nao vai entrar no if ......  e essa linha nunca vai rodar

Comment: @Arthur Será executada sim, pois, como era esperado, a função recursiva possui uma condição de parada. Se `*n` é 1, não será feita a chamada recursiva. Recomendo que você tente construir o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para entender melhor

Comment: eu estou fazendo e... o resultado deu 1
no final de tudo o *n deu 1 e o tempo 0 ...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92842/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-arthur).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int *a,int *p) {
    while(*a>1){
            *p*=*a;
            *a=*a-1;
            }
    }
 int main() {
        int num, factorial=1,c,*p;
        p=&factorial;
        printf("entre um numero:");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        fact(&num,p);
        printf("fatorial do numero é:%d",*p);

        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Precisa passar o n por referencia

Comment: O que são `a` e `p` da função?

Answer (score -1):

**Implementação de fatorial em C:**

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n >= 1)
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

O erro que tem é porque está a passar como parâmetro um int e precisa de passar uma referência de int pelo que tinha anteriormente

> int *n

**Passando por valor por referencia usando um loop:**

```
void factorial(int *f){
    int i, temp = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= *f; i++)
        temp = temp * i;
    *f = temp;
}
```

Comment: Desta maneira não funcionou...

Comment: O que não funcionou?

Comment: Precisa passar o endereço de memória do n

Comment: Pode fazer sem usar recursão e apenas usando um loop?

Comment: Não, precisa da recursão

Comment: e precisa passar o N por referencia

Comment: obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: de nada, hoje é você a precisar e outro dia posso ser eu ;)

Comment: Note que você tem o n parâmetro e outro n declarado como variável local.