# Verificar Números Pares

Tags: javascript

Preciso verificar os números pares entre `x` e `y`, porém quando executo o código ele fica carregando a página eternamente e mostra no console somente o número `x`. Estou rodando o código no Google Chrome.

```
function pares(x, y) {
    while (x <= y) {
      if (x % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(x);
        x++;
      }
    }
  }
  pares(32, 321);
```

Comment: Vc só incrementa x quando ele é par, aí ele passa a ser ímpar e nunca mais é incrementado (e por isso nunca sai do while). Faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220526/112052) no código e entenderá o problema :-)

Comment: Genial cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o incremento da variável "x" fora do seu IF. Altere o código da seguinte forma:

```js
function pares(x, y) {
    while (x <= y) {
      if (x % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(x);
        
      }
   x++;
    }
  }
  pares(32, 321);
```

Answer (score 4):

Como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380590/112052) já disse, bastava incrementar o `x` fora do `if`. Do jeito que está, seu código só incrementa `x` se ele for par. Mas aí ele passa a ser ímpar e nunca mais é incrementado (pois não entra mais no `if`), e por isso o `while` nunca termina.

---

Mas se você quer imprimir somente os números pares, não precisa incrementar `x` de um em um.

Basta você verificar se o primeiro número é par (se não for, incrementa), e a partir daí, basta ir somando de 2 em 2. Assim você já pula todos os ímpares, evitando `if`'s desnecessários dentro do `while`:

```js
function pares(x, y) {
    // verifica se x é par (se não for, soma 1)
    if (x % 2 != 0) {
        x++; // x passa a ser par
    }
    // nesse ponto eu garanti que x é par
    while (x <= y) {
        console.log(x);
        x += 2; // soma 2, assim já vai para o próximo número par
    }
}

pares(32, 321);
```

---

Obs: o *snippet* acima não está mostrando todas as linhas (no meu browser, está mostrando apenas do 222 ao 320). Mas você pode abrir o console do seu browser para ver toda a saída (pressione <kbd>F12</kbd> e escolha a aba "Console").