# Classe não conecta com PDO ao banco e outra classe no mesmo path sim

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

Tenho a alasse **conexao**:

```
<?php

namespace classes\conexao;

use PDO;

class Conexao {

    private static $instancia;
    private static $host = "localhost";
    private static $db = "mvc_crud";
    private static $user = "mvc_crud";
    private static $password = "mvc_crud";  

    private function __construct (){}

    private static function obtemConexao() {

        if ( !isset( self::$instancia ) ) {

            try {

                self::$instancia = new \PDO ('mysql:host=' . self::$host . ';dbname=' . self::$db ,  self::$user, self::$password);
                self::$instancia->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                self::$instancia->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

            } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

                throw new PDOException( "Reveja suas credênciais de conexão ao banco de dados!<br />Contate o administrador!" );

                return;

            }

            return self::$instancia;
        }

    }

    public static function abreConexao () { return self::obtemConexao(); }

}
```

?>
Não consigo instanciá-la 2 vezes

Comment: Eu sei que não é recomendado isso, mas e se você testar, colocando ```$this->pdo = Conexao::abreConexao();``` dentro da função incluir, pra ver se está pegando a conexão?

Comment: A sua classe `Conexao` está errada.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin: Conexao::abreConexao(); dá NULL.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acho que não esteja errada senão a outra classe não funcionaria. Não é não?

Comment: Não. É justamente esse o erro: ela só funciona na primeira chamada. Se você [edit] a pergunta, adicionar o código dela (e remover tudo o que tem agora), poderei explicar/responder.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, entendi, adicionei ao final da pergunta a classe conexão

Comment: Editei a pergunta removendo todo o ruído. Isso é fazer um **exemplo mínimo**.

Comment: PDO ou mysqli? Na classe de conexão está usando mysqli para conectar...

Comment: Você está chamando o método `abreConexao` como se fosse estático porém não é

Comment: Por favor, podem me perdoar? Coloquei a classe errada na pergunta. Agora acertei a classe lá. É nessa que o erro ocorre. Podem olhar mais uma vez? @AndersonCarlosWoss,

Comment: Consegue fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) da função `obtemConexao`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss. Coloquei a classe de visão (View) no final da pergunta. Note que a classe pdo é chamada algumas vezes e nenhuma delas dá isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é simples: no método `Conexao::obtemConexao`, se `self::$instancia` estiver definido, o método não possui retorno, por isso na primeira chamada, quando não está definido, retorna corretamente, mas nas próximas o retorno é `null`.

```
private static function obtemConexao() {

    if ( !isset( self::$instancia ) ) {

        try {

            self::$instancia = new \PDO ('mysql:host=' . self::$host . ';dbname=' . self::$db ,  self::$user, self::$password);
            self::$instancia->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            self::$instancia->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

        } catch ( PDOException $e ) {

            throw new PDOException( "Reveja suas credênciais de conexão ao banco de dados!<br />Contate o administrador!" );

            return;

        }

        return self::$instancia;
    }

}
```

Comment: então pasando return self::$instancia; para fora do if vai funcionar

Comment: @CarlosRocha Essa pergunta já devia estar marcada como resolvida ou fechada a algum tempo. O que aconteceu?

Comment: Peço minhas sinceras desculpas, mas eu tenho quase certeza que já havia marcado ela como resolvida e te agradecido aqui. Mas vai lá. Obrigado pelo lembrete.