# Por que entra no if mesmo sendo false?

Tags: java, if

Mesmo a condição sendo falsa, ele entra no `if`, atribuindo sempre a última posição nos dois casos.

Porém, ao atribuir a variável do `for` no índice da variável `notas`, funciona corretamente.

Para esse código funcionar, eu adicionei essas linhas marcadas com comentário, porém estão "inúteis" no código, já que só com a posição iria me atender. Mas sem elas não funciona corretamente.

```
class Exer8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double maiorValor = 0; /* ESTA */
        int indMaior = 0;
        double menorValor = 10; /* ESTA */
        int indMenor = 0;
        double[] notas = {8, 5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 5};

        for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {

            if (maiorValor < notas[i]) {
                maiorValor = notas[i]; /* ESTA */
                indMaior = i;
            }
            if (menorValor > notas[i]) {
                menorValor = notas[i]; /* ESTA */
                indMenor = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("A maior nota é " + notas[indMaior] + ", Posição: " + indMaior);
        System.out.println("A menor nota é " + notas[indMenor] + ", Posição: " + indMenor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, se entra no `if` claramente não é `false`, você acha que é, mas não é. Segundo, estas linhas não tem nada de inúteis, elas são fundamentais, se elas não existiam o código está estava errada, e se só adicionou- as e não fez mais nada o código nem compilava.

Comment: Uma dica para verificar o que o código está fazendo é realizar o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do `if` você altera apenas o valor da `indMaior` sem alterar o valor da `maiorValor`.
Ou seja, SEMPRE que chega nesse `if` ele faz `if(0 < notas[i])`, como não existe nenhum valor menor ou igual a 0 no array, sempre será `true`.

Como o @Maniero disse nos comentários, essas linhas são na verdade fundamentais.

Comment: nossa, vdd, nem me atentei a isso.
Mexi e mexi tanto que esqueci da condicional. Obrigado.
Aprendendo e apanhando com o que ta na cara kkkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer a mesma coisa economizando algumas variáveis e atribuições.

Veja:

```
class Exer8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int indMaior = 0;
        int indMenor = 0;
        double[] notas = {8, 5, 7, 2, 10, 3, 5};

        for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {

            if (notas[indMaior] < notas[i]) {
                indMaior = i;
            }
            if (notas[indMenor] > notas[i]) {
                indMenor = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("A maior nota é " + notas[indMaior] + ", Posição: " + indMaior);
        System.out.println("A menor nota é " + notas[indMenor] + ", Posição: " + indMenor);
    }
}
```

Neste caso, só utilizei o índice do elemento no array. 
Quando é identificado que aquele elemento do array atende a condição de maior ou menor. 
É passado o índice para o respectivo índice `indMaior` ou `indMenor`.

Espero ter contribuído.

Comment: Obrigado. Realmente desse jeito o codigo fica muito melhor.