# Preciso de uma ajuda em pilhas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso criar uma nova lista com os valores de uma string, sem repetir o algarismo anterior. Se fosse somente não colocar valores duplicados, seria mais fácil, mas a regra é não repetir  o valor anterior.

```
a = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'
b = 'ABBCcAD'
c = [1,2,2,3,3]
pilha = []
for ind, letra in enumerate(a):
    if ind <= 0:
        pilha.append(letra)
    elif len(pilha) > 0:
        pilha.append(letra)
        if letra == pilha[ind-1]:
            pilha.pop()

print(pilha)
```

Essas variáveis são para teste.

Comment: Esse segundo código não parece estar relacionado com a pergunta, então ele só está adicionando ruído a ela. Quanto ao seu código inicial, está um tanto estranho, principalmente a condição para executar o pop. Você está usando o valor de `ind` para verificar a pilha, mas `ind` é o índice da sua string de entrada. Para verificar se deve efetuar o pop você deve comparar com o penúltimo valor da pilha com `pilha[-2]`

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, realmente trocar o (ind-1) pelo -2 funcionou. Pelo que eu entendi, o ultimo seria -1, e o penúltimo seria -2. Mas quero realmente entender, como o ind-1 está fora do range da minha pilha, já que tem um item lá. que é o primeiro. Você tem alguma lugar aonde posso me aprofundar sobre esse assunto? Estou tentado resolver esses problemas que vejo no youtube sobre pilhas, para eu entender melhor, mas pelo seu relato, percebo que não estou saindo do lugar. Poderia me dar feedback? Muitíssimo obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) e acompanhe o valor de `ind` que entenderá.

Comment: Veja seu código rodando no [Python Tutor](https://bit.ly/2kmAitY) pra entender onde está o erro do código...