# Fazer uma aplicação para ler 6 valores. Calcular e mostrar

Tags: php

Fazer uma aplicação para ler 6 valores. Calcular e mostrar:

**a)** A sequencia digitada;
**b)** a média dos mesmos;
**c)** os valores que estiverem acima da média.

Eu consigo imprimir a sequencia, consigo somar, mas não esta batendo a media, e não estou conseguindo fazer ele de maneira coerente!

**Meu código até agora**

```
<?php
$valores = array();
$media   = 0;
$soma    = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    printf("Digite um valor:");
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d \n", $valores[$i]);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    printf("$valores[$i] \n");
    if ($media < $valores[$i]) {
        $soma  = $soma + $valores[$i];
        $media = $soma / 6;
        if ($valores[$i] >= $media) {
            $acimaM = $valores[$i];
            printf("E os valores acima da media sao " . $acimaM[$i]);
        }
    }
}
printf("A media e " . $media . "\n");
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? O que já tentou?

Comment: eu consigo imprimir a sequencia, consigo somar, mas nao esta batendo a media, e nao estou conseguindo fazer ele de maneira coerente!

Comment: <?php
$valores = array();
$media = 0;
$soma = 0;
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    printf("Digite um valor:");
    fscanf(STDIN,"%d \n", $valores[$i]);
}
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    printf("$valores[$i] \n");
    if($media < $valores[$i]){
        $soma =  $soma + $valores[$i];
        $media = $soma/6;
        if($valores[$i]>= $media){
            $acimaM = $valores[$i];
            printf("E os valores acima da media sao ".$acimaM[$i]);
        }
         
    }
}
printf("A media e ".$media."\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua lógica para calcular a média está bastante confusa e para mim fez sentido algum ao ponto de eu achar o código foi escrito quase que aleatoriamente sem ser pensado antes.

Então para entender o que foi feito e perceber como está confuso recomendo que faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878). Com ele você perceberá exatamente o que seu código está fazendo e poderá comparar com o que ele deveria estar fazendo.

Como alternativa, você pode resolver o problema assim:

```php
$valores = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    printf("Digite um valor:");
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $valores[$i]);
}

$soma  = array_sum($valores);
$media = $soma / 6;

$valoresAcimaDaMedia = array_filter($valores, function ($valor) use ($media) {
    return $valor >= $media;
});

print_r($valoresAcimaDaMedia);
```

Se você informar as entradas 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6, a média será 3.5 e, portanto, serão exibidos os valores 4, 5 e 6 como saída.