# Meu programa parece não estar correto, o que melhorar?

Tags: python, algoritmo

```
maior50 = menor20 = maior10 = 0
x = 1

while x <= 20:
    idad = int(input("Digite sua idade:"))
    alt = float(input("Digite sua altura:"))
    peso = float(input("Digite seu peso:"))
    x = x + 1
    if idad >= 50:
         maior50 += 1
    if idad <= 20:
         menor20 += 1
    elif idad >= 10:
         maior10 += 1
    if idad < 40:
        medpeso = peso * 20 / 100

med = maior10 + menor20 / 2

print(f"Total de pessoas maiores de 50 Anos: {maior50}")
print("A média das alturas das pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos é:%d"%med)
print("A porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 quilos entre todas as pessoas é:%d"%medpeso)
```

Desenvolver um programa que leia a idade, a altura e o peso de 20 pessoas. Valide a entrada de dados. Este programa deverá calcular e mostrar:

- a) A quantidade de pessoas com idade superior a 50 anos;
- b) A média das alturas das pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos;
- c) A porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 quilos entre todas as pessoas.

Gostaria de saber se da forma que fiz está correta.

Comment: Não e eu recomendaria que você fizesse um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para entender o que o seu código faz.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não, e deveria ser óbvio.

A letra C pede para dar a porcentagem, em nenhum momento você calcula porcentagem de nada, calcula algo que eu nem imagino o que seja, dá para inferir que está considerando que a média é último peso entrado aplicando 20%. Ela fala para considerar as pessoas com até 40 quilos, por alguma razão você resolveu considerar as pessoas com idade menor que 40 anos. Isto é matemática e interpretação de texto e não programação.

A letra B diz que a média deve ser das pessoas entre uma faixa de idade, no caso entre 10 e 20 (não fala se é inclusivo ou exclusivo), e fez duas coisas distintas, uma para quem tem até 20, incluindo as que tem menos de 10 e fez outra para as pessoas que tem pelo menos 10, incluindo as que tem mais de 20. E ainda está contando quantas pessoas tem, o que está certo, mas onde está acumulando as alturas para poder fazer o cálculo de média? E nem precisa dizer que o cálculo da média está errado porque sequer tem os dados das alturas, tem apenas quantas pessoas se encaixas nos dois critérios sem sentido. Mais ainda se é a média das pessoas com essas idade então deveria dividir pelo contador de pessoas e não por 2. Estudo lógica booleana para criar condições apropriadas para filtrar o que entra no cálculo e reveja como se calcula média (matemática básica).

A letra A parece certa, embora o requisito seja ambíguo, então pode ter um erro e não ter que comparar com maior ou igual e ser só o maior, mas aí depende de como se interpeta um texto não muito claro.

Portanto está bastante incorreto. Seria fácil identificar isso porque fazendo matematicamente dá um resultado muito diferente da programação. Um código deve fazer o que já se sabe fazer no papel.

Comment: Boa noite! ainda sou iniciante e, gostaria de saber se dessa mudança há erros?

Comment: Na verdade você não pode mudar a pergunta, uma vez feita o conteúdo deve ser o mesmo, pode editar pra formatar, corrigir um erro ortográfico, deixar mais limpo, mas não trocar a pergunta. Eu reverti. Faça outra pergunta.