# Função para calcular a distância entre dois pontos

Tags: javascript

```
//D = raizQuadrada( (x2 - x1)² + (y2 - y1)²)
function calculoX(x1, x2){
    var x1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de x1: "));
    var x2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de x2: "));
    console.log("Valor de X1: " + x1);
    console.log("Valor de X2: " + x2);
    var x3 = Math.pow(x2, 2) - Math.pow(x1, 2);
    return x3;

}
 function calculoY(y1, y2){
    var y1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de y1: "));
    var y2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de y2: "));
    var y3 = (Math.pow(y2, 2)) - (Math.pow(y1, 2));
    console.log("Valor de Y1: " + y1);
    console.log("Valor de Y2: " + y1);
    return y3;
}

 function distancia(x, y){
    var res = Math.sqrt((x + y));
    return res;
}
var x = calculoX();
var y = calculoY();
var d = distancia(x, y);

document.write("Valor final é: " + d);
```

Como posso melhorar esse código?

Algumas entradas dão alguns erros no resultado final (como `x1 = 7`, `x2= 4`, `y1 = 5`, `y2 = 5`) e me retornam [`NaN`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), por que isso acontece?

Referência: [PUCRS](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Exercicios/SeqDecisao/lista1.htm)

Comment: Qual é a idea de ter `function calculoX(x1, x2){` e depois re-escrever essas variáveis `x1`, `x2` dentro da função?

Comment: Vc está fazendo "x2 ao quadrado menos x1 ao quadrado", que é diferente de "(x2 - x1) ao quadrado". O mesmo para y1 e y2. Não vi o restante do código pra ver se tem mais erros, mas eu começaria por aí...

Comment: Outra dica é fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), pois aí vc perceberá que para x1=7 e x2=4, calculoX() retorna 4^2 - 7^2 = -33. E como y1 e y2 são iguais, calculoY() retorna zero. Depois vc calcula a raiz quadrada de x + y (que é -33), e [raiz quadrada de número negativo resulta em NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt#Return_value)

Comment: @hkotsubo me confundi na regra de matemática, eu pensava que ambos eram multiplicados ao quadrado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O cálculo não está sendo feito da maneira correta:

```
Math.pow(x2, 2) - Math.pow(x1, 2);
```

`Math.pow(x2, 2)` calcula `x2` ao quadrado, então na verdade você está fazendo `x2² - x1²`. Mas o que você quer é `(x2 - x1)²`, então o certo seria:

```
Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
```

O mesmo vale para `y1` e `y2`. E da forma que este cálculo é feito, `x + y` pode resultar em um número negativo (como é o caso dos números que você colocou na pergunta), e [quando o número é negativo, `Math.sqrt` retorna `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt#Return_value).

---

Outro detalhe é que você declara a função com dois parâmetros:

```
function calculoX(x1, x2)
```

Mas dentro da função você sobrescreve esses valores, então eles na verdade não estão servindo para nada. Você tem que decidir se lê os valores dentro da função, ou se lê fora dela e passa-os como parâmetros.

Outra coisa, você reparou que o cálculo feito para `x1` e `x2` é o mesmo que deve ser feito para `y1` e `y2`? Então não tem porque criar duas funcões praticamente idênticas. A ideia de funções é justamente executar algo que deve ser feito do mesmo jeito, podendo haver alguma variação conforme os valores dos parâmetros. Então você poderia criar um única função que recebe um parâmetro indicando se estou trabalhando com os valores de `x` ou `y` (mais ou menos como sugerido na [resposta do Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415550/112052), com o detalhe que ele não corrigiu o cálculo):

```js
function calculo(variavel){
    let x1 = parseInt(prompt(`Digite o valor de ${variavel}1: `));
    let x2 = parseInt(prompt(`Digite o valor de ${variavel}2: `));
    return Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
}

let x = calculo('x');
let y = calculo('y');

let distancia = Math.sqrt(x + y);
console.log(`Distância: ${distancia}`);
```

---

Mas talvez nem precise dessas funções, afinal você só precisa disso:

```js
let x1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x1: '));
let x2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x2: '));
let y1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y1: '));
let y2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y2: '));

let distancia = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) );
console.log(`Distância: ${distancia}`);
```

Ah sim, repare também que tanto faz usar `x1 - x2` ou `x2 - x1`, pois como estou elevando ao quadrado, o resultado será o mesmo.

---

Se quiser, você pode até fazer uma função para validar se foi realmente digitado um número. Por exemplo:

```js
function lerNumero(variavel) {
    while (true) {
        let valor = parseInt(prompt(`Digite o valor de ${variavel}: `));
        if (isNaN(valor)) {
            console.log('Valor não é um número');
        } else {
            return valor;
        }
    }
}

let x1 = lerNumero('x1');
let x2 = lerNumero('x2');
let y1 = lerNumero('y1');
let y2 = lerNumero('y2');

let distancia = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) );
console.log(`Distância: ${distancia}`);
```

Por fim, você pode ainda trocar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) por [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), se quiser aceitar números com casas decimais.

---

E nas versões mais novas da linguagem, você pode usar o [operador de exponenciação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) `**` (em vez de `Math.pow`), recurso [já suportado pelos *browsers*](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-exponentiation_(**)_operator):

```js
let x1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x1: '));
let x2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x2: '));
let y1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y1: '));
let y2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y2: '));

// elevar a 0.5 é o mesmo que obter a raiz quadrada
let distancia = ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5;
console.log(`Distância: ${distancia}`);
```

Comment: Excelente explicação @hkotsubo, e mostrou onde eu estou/estava errando. +1

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para complementar a resposta que já explica alguns pontos em relação ao código original, dá para encurtar ainda mais a parte do cálculo da distância propriamente dita.

Isso porque, a rigor, o próprio JavaScript já implementa o cálculo para determinar essa distância. A função é qualificada como `hypot`, no objeto global `Math`.

Como a distância entre dois pontos nada mais é que a hipotenusa de um triângulo retângulo, podemos utilizar [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot). É trivial:

```
Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
```

No exemplo já fornecido:

```js
let x1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x1: '));
let y1 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y1: '));
let x2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de x2: '));
let y2 = parseInt(prompt('Digite o valor de y2: '));

let dist = Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
console.log(`Distância: ${dist}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pode melhorar o código reutilizando a função de calculo.

E o NAN ocorre pois o valor informado para Math.sqrt é negativo, utilizando o Math.abs pode ser retirado o sinal do número, sempre retornando o valor positivo.

```
function calculo(letter){
    var x1 = parseInt(prompt(`Digite o valor de ${letter}1: `));
    var x2 = parseInt(prompt(`Digite o valor de ${letter}2: `));
    var x3 = Math.pow(x2, 2) - Math.pow(x1, 2);
    return Math.abs(x3);
}

function distancia(x, y){
    var res = Math.sqrt(x + y);
    return res;
}
var x = calculo("x");
var y = calculo("y");
var d = distancia(x, y);
```