# Imprimir o intervalo aberto entre dois números em ordem decrescente

Tags: python, python-3.x

No código abaixo, eu consigo fazer com que não mostre valor da variável `a`, mas a variável `b` acaba saindo no `print`.

A resposta esperada seria o intervalo aberto `]A..B[`.

Ex: variável a = 10 e variável b = 5.

Resposta esperada: `9,8,7,6`

Resposta obtida: `9,8,7,6,5`. Sendo que o valores informados no `input` para serem exibidos, o valor da variável `a` consigo fazer para que não seja exibida no `print`, mas o valor de `b` sempre acaba saindo.

```py
a = int(input('Valor de a tem que ser maior do que b: '))
b = int(input('Valor de b tem que ser menor do que a: '))

cont = a #Estou fazendo que a var cont receba o valor de a

if a > b and b < a: # O if estou verificando se a é maior do que b e b é menor que a
    while cont > b: # condição para o while é enquanto contador for maior que b vai repetir
        cont = cont - 1 # estou fazendo para que cont receba cont -1
        print(cont) # exibindo cont na tela
        a = a - 1 # estou fazendo que a receba a - 1 para que no cont fique com o valor de a, e depois ele subtraia - 1
```

Comment: Recomendo que você pesquise como se usa um debugger com o python, desta forma você poderá análisar o fluxo do seu programa passo a passo e quem sabe ver o que está dando errado. Não sei que editor estás usando, mas uma das formas mais fáceis de debugar python é usando o editor VSCode, clicando na engrenagem. A partir da interface original do python (a IDLE) você não vai conseguir fazer o debug...

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Qual foi o obtido? Por que o valor de `a` muda durante o *loop*?

Comment: Esse `if` está estranho. Se você já verificou `a >= b`, não precisa verificar `b <= a`, é redundante. A condição do `while` também está estranha, pois `cont` começa com o mesmo valor de `a` e dentro do loop ambos são decrementados, então `cont <= a` sempre será verdadeiro.

Comment: Gabriel - mesmo o programa sendo seu, e você snedo o único usuário, um `input()` sem nada e você ter que adivinar que vai digitar um número maior e depois um número menor, sem nada na tela é algo bem ruim de usar. EM Python, o `input` já aceita uma string que pode imprimir instruções sobre o que está sendo digitado - sugiro que use, e vá aprendendo a valorizar a "experiência do usuário" - mesmo que o usuário seja só você. 

COntinuando - se você colocar uns "prints" no "else" do "if" , e outros dentro, vai entender melhor o que está fazendo aí.

Comment: obrigado galera pela ajuda. primeiro wkrueger, usei o debug e vi o passo a passo do algoritmo só que por exemplo eu coloco no valores na variável "a" = (10) e na variável "b" = (5), o resultado sai 9,8,7,6,5 só que o resultado esperado seria o intervalo aberto ]A..B[.

Comment: obrigado galera pela ajuda. segundo Anderson Carlos Woss, então o resultado esperado seria o intervalo aberto ]A..B[ por exemplo: variável "a" = (10) e na variável "b" = (5), ai gostaria de ter este resultado 9,8,7,6. e o resultado obtido foi 9,8,7,6,5 sendo que o valor de entrada da variável "b" está sendo exibido. e por quê o valor de "a" muda é porque foi único jeito que consegui fazer ele mostrar em contagem decrescente a = a - 1.

Comment: obrigado galera pela ajuda. terceiro hkotsubo, o pior é que eu sei disso cara... Só que foi só com essa condição que quase cheguei na resposta esperada, como fiquei sem opção recorri a perguntar para vocês por quê achei que fosse um programa simples e acabou que está ficando muito complicado.
Mas obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar melhorar a condições do if e while.

Comment: obrigado galera pela ajuda. quarto jsbueno, cara obrigado vou melhorar o código para melhor visualização, não coloquei antes por que tipo este é um programa para a faculdade e eles pedem para que nada seja colocado no input, ai pensei que estava bom assim, por achar que o programa seria fácil.
Mas vou melhorar o código.
 (É que estou começando agora)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quer iterar de um número a outro (não incluindo esses números), faça um *loop* simples:

```
a = 10
b = 5 
while a > b + 1:
    a -= 1
    print(a)
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/8OXiRz) o código rodando</sup>

O `while` continua executando enquanto `a` for maior que `b + 1` (a condição deve ser essa para que `b` não seja considerado). Dentro do *loop*, eu subtraio 1 de `a` e imprimo seu valor (nessa ordem, assim eu garanto que o `10` não fará parte da sequência). O código acima imprime os números 9, 8, 7 e 6, nesta ordem.

Repare que, a princípio, **você não precisa do `if`**. Se `a` for menor ou igual a `b + 1`, o código não vai entrar no `while`, então o `if` é redundante. Ele só seria necessário se você quisesse por exemplo tomar alguma ação caso `a` seja menor ou igual a `b + 1`. Ex:

```
if a > b + 1:
    while a > b + 1:
        a -= 1
        print(a)
else:
    print('O valor de a deve ser maior que b + 1')
```

Aí faz sentido ter o `if`. Senão, é só ruído. Repare que a condição é `if a > b + 1`, pois se fosse somente `if a > b`, poderia cair no caso em que `a` é 10 e `b` é 9, e nesse caso nenhum número será impresso (portanto, também deveria cair no `else`).

---

Também não há motivo para criar essa variável `cont`. Ok, *talvez* ela fosse necessária se você não quisesse alterar o valor de `a`, mas dentro do *loop* você altera o valor de `a` **e** de `cont`. Então dá para usar apenas a variável `a`.

Mas se quiser muito usar outra variável (talvez porque o valor de `a` não possa ser alterado, por exemplo), você poderia inicializá-la com o primeiro valor da sequência e fazer o *loop* assim:

```
a = 10
b = 5
n = a - 1
while n > b:
    print(n)
    n -= 1
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/TqB739) o código rodando</sup>

Tem outros detalhes que mudaram: agora a condição é `n > b` (e não `b + 1`), e dentro do *loop* eu imprimo o valor e depois subtraio 1. Repare que não é necessário subtrair 1 de `a`, pois ela não é usada dentro do *loop* e não há motivo nenhum para mudar seu valor.

Sugiro que faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) em ambos os códigos, para entender melhor como funcionam (porque em um a condição é `b + 1` e no outro é só `b`, por exemplo).

---

Pelo que vi nos comentários, isso é um exercício, então é bem provável que queiram que você faça um *loop* como o que está acima.

Mas em Python você também pode usar um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que representa justamente uma sequência de números:

```
a = 10
b = 5
for i in range(a - 1, b, -1):
    print(i)
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/X9ZxZ6) o código rodando</sup>

O primeiro parâmetro é o valor inicial (no caso, `a - 1`, já que o `a` não pode fazer parte da sequência).

O segundo parâmetro é o valor final, mas eu coloquei `b`, pois em um `range` o valor inicial é incluso, mas o valor final não. Então já é garantido que `b` não fará parte da sequência.

O terceiro parâmetro é o "passo". No caso, é `-1`, já que a sequência começa em `a - 1` e vai "andando" de -1 em -1, até chegar a `b`. O código acima também imprime os números 9, 8, 7 e 6, nesta ordem.

E nesse caso também não precisa do `if`, pois se `a` for menor que `b`, o `range` não terá nenhum número ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/tXV6GR)). O `if` só faz sentido se quiser tomar alguma ação específica caso os números sejam inválidos (como o exemplo acima, que mostra uma mensagem dizendo que `a` deve ser maior que `b + 1`).

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, você não sabe o quanto você me ajudou muito.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, você não sabe o quanto me ajudou.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela explicação foi muito detalhada vou prestar mais atenção no minhas condições a partir de agora.
(e eu aceitei a sua resposta.)
É que na verdade eu queria aceitar a duas respostas a sua e a do Jean que está logo a baixo, mas não deixa.

Comment: @Gabriel É, o sistema só deixa aceitar uma resposta. Mas quando vc tiver mais de 15 pontos, [poderá votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis

Comment: Entendi, obrigado de novo. E vou tentar ganhar esses 15 pontos para também aceitar a resposta do Jean.

Comment: @Gabriel Só para deixar claro, aceitar e votar são coisas diferentes. Vc só pode aceitar uma resposta (de uma pergunta que vc fez), mas pode votar em quantas quiser (independente de ter sido aceita ou não, independente de vc ser o autor da pergunta ou não).

Comment: Obrigado pelo reconhecimento Gabriel <3. Como o @hkotsubo disse, aceitar resposta e votar são coisas diferentes. Caso uma resposta relacionada à sua pergunta tenha solucionado seu problema por completo, você pode aceitar ela. Caso outra resposta tenha também te ajudado você pode votar ( é basicamente um like do stack overflow rs ). Enfim, espero que consiga logo os 15 pontos e evolua na plataforma kkk

Answer (score 0):

O problema acontece pois quando a variável `cont` é igual a `b + 1` ele continua dentro do while loop e recebe o valor dele menos 1 antes de ter seu valor impresso. Para resolver este problema, eu apenas adicionei `+1` na condição do while. Veja o código abaixo:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
cont = a
if a > b:
    while cont > b + 1:
        cont -= 1
        a -= 1
        print(cont)
```

Você pode simplificar bastante o código utilizando a função `range`. Veja o código abaixo:

```
a = int(input("Digite o valor de A: "))
b = int(input("Digite o valor de B: "))

for num in range(a-1,b,-1): 
    print(num)
```

A função `range` retorna um objeto iterável (sequência) com número de **a** à **b** num passo de **x**.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, você não sabe o quanto me ajudou.