# Tenho um trabalho em Python 3 e não sei como proceder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso fazer um algoritmo que solicite ao usuário números e os armazene em um vetor de 20 posições. Crie uma função que receba o vetor preenchido e substitua todas as ocorrências de valores negativos por 0, as de valores menores do que 10 por 1 e as demais por 2. Pesquisei bastante mas não consegui fazer o exercício

O que eu fiz até agora:

```py
  numeros = [int(input("Número: ")) for i in range(20)]

  numeros = [0 for item in numeros if item <= 0]
  numeros = [1 for item in numeros if item < 10]
  numeros = [2 for item in numeros if item >= 10]

  print(
      numeros
  )
```

O problema e a minha dúvida é que a parte de troca de valores do vetor não está funcionando, queria saber onde é que eu errei.

Comment: Separe os problemas em duas perguntas e detalhe o máximo que conseguir. Você conseguiria explicar exatamente o que você fez no seu código?

Comment: Leonardo, você precisar tentar fazer o problema e quando surgir uma dúvida você pesquisa aqui no site, pois é quase certo que alguém já teve sua dúvida. Se mesmo assim você não achar uma resposta, aí você abre uma pergunta com sua dúvida. Que parte do problema você não entendeu?

Comment: eu fiz um input para o usuário digitar os valores, e após isso eu tentei fazer com que todos os números menores ou iguais a 0 do vetor sejam trocados por 0, e a mesma coisa para os de baixo. Mas ao dar run após inserir os números o processo é finalizado e não funciona a parte de substituição de valores.

Comment: Você está reatribuindo a variável `numeros` toda vez; primeiro lendo os 20 números; segundo filtrando a lista de menores ou iguais a zero, substituindo o valor por 0 (ou seja, será uma lista somente de zeros); terceiro está substituindo todos os valores menores que 10 por 1, mas como a lista é inteira de zeros todos serão substituídos por um; quarto está substituindo valores maiores ou iguais a 10 por 2, mas como são todos 1 o resultado será uma lista vazia. Faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) para entender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está com vários problemas básicos. Por exemplo: Você está lendo 20 números no `for` inicial e depois inicializando 3 vezes seguidas a variável `numeros`.

O correto é fazer tudo dentro de um `for` e adicionar `0`, `1` ou `2` de acordo com alguns `if`s. Abaixo tem um código funcionando, mas não copie e cole apenas. Como é um trabalho de faculdade tente entender o que está acontecendo, e o principal: por que o seu não funcionou.

```
numeros = []

for i in range(20):
  x = int(input('digite um valor: '))
  if x <= 0:
    numeros.append(0)
  elif x < 10:
    numeros.append(1)
  else:
    numeros.append(2)

print(
    numeros
)
```

Aqui tem um [excelente curso inicial de Python](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHz_AreHm4dlKP6QQCekuIPky1CiwmdI6).

Answer (score -1):

Separe seu problema em micro-problemas, como o @Woss comentou. O que voce precisa para resolver esse problema?

- Criar uma lista vazia
- Solicitar 20 vezes para o usuario digitar os numeros. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?;
- A cada numero novo que o usuario digitar, coloque-o na lista. Utilize `append`;
- Depois das 20 iterações do usuário voce terá sua lista completa;
- Percorra sua lista recém criada, item a item. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?
- Enquanto percorre sua lista, faça condições para alterar seus valores, conforme o enunciado. (Aqui voce pode criar uma segunda lista para guardar o novo resultado ou alterar a lista existente);
- Dê um print na lista com os novos resultados para conferir.

----------------- ou ------------------

- Criar uma lista vazia
- Solicitar 20 vezes para o usuário digitar os números;
- A cada numero novo que o usuario digitar, realize as condições necessárias para já gravar o numero digitado substituído pela logica do enunciado;
- Dê um print na lista com os novos resultados para conferir.

Neste segundo exemplo, não foi feito exatamente o que estava no enunciado, por exemplo. Pois de acordo com "solicite ao usuário números e os armazene em um vetor de 20 posições", dá a entender que voce precisa criar uma lista com os numeros digitados pelo usuario antes de converte-los.

É mais ou menos isso que você precisa fazer. Claro que cada programador pode pensar em uma lógica diferente. Tente fazer parte por parte. E vá pesquisando o que não consegue aos poucos... Dividir um problema em varios te ajuda a entender melhor a lógica que precisa utilizar..