# Uma função de armazena elementos específicos de uma lista em outra lista

Tags: python, lista

Quero fazer uma função que recebe uma lista de números ordenados e dois números(um inferior e um superior) e que retorna uma lista nova com os elementos da primeira lista entre os dois números.

Exemplo:

```
lista inicial=[12,14,15,16,18,20,24,26,28,32,34,38]  
limite inferior=13  
limite superior = 26  
lista exibida: [14,15,16,18,20,24,26]
```

O que eu tentei fazer:

```py
def mudalista(l,li,ls):
    sublista=list()
    for el in l:
        if el>=li:
            pos_el1=l.index(el)
        elif el>=ls:
            pos_el2=l.index(el)
        sublista=l[pos_el1:pos_el2]     
    print(l[subslista])
    return
```

Tentei começar a função com "for el in l" e quando(`if`) o elemento fosse maior que o numero menor, armazenasse em uma variável, fazendo a mesma coisa com o superior(`elif`), mas quando vou tentar fazer a segunda lista, ele dá erro.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    mudalista([12,14,15,16,18,20,24,26,28,32,34,38],13,26)
  File "C:\Users\G1820583\Downloads\exercicio lista.py", line 11, in mudalista
    sublista=l[pos_el1:pos_el2]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos_el1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Guilherme, conhece [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)?

Comment: Não... vou ler sobre

Comment: Estude os métodos de lista do Python, mais precisamente como pegar segmentos dela e, claro, o método `index()`.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

```
import bisect

def intervalo(lista, i, j):
    left = bisect.bisect_left(lista, i)
    right = bisect.bisect(lista, j)

    return lista[left:right]
```

---

## Explicação

Repare neste trecho do seu código:

```
if el >= li:
    pos_el1 = l.index(el)
elif el >= ls:
    pos_el2 = l.index(el)
sublista = l[pos_el1:pos_el2]
```

O código acima tem 3 possibilidades:

1. `el >= li` então `pos_el1` é criado, pois entrou no 1º `if`;
2. `el >= ls` então `pos_el2` é criado, pois entrou no 2º `if`;
3. `el` é menor que ambos, `li` e `ls`, e nenhuma variável é criada pois não entrou em nenhum `if` e você apenas cria eles dentro destes `if`s.

Note que em nenhum fluxo possível deste código as variáveis `pos_el1` e `pos_el2` podem coexistir, ou apenas uma existe, ou apenas a outra, nunca ambas são criadas no mesmo fluxo.

Isso faz com que a linha posterior: `sublista = l[pos_el1:pos_el2]` obrigatoriamente dê erro, pois você está usando uma das variáveis que obrigatoriamente não será criada.

Possíveis soluções:

---

## List comprehension ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

A mais simples de todas poderia ser usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) filtrando apenas os itens que cumprirem sua condição. Como sua lista têm os valores ordenados, essa solução funciona bem:

```
def intervalo(lista, i, j):
    return [item for item in lista if i <= item <= j]

lista_inicial = [12,14,15,16,18,20,24,26,28,32,34,38]
intervalo(lista_inicial, 13, 26)
# [14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 26]
```

Se você ainda não conhece o conceito de *comprehensions*, uma versão equivalente usando `for` ficaria assim:

```
def intervalo(lista, i, j):
    resultado = []

    for item in lista:
        if if i <= item <= j:
            resultado.append(item)

    return resultado

lista_inicial = [12,14,15,16,18,20,24,26,28,32,34,38]
intervalo(lista_inicial, 13, 26)
# [14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 26]
```

---

## Slice ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice))

Pode-se usar [*slices*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), como você mesmo fez, mas é preciso tratar quando os valores procurados não existem na lista, pois se os valores que limitam seu intervalo não existirem na lista você vai ter que selecionar o índice mais próximo. Uma solução poderia ser:

```
def intervalo_slices(lista, i, j):
    left, right = 0, len(lista)

    for index, item in enumerate(lista):
        if item < i:
            # se for menor que o mínimo mostra do próximo em diante
            left = index + 1
        if item <= j:
            # Se for maior que o máximo mostra até o próximo índice
            right = index + 1

    return lista[left:right]
```

O algoritmo é simples:

1. Eu crio `left` e `right` com valores padrão `0` e o tamanho total da lista (`len(lista)`), dessa maneira se o fluxo não entrar em nenhum dos `if`s o resultado será `lista[0:len(lista)]` que é apenas uma cópia da lista original;
2. Uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para ter os índices dos itens que estou iterando e realizar os cálculos (semelhante ao `i` que vemos em laços `for` de outras linguagens);
3. Testo em todas as iterações se `item` é menor que o mínimo.
   Caso a condição seja verdadeira, significa que o limite inferior da nossa lista é o item seguinte, pois vai ser igual ou maior que `i`;
4. Testo em todas as iterações se `item` é menor ou igual ao máximo, se sim, o índice que eu quero também é o próximo, pois slices não incluem o valor da direita (ex: `[0, 1, 2, 3][:2]` resulta em `[0, 1]`);
5. Por fim retorno o [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) com os valores corretos

Se você der um `print` dentro dos `if` verá que `left` e `right` recebem valores várias vezes até que as condições deixem de serem verdadeiras. Não é uma solução muito otimizada, mas é um algoritmo mais "feito na mão" e eu queria mostrar o que deu errado com seu exemplo com uma possível solução para a sua linha de raciocínio.

Para uma solução mais otimizada nessa mesma linha de raciocínio, veja a próxima sessão.

---

## Módulo `bisect` ([#Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html))

Outra maneira de resolver o problema "qual índice da lista devo fazer slice" é usar um [algoritmo de pesquisa binário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria) para encontrar em qual posição da lista deve-se fazer o *slice*, mesmo que o valor não exista nesta lista.

O módulo [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) foi feito para trabalhar com sequências ordenadas e pesquisa binária, então podemos tirar proveito de um módulo nativo do python para resolver o problema com uma [complexidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo) de O(Log<sub>2</sub> n) ao invés de O(n) como os problemas anteriores.

Para isso usaremos as funções [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) e [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left). Ambas têm o mesmo propósito e funcionamento, elas servem para descobrir em qual posição de uma sequência ordenada um valor deve ser inserido para que seja mantida sua ordenação.

Por exemplo:

```
from bisect import bisect

lista = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10]
index = bisect(lista, 3)
# 2

lista.insert(index, 3)
# lista = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
#                └── posição retornada por bisect
```

Veja que `bisect` retornou o índice `2`, que é exatamente onde eu posso inserir o valor `3` na minha lista para que seja mantida a ordenação da mesma.

#### Mas pra que serve o `bisect_left`?

A funções [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) e [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) se diferenciam apenas **quando o valor procurado já existe na sequência**, ou seja, no exemplo anterior poderia ser usado [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) ou [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) pois o resultado seria o mesmo.

Quando procuramos o índice de inserção de um valor já existente na sequência ficamos com duas opções:

1. Inserir no mesmo índice do valor encontrado ([`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)).

   Para inserir o valor `1` na lista `[0, 1, 2, 3]`:

   ```
   #      ┌── valor encontrado
   [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
   #   └── novo valor
   ```
2. Inserir no próximo índice do valor encontrado ([`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect)).

   Para inserir o valor `1` na lista `[0, 1, 2, 3]`:

   ```
   #   ┌── valor encontrado
   [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
   #      └── novo valor
   ```

Em resumo, a diferença é se o índice retornado é o mesmo do valor encontrado ou o próximo. O código abaixo ilustra os exemplos citados acima:

```
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left

lista = [0, 1, 2, 3]
indice = bisect(lista, 1)
# 2
indice_left = bisect(lista, 1)
# 1
```

#### Código final usando `bisect`

Agora que você entendeu o conceito, bastaria usar o `bisect_left` para pegar corretamente o índice mínimo para usar no *slice* e `bisect` para pegar o índice máximo.

```
import bisect

def intervalo(lista, i, j):
    left = bisect.bisect_left(lista, i)
    right = bisect.bisect(lista, j)

    return lista[left:right]
```

---

### Conclusão

Estas são algumas formas de fazer o que você quer, apresentei o módulo `bisect` pois além de ser performático e interessante, acho importante para o apredizado termos exemplos de uso prático.

Criei este [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-420004-6333) com todos os exemplos rodando.

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro que você apresentou ocorre porque a variável `pos_el1` só é criada caso entre no `if el>=1`. Ou seja, se o programa não entrar nesse bloco, você tentará utilizar uma variável que não existe.

Há também alguns outros erros de lógica como por exemplo o bloco `if el>=li`. Caso o elemento seja maior que `li` o **menor** elemento será ele. Só que isso significa que o maior elemento da lista também será o menor, já que o maior elemento é maior que `li`.

Há também um problema ao utilizar slice para obter uma nova lista de números. Lembre-se que a posição final é uma posição de parada e o valor nessa posição não será retornado. Logo você deverá fazer com que a posição final seja a posição do maior elemento `+1`.

Veja esse código abaixo que eu fiz:

```
def mudaLista(lista,li,ls):

    menor_elemento = None
    maior_elemento = None

    for elemento in lista:

        if not menor_elemento and elemento >= li:
            menor_elemento = elemento

        if elemento <= ls:
            maior_elemento = elemento

    if menor_elemento and maior_elemento:

        pos_menor = lista.index(menor_elemento)
        pos_maior = lista.index(maior_elemento)

        return lista[pos_menor:pos_maior+1]

    else:
        return []

lista = [num for num in range(100)] #Gera uma lista com números de 1 à 100
li = 43
ls = 57
print(mudaLista(lista,li,ls)) # Saída: [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]
```