# Mostrar posição em python de apenas números primos

Tags: python, array

Leia 10 numeros inteiros e os armazene em um vetor. Em seguida escreva os elementos que sao primos e suas respectivas posiçoes no vetor

```
vetor=[]
for c in range(3):
    n = int(input("Digite um número para armazena-lo:"))
    divisores = 0
    for divisor in range(1, n):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            divisores += 1
    if divisores > 1:
        None
    else:
        vetor+=[n]
        index = vetor.index()
print(f'Os primos nesse vetor são {vetor}:{index}')
```

Não consigo mostrar a posição dos números primos.

Comment: Lucas, consegue fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código? Por que a variável `c` varia de 0 a 3? Qual seria a lógica do `None` quando há mais de um divisor? O que seria o método `index()` da lista?

Comment: `c` é para variar de 0 até 10, só usei 3 para testar o código mais rápido.
E `None` é porque não quero que ele não faça nada quando o numero não for primo.

Comment: Não estaria mais de acordo com o que foi pedido se você primeiro lesse todo o vetor e depois percorresse o vetor verificando se cada elemento é primo?

Comment: Entendi, o que você propôs, só não sei como fazer isso.
Se puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função nativa [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que é capaz de receber uma lista ou qualquer outro objeto [iterável](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) como parâmetro e retornar um [gerador](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) de tuplas contendo o índice e seu respectivo valor na lista, veja só:

```
vetor = [10,20,30,40,50]
gen = enumerate(vetor)
print(list(gen))
```

Saída:

```
[(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40), (4, 50)]
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LittleUncomfortableServer)

Segue um exemplo de código capaz de solucionar o seu problema fazendo uso da função `enumerate()`:

```
def eh_primo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def ler_numeros(n):
    v = []
    for i in range(n):
        n = int(input("Digite um número para armazena-lo: "))
        v.append(n)
    return v

for i, n in enumerate(ler_numeros(10)):
    if eh_primo(n):
        print(f'O numero {n} eh primo e estah na posicao {i} do vetor.')
```

Testando:

```
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 101
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 102
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 103
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 104
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 105
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 106
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 107
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 108
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 109
Digite um número para armazena-lo: 110
```

Saída:

```
O numero 101 eh primo e estah na posicao 0 do vetor.
O numero 103 eh primo e estah na posicao 2 do vetor.
O numero 107 eh primo e estah na posicao 6 do vetor.
O numero 109 eh primo e estah na posicao 8 do vetor.
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CharmingFixedTrust)

Answer (score 2):

A lógica para resolver esse problema é mais simples do que pensa:

1. Defina um vetor vazio;
2. Defina um laço de repetição com 10 iterações;

   1. Para cada iteração leia um número;
   2. Adicione o número no vetor;
3. Defina um laço de repetição percorrendo o vetor;

   1. Para cada valor verifique se é um número primo;
   2. Se for primo, exiba o valor junto com o índice;

O índice você consegue obter através do seu laço de repetição; recomendo estudar a função `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão devemos ler e armazenar em um vetor um total de dez valores. Em seguida, verificar quais deles são primos e, posteriormente, exibir o valor e a posição do referido primo.

Para isso podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
def valor_posicao(vet):
    primos = list()
    posicao = list()
    for c in vet:
        if primo(c):
            primos.append(c)
            posicao.append(vet.index(c))
    return primos, posicao


def primo(m):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= m:
        if m % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont != 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


vetor = list(map(int, input('Digite 10 números: ').split()))

pri, posi = valor_posicao(vetor)

for a, b in zip(pri, posi):
    print(f'O número {a} é primo e está na posição {b}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/xgptnkuf-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite 10 número:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Neste momento os valores serão armazenados na lista `vetor` e, em seguida, a tal lista será enviada, como parâmetro, para a função `valor_posicao()`. Chagando lá o **bloco for** percorrerá todos os valores da respectiva lista e, com a ajuda do **bloco if** será verificado se cada elemento de `vetor` é primo. Caso positivo, o valor primo será adicionado na lista `primos` e o índice do valor será adicionado na lista `posicao`. Posteriormente serão exibidas duas listas. Uma contendo os valores primos encontrados no vetor e a outra contendo os índices de cada número primo encontrado no respectivo vetor.