# O que é debug? Para que serve e como fazer?

Tags: terminologia, debug

Pessoas enquanto estou programando sempre vejo nas IDE's uma parte chamada de *debug*, não sei muito bem como funciona e para que serve exatamente já que sei lá pra mim tem cara de ser edição de código mas acredito que não faz sentido ter uma sessão só para isso sendo que dá para editar direto enquanto está programando, então gostaria de saber das pessoas que tem mais experiência o que é esse tal *debug*, para que serve e sei lá como se usa ele de forma correta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse *debug* que está falando é uma ferramenta que dizemos que usa-se para fazer depuração, ou seja, para acompanhar e analisar a execução da aplicação para entender o que está acontecendo e tentar achar o que está ocorrendo em desacordo com o que você esperava.

Ele não é usado para encontrar erros de sintaxe e eventualmente de semântica, mas sim erros de lógica que faz a execução produzir um resultado diferente do esperado (mesmo que esse resulta produza uma erro/exceção).

O ideal é nunca usá-lo, porém isso é teoria, na prática todo programador usará muito, e saber como usar profundamente é uma das capacidades mais importantes que o programador deve ter (existem vários "experientes" que não conseguem ou nem sabem que existe isto, terrível). O iniciante quase deve aprender isto antes de programar de fato, porque ele ajuda entender o código, ajuda compreender o que está acontecendo ali. Então para iniciantes serve como uma ferramenta de aprendizado para "ver" o computador executar o seu código, mesmo certo. É uma forma de criar intimidade com o "jeito do computador" de fazer as coisas. Sem entender isso a pessoa jamais pode se auto denominar programador.

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.
>
> -- Brian Kernighan

*Debugging* é a técnica de fazer isto. Ele funciona mais ou menos como um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101) automatizado, outra técnica que todo programador deve **dominar**.

O *debug* em si quase sempre é um termo errado porque é a ação, o que deve estar perguntando é sobre o *debugger* que não faz parte do IDE, mas é comum as pessoas o usarem com ajuda do IDE porque fica mais visual e mais fácil pegar as informações necessários de estado, ver o fluxo acontecendo e determinar o que fazer, além de fazer algumas configurações como *breakpoints* e *watchpoints*.

Isto se opõe ou pelo menos se completa a uma técnica básica de *debugging* que é colocar alguma função de parada de código e impressão dos valores que deseja de forma simples inserida dentro do código. Embora possa ser uma forma amadora em alguns caos, para quem sabe fazer bem pode ser mais efetivo que usar uma ferramenta de *debug*. Porque *debugging* é só isto, ver o fluxo acontecer e ver o estado das variáveis e como eles vão sendo modificados, tentando achar um padrão que não deveria acontecer para depois consertá-lo e tentar de novo.

A parte difícil não é usar a ferramenta, é entender como fazer a técnica de forma mais efetiva e eficaz. Portando é mais importante aprender programar bem em todos os aspectos. A ferramenta é igual a qualquer outro software, tem uns comandos que precisa saber para conseguir o que quer, não é muito e decora rápido, mas como aplicar isso do jeito que te ajude demanda experiência, comprometimento e estudo, além de pensamento lógico.

Alguns IDEs permitem que você modifique o código na hora e continuar depurando o código que já passará executar na sua nova forma, mas não é função do *debugger* fazer isto.

[A técnica foi mais ou menos descrita no nosso meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/101), mas não necessariamente usando a ferramenta. Já falei que ela é mais importante que a ferramenta?

Cada IDE tem um jeito um pouco diferente de operar, e cada linguagem pode trazer diferenças, ainda que o básico seja tudo igual. Tem o código que você vê sendo executado, pode ir passo a passo, ou pular algumas partes e deixar ele executar naturalmente sem acompanhar diretamente, ir até um certo ponto, ou parar quando um dado tem um valor específico, e dá para ver o valor de todas variáveis disponíveis e outros dados que podem ser úteis.

Algumas pessoas poderão resumir que é uma câmera lenta do código executando, uma Matrix, então algo que executaria em uma fração de segundo executará em segundos, minutos ou horas, sob seu controle, dando a chance do programador ver e entender o que está acorrendo. Ele vai dando fotos da memória e registradores do computador, pelo menos em um nível mais baixo. Em linguagens mais alto nível não deixa de fazer isto, mas ele faz de uma forma mais fácil de entender.

A pergunta é um pouco ampla para descrever aqui tudo o que esta ferramenta faz e cabe novas perguntas mais específicas conforme for aprendendo, até porque a pergunta aqui é só sobre o termo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).