# Criando um programa de covariância com Python

Tags: python-3.x, data, estatística-bootstrap

estou exercitando um pouco com as listas e tentando criar operações estatísticas com elas e estou com dificuldades para calcular a covariância

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente estou tentando criar elementos separados e realizar o cálculo como um produto entre dois somatórios de mesmo índice i.

Basicamente, uma lista para as amostras X, ump para as amostras Y
Uma para calcular o total somado do comprimento de cada lista (O somatório da lista de X com a lista Y dá o total N). 
Iniciei os contadores i em 1 para equivaler a operação (n-1)
E basicamente tentei criar o desvio padrão para X e o desvio padrão para Y, divido-lo pela soma entre o comprimento das listas X e Y e depois exibir a covariância como um resultado numérico

Esse é meu código

```
    #Covariância
 #Índice referente ao número da amostra.
n=int(input("Insira o número total de amostras"))

#Contador para percorrer os índices
i=1    #Amostras X e Amostras Y
Amostrax=[]
Amostray=[]

#Tamanho total da lista de cada variável
 for i in range(n):        
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra X dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostrasx.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras associadas a X")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras X na tela para o usuário
print(Amostrasx)
#Soma das variáveis para gerar as médias de X e Y
Xi = 0
Nx = len(Amostrax)


j=1
for j in range(n):        
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra X dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostrasy.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras associadas a Y")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras X na tela para o usuário
print(Amostrasy)
 Yi = 0
 Ny = len(Amostray)
#Preenchendo as listas de amostras
for amostraix in Amostrax:
    Xi +=amostraix
for amostraiy in Amostray:
    Yi +=amostraiy  
Médiax=Xi/Nx
Médiay=Yi/Ny

print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras", Xi)
print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras", Yi)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras X que você possui", Nx)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras Y que você possui", Ny)
print ("Esta é a média da variável X", Médiax)
print ("Esta é a média da variável Y", Médiay)

DesviosMédiosx=[] 
DesviosMédiosy=[]
for i in range (n):
    DesviosMédiosx.append(Amostrax[i]-Médiax)
XiMenosXmédio=0
for desviosmediosi in DesviosMédiosx:
    XiMenosXmédio+=DesviosMédios[i]

for j in range (n):
    DesviosMédiosy.append(Amostray[j]-Médiay)
YiMenosXmédio=0
for desviosmediosi in DesviosMédiosy:
    YiMenosYmédio+=DesviosMédios[j]

Covariância=(XiMenosXmédio*YiMenosXmédio)/(Nx+Ny)
print ("Este é cada desvio médio individual:", DesviosMédiosx)
print ("Este é cada desvio médio individual:", DesviosMédiosy)
print ("Este é o desvio médio:",Covariância)
```

---

O problema foi solucionado pelo Elton Nunes no post abaixo, só queria editar para anexar uma solução alternativa utilizando uma outra fórmula que é matematicamente equivalente e que consegui desenvolver (Referências - Estimativas e Erros experimentais em Física - Editora UERJ, 3 edição, página 26)

```
#Covariância
 #Índice referente ao espaço amostral associadas as variáveis X e Y.
n=int(input("Insira o número total de amostras"))    
#Contador para percorrer os índices
i=1    #Amostras X e Amostras Y
Amostrax=[]
Amostray=[]  
Amostraxy=[]
#Tamanho total da lista de cada variável
for i in range(n):
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra X dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostrax.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras associadas a X")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras X na tela para o usuário
print("Estas são as amostras da variável X:", Amostrax)
#Soma das variáveis para gerar as médias de X e Y
Xi = 0
Nx = len(Amostrax)   
j=1
for j in range(n):        
    #Adiciona o valor da amostra X dentro da lista de amostras
    Amostray.append(int(input("Insira o valor das amostras associadas a Y")))
#Escreve a lista de amostras X na tela para o usuário
print(Amostray)
Yi = 0
Ny = len(Amostray)
#Preenchendo as listas de amostras
for amostraix in Amostrax:
    Xi +=amostraix
for amostraiy in Amostray:
    Yi +=amostraiy
Médiax=Xi/Nx
Médiay=Yi/Ny
for k in range(n):
    Amostraxy.append(Amostrax[k]*Amostray[k])

Nxy=len(Amostraxy)
XiYi=0
for amostraixy in Amostraxy:
    XiYi +=amostraixy

Médiaxy=XiYi/Nxy
Covariância=Médiaxy-(Médiax * Médiay)

print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras X", Xi)
print ("Esse é o valor da soma das amostras Y", Yi)
print ("Este é o produto das amostras X e Y:", Amostraxy)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras X que você possui", Nx)
print ("Este é a quantidade de amostras Y que você possui", Ny)
print ("Esta é a média da variável X", Médiax)
print ("Esta é a média da variável Y", Médiay)
print ("Esta é a média do produto X com Y:", Médiaxy)
print ("Esta é a covariância:", Covariância)
```

Comment: estou dando uma olhada, como deveria ser a declaração de 'DesviosMédios'?

Comment: A operação referente ao somatório, de (Xi - Xmédio) / Nx é o desvio médio de X e (Yi-médiay) é o desvio médio de Y
por isso separei em 2 listas, DesviosMédiosx e DesviosmédiosY

Comment: sim, mas vc esta usando antes de declarar, esta gerando um erro não é?

Comment: Está, não sabia que esse erro era daí. 
Em que posição eu deveria declarar?

Comment: antes de usar elas, porem elas vão estar vazias e vai dar outro erro, erro de index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiz o exercicio seguindo este exemplo no [wikihow](https://pt.wikihow.com/Calcular-a-Covari%C3%A2ncia)

deixei bem cru para vc ver o meu passo a passo,

e é uma coisa que recomendo a fazer quando se esta treinando, vc vai executando o codigo a cada linha acrescentada e confere se esta indo certo

```
n=9

Amostrax=[1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 12, 2, 4]
Amostray=[8, 6, 9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 7, 7]

media_x = round(sum(Amostrax) / n, 2)
media_y = round(sum(Amostray) / n, 2)

dif_x = [round(x - media_x, 2)
    for x in Amostrax]

dif_y = [round(y - media_y, 3)
    for y in Amostray]

produto = [round(x*y, 2)
    for x,y in zip(dif_x, dif_y)]

produto_soma = sum(produto)

covariance = round(produto_soma /(n-1), 2)

print(media_x,                                                                                                         
    media_y,
    dif_x,
    dif_y,
    produto,
    produto_soma,
    covariance,
    sep='\n')
```

uso bastante a função round no codigo, ela arredonda

```
print(round(1.111111111, 2))
```

vai printar o valor arredondado para 2 casas apos a virgula, no codigo a cima tambem usei 3 para definir as casas decimais, foi erro meu era para ser 2 tambem, mas não atrapalha a executar o codigo, e vc pode ver uma versão com apenas um uso desta função

```
amostrax=[1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 7, 12, 2, 4]
amostray=[8, 6, 9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 7, 7]

def covariance(x, y): 
    n = len(x)
    media_x = sum(x)/n
    media_y = sum(y)/n

    diferença_x = [i - media_x
        for i in x]

    diferença_y = [j - media_y
        for j in y]                                                                                                

    produto = [i*j
        for i,j in zip(diferença_x, diferença_y)]

    produto_soma = sum(produto)

    return round(produto_soma/(n-1), 2)

cov = covariance(amostrax, amostray)
print(cov)
```

Comment: Boa resposa Elton, acredito que vale mencionar sobre como executar um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%c3%a9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%c3%a1-lo) e

Comment: teste de mesa é oq sempre faço quando aprendo uma ferramenta nova, valeu a dica

Comment: Elton, acabei de rodar seu código e observar os resultados dele, mas não entendi algumas etapas da própria sintaxe. 

media_x = round(sum(Amostrax) / n, 2)
media_y = round(sum(Amostray) / n, 2)

dif_x = [round(x - media_x, 2)
    for x in Amostrax]

dif_y = [round(y - media_y, 3)
    for y in Amostray]

produto = [round(x*y, 2)
    for x,y in zip(dif_x, dif_y)]

produto_soma = sum(produto)

covariance = round(produto_soma /(n-1), 2)

O que são esses valores "2" e "3" após as vírgulas?

e para que serve esse comando Round serve para passar em cada elemento da lista?

Comment: adicionei a explicação em um codigo formatado

Comment: Adicionei uma outra solução para o problema, peguei as suas e vou tentar dar mais uma afinada no código pois tem alguns comandos que você usou que ainda não aprendi xD