# Lógica do laço de função

Tags: javascript, lógica, recursão

Estou iniciando estudo de funções em JavaScript e analisando o laço abaixo me veio a dúvida sobre a lógica do resultado.

```
function foo(i) {
   if (i < 0)
      return;
   document.writeln('begin:' + i);
   foo(i - 1);
   document.writeln('end:' + i);
}
foo(2);
```

O resultado:

```
begin:2 
begin:1 
begin:0 
end:0 
end:1 
end:2
```

porém no meu entendimento de iniciante o resultado deveria ser:

```
begin:2 
begin:1 
begin:0 
end:1 
end:0
```

Gostaria de uma explicação didática para não prosseguir com esta dúvida.

Comment: Consegue detalhar por que acha que o `end: 2` não seria exibido e por que a ordem seria decrescente?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, ao meu ver a função está correta e o resultado errado parece certo.
Se inserir `foo(i++ - 1)` vai dar o resultado que espera, porém o `end: 2` ainda vai aparecer... Uma forma de sair dessa seria `if (i < 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você fez [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101)? E no teste deu o resultado que acha que deveria acontecer? Se você acha que é assim, poderia ter justificado como chegou no seu resultado.

Eu não consigo nem imaginar porque daria o que espera. Vamos lá:

1. A função é chamada e `i` vale 2, portanto `i` não é menor que 0 e imprime 2, e em seguida chama ela mesma agora com o valor 1.
2. Nova execução com `i` valendo 1, portanto `i` não é menor que 0 e imprime 1, e em seguida chama ela mesma agora com o valor 0.
3. Agora outra execução com `i` valendo 0, portanto `i` não é menor que 0 e imprime 0, e em seguida chama ela mesma agora com o valor -1.
4. Mais uma execução com `i` valendo -1, portanto `i` **é** menor que 0 e encerra a execução ali mesmo voltando ao controla da chamadora, portanto continuará o que estava fazendo no passo 3.
5. A continuação obviamente será a linha seguida ao da chamada da função da função `foo()` que manda imprimir o valor de `i` no que está descrito no passo 3 e lá está bem claro, `ì` está valendo 0, é o valor impresso. E ela encerra, entregando o controle da sua função chamadora, no caso continuará o que estava fazendo no passo 2.
6. De novo será a linha seguida ao da chamada da função da função `foo()` que manda imprimir o valor de `i` no que está descrito no passo 2 e lá está bem claro, `ì` está valendo 1, é o valor impresso. E ela encerra, entregando o controle da sua função chamadora, no caso continuará o que estava fazendo no passo 1.
7. Finalmente ali continua a linha seguida ao da chamada da função da função `foo()` que manda imprimir o valor de `i` no que está descrito no passo 1 e lá está bem claro, `ì` está valendo 2, é o valor impresso. E ela encerra, entregando o controle da sua função chamadora, no caso é a que fez a chamada inicial.
8. E na sua continuação encerra o programa e nada mais é feito.

Provavelmente se perdeu no fluxo e acha que volta para outro lugar. A chamada de função é um desvio de fluxo que vai para um lugar, quando esse lugar termina ele volta exatamente para o mesmo lugar que estava.

Se tem 2 impressões a quantidade de impressões certamente seria par, a sua lógica manda imprimir 5 vezes, como isso é possível? Note que não tem um enceramento precoce no meio, ou encerra no final ou encerrar logo na entrada, não dá para ficar meio termo.

Pensei até que achou que a variável `i` é global e mudou o valor é o mesmo em todas execução, mas nem teria lógica. Cada `i` é independente.

Vamos pensar nas mesmas chamadas mas sem ser recursivas, ou seja, chamadas foram feitas com os valores 2, 1, 0, -1 (sim teve uma chamada assim, mas que não gera impressão):

```js
function foo(i) {
   console.log('entrei com valor i: ' + i);
   if (i < 0) {
      console.log('entrou no if e i: ' + i);
      return;
   }
   document.writeln('begin:' + i);
   console.log('chamará nova função e i: ' + i + ', então chamará com o valor ' + (i - 1));
   foo (i - 1);
   console.log('voltei pra função que estava e i: ' + i);
   document.writeln('end:' + i);
   console.log('estou encerrando a função e i: ' + i);
}
console.log('vou começar');
foo(2);
console.log('terminei');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/RecursionExplained.js).

Isso faz o que chamamos de [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack?tab=Votes).

Comment: Excelente sua explicação! eu estava me atrapalhando no fluxo. Obrigado.

Comment: @JLMendonca agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.