# Acrescentando elementos a um dicionário somente se a chave não existir

Tags: python

Tenho que criar uma função que acrescenta os dados de um novo aluno em um dicionário.

Entrada:

- *alunos:* dicionario com os dados dos alunos
- *nome:* nome do aluno (chave)
- *notas:* lista com as notas de um aluno (valor)

Retorno:

- A função deve retornar o dicionário com as modificações realizadas*

Observação: Caso a chave já exista no dicionário, deve retornar o dicionário sem nenhuma alteração.

Esse é meu código, que retorna "já cadastrado", sendo que o valor foi inserido pela primeira vez:

```
alunos = dict()

def adicionar_aluno ( alunos , nome , notas ):
    alunos[nome]=[notas]
    if nome in alunos:
        return 'já cadastrado'
    else:
        return alunos

nome = input ( 'nome: ' )
notas = float ( input ( 'nota: ' ) )
a=adicionar_aluno(alunos, nome, notas)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por causa da ordem em que as coisas são feitas (e que poderia ser detectado fazendo um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052)).

Primeiro você adiciona o aluno no dicionário:

```
alunos[nome]=[notas]
```

Depois você verifica se esse aluno está no dicionário:

```
if nome in alunos:
```

Ou seja, esse `if` sempre será verdadeiro, porque o aluno que você está verificando já foi adicionado na linha anterior.

O que você deve fazer é cadastrar o aluno **somente se ele não existir no dicionário** (ou seja, dentro do `else`):

```
def adicionar_aluno ( alunos , nome , notas ):
    if nome in alunos:
        return 'já cadastrado'
    else:
        alunos[nome] = [notas]
        return alunos
```

---

Se bem que os requisitos dizem que deve sempre retornar o dicionário, então basta modificar a condição para só acrescentar o aluno se ele não existir:

```
def adicionar_aluno ( alunos , nome , notas ):
    if nome not in alunos:
        alunos[nome] = [notas]
    return alunos
```

Ou seja, se o aluno não existe no dicionário, adiciona (repare no `not in`, que verifica se o aluno não está no dicionário). Se ele já existir, não precisa fazer nada (por isso nem precisa do `else`).

No final, retorne o dicionário. Se ele entrou no `if`, ele terá o novo aluno. Se ele não entrou no `if`, será retornado sem modificações.

---

Só achei estranho a sua função retornar uma mensagem ou o próprio dicionário. Talvez seja melhor ela retornar `True` ou `False`, indicando se o aluno foi ou não cadastrado. **Não precisa retornar o próprio dicionário porque o mesmo é modificado dentro da função**:

```
alunos = dict()

def adicionar_aluno ( alunos , nome , notas ):
    if nome in alunos:
        return False
    else:
        alunos[nome] = [notas]
        return True

nome = input('nome: ')
nota = float(input('nota: ' ))
if adicionar_aluno(alunos, nome, nota):
    print(f'aluno {nome} adicionado')
else:
    print(f'aluno {nome} já cadastrado')
```

Comment: cara muito obrigado, deu uma luz aqui no meu problema, to começando na linguagem e ai algumas coisas são meio confusas, obg!

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar a atribuição das notas dentro do bloco `if` e utilizar um `not` antes para verificar se o aluno não está registrado.

Também não é necessário um `else` já que de qualquer maneira, o dicionário será retornado. Veja o código abaixo:

```
def adicionar_aluno ( alunos, nome, notas ):

    if not nome in alunos:
        alunos[nome] = [notas]
    return alunos
```

Como a função `adicionar_aluno` altera o objeto de dicionário diretamente sem criar um novo dicionário, acho que não seria necessário retornar o dicionário e sim um valor `bool` como True ou False para informar se o dicionário foi modificado.

```
def adicionar_aluno ( alunos, nome, notas ):

    if not nome in alunos:
        alunos[nome] = [notas]
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: obg pela atenção!