# Problemas para ordem de jogada dos jogadores em Jogo da Velha

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Tenho problemas com a função `players()`, pois não consigo incrementar a variável `n`, a função só está retornando `"X"`. Eu sei que parece algo bem simples, mas não consigo identificar o problema. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
def players():
    n = 0
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n + 1
        return 'X'
    else:
        n = n + 1
        return 'O'

def play():
    gon = 0
    while gon != 9:
        pos = input('Insira a posição que deseja jogar: ')
        if pos == '1':
            paper[0][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '2':
            paper[1][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '3':
            paper[2][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '4':
            paper[3][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '5':
            paper[4][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '6':
            paper[5][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '7':
            paper[6][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '8':
            paper[7][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        elif pos == '9':
            paper[8][0] = players()
            gon += 1
        else:
            print('Dígito inválido! Tente novamente.')

        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % (paper[0][0],paper[1][0],paper[2][0]))
        print('-----------')
        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % (paper[3][0],paper[4][0],paper[5][0]))
        print('-----------')
        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % (paper[6][0],paper[7][0],paper[8][0]))
    if gon == 9:
        print('\n Empate!')

paper = [[' '],[' '],[' '],
         [' '],[' '],[' '],
         [' '],[' '],[' ']]

print('Bem-vindo ao Jogo da Velha!')
print('Cliente é X;')
print('Servidor é O.')
play()
```

Comment: Sua função `players()` esta setando toda vez o `n` em zero, sempre que é chamada, esse `n = 0` não pode estar la dentro

Answer (score 4):

O problema pode ser verificado fazendo um simples [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) na função `players`. Basicamente, ela começa com `n = 0`, ou seja, toda vez que você chamar `players()`, a primeira coisa que ela fará é setar o valor zero na variável `n`. **Sempre**, toda vez que for chamada.

Por isso sempre vai entrar no `if`. Se você quer que o comportamento varie conforme o valor de `n`, então *provavelmente* o que você quer é que a função receba o valor como parâmetro:

```
def players(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 'X'
    else:
        return 'O'
```

Ainda dá para simplificar e melhorar algumas coisas no código. Por exemplo, a função `play`:

```
def play():
    paper = [ ' ' ] * 9
    gon = 0
    n = 0
    while gon != 9:
        try:
            pos = int(input('Insira a posição que deseja jogar: '))
            if 1 <= pos <= 9:
                paper[pos - 1] = players(n)

                n = 1 - n # se n for 1, vira zero, se for zero, vira 1
                gon += 1

                for i in range(0, len(paper), 3):
                    print(' {} | {} | {} '.format(paper[i],paper[i + 1],paper[i + 2]))
                    if i < 6:
                        print('-----------')
            else:
                print('Valor deve estar entre 1 e 9')
        except ValueError:
            print('Valor inválido! Tente novamente.')

    if gon == 9:
        print('\n Empate!')
```

Eu converto o resultado de `input` para número usando [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) (e caso não seja um número, ele lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), que eu capturo com `except`). E eu só atualizo o tabuleiro se o valor da posição for válido.

Se o tabuleiro é sempre o mesmo, você pode criá-lo dentro da função mesmo (não vi sentido em criá-lo fora, a menos que ele pudesse ter tamanho variado, aí ele poderia ser um parâmetro da função, por exemplo).

Também fiz um "tabuleiro" como sendo uma lista com 9 posições. Claro que ser uma lista de listas (uma "matriz") seria mais "fiel", mas deixando-a como uma lista simples simplifica aquele monte de `if`'s.

Na hora de imprimir o tabuleiro, usei um `range` de 3 em 3, assim dá para imprimir cada "linha" da "matriz" de uma vez.

---

Claro que dá para melhorar mais, pois o código não verifica se uma posição já foi ocupada, não faz uma verificação de fato se houve um vencedor, etc. Um exemplo:

```
def players(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 'X'
    else:
        return 'O'

def jogo_terminou(tabuleiro):
    posicoes_vencedoras = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], # horizontal
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], # vertical
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6] # diagonal
    ]
    # verifica todas as combinações de posições vencedoras
    for pos1, pos2, pos3 in posicoes_vencedoras:
        if tabuleiro[pos1] == tabuleiro[pos2] == tabuleiro[pos3] and tabuleiro[pos1] in ('X', 'O'):
            print(f'Temos um vencedor: {tabuleiro[pos1]}! Parabéns!') # mudei a mensagem para mostrar quem ganhou
            # se já encontrei um vencedor, posso retornar direto (não precisa continuar verificando as outras combinações)
            return True

    # não tem vencedor, verifica se todas as posições estão ocupadas (não preciso mais do contador de jogadas)
    if all(posicao in ('X', 'O') for posicao in tabuleiro):
        print('Deu velha! Ninguém ganhou.')
        return True

    # jogo ainda não terminou
    return False

def play():
    paper = [ ' ' ] * 9
    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            pos = int(input('Insira a posição que deseja jogar: '))
            if 1 <= pos <= 9:
                if paper[pos - 1] == ' ': # verifica se posição não está ocupada
                    paper[pos - 1] = players(n)

                    n = 1 - n # se n for 1, vira zero, se for zero, vira 1

                    for i in range(0, len(paper), 3):
                        print(' {} | {} | {} '.format(paper[i],paper[i + 1],paper[i + 2]))
                        if i < 6:
                            print('-----------')
                else:
                    print('posição já ocupada')
            else:
                print('Valor deve estar entre 1 e 9')
        except ValueError:
            print('Valor inválido! Tente novamente.')

        if jogo_terminou(paper):
            break
```

Comment: Obrigado, hkotsubo! (y). Sobre a confirmação de que há um vencedor ou não, eu fiz 6 condições booleanas de acordo com as linhas, colunas e diagonais da matriz que fiz. Obrigado novamente!

Comment: @jmb2001 Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: A condição de que o valor deve estar entre 1 e 9 (posição ocupada) não funciona. Eu pensei em colocar um if de que a posição do paper for False já que não contém nada por enquanto. Mas mesmo assim, tou em dúvida.

Comment: @jmb2001 O que exatamente não funciona? Pois "não funciona" é muito vago, da forma que eu fiz funciona sim, pois testei bastante antes de postar o código. O que eu **acho** que pode ser o problema (ou pelo menos um deles) é que nesta resposta eu mudei o tabuleiro para ser uma lista com 9 posições (`paper = [ ' ' ] * 9`), mas na sua [outra pergunta](/q/449765/112052), na função `winner` você ainda considera como uma lista de listas, e aí claro que não vai funcionar porque ele será uma lista com 3 posições (e cada posição tem outra lista com 3 posições). De qq forma já comentei lá com um link...

Comment: ... [este link](/a/446286/112052), que tem a função `jogo_terminou`, que verifica se tem um vencedor (considerando que o tabuleiro é uma lista de 9 posições, que é o que estou usando neste código).

Comment: Nessa condição de posição ocupada, eu insiro o valor na posição 1. Quando é a vez do outro jogador, ele insere o valor na posição 1. Aí acontece a troca, quando era pra dizer que a posição já tá ocupada.

Comment: @jmb2001 No último parágrafo da resposta: "*Claro que dá para melhorar mais, pois o código **não verifica se uma posição já foi ocupada**.*" - basta fazer um `if` antes de inserir o valor na posição (se já estiver ocupado, pede para o usuário digitar novamente, etc)

Comment: @jmb2001 De qualquer forma, adicionei um código no final da resposta com essa verificação

Comment: Certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Onde digo que o problema foi resolvido aqui no stackoverflow?

Comment: @jmb2001 É só [**aceitar a resposta**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), basta clicar no **✓** (se não achar onde é, veja [no link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052)).

Comment: @jmb2001 Além de aceitar a resposta, [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) nela,  caso tenha achado útil. Aliás, como vc já tem mais de 15 pontos, pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta do site

Answer (score 1):

Caro jmb2001, sem querer modificar muito o seu programa mas procurando simplifica-lo eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
import os

def players(flag):

    if flag:
        return 'X'
    else:
        return 'O'

def play():
    flag = True
    gon = 0
    while gon != 9:
        os.system('clear')

        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % tuple(paper[0:3]))
        print('-----------')
        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % tuple(paper[3:6]))
        print('-----------')
        print(' %s | %s | %s ' % tuple(paper[6:9]))
        print()

        pos = input('Insira a posição que deseja jogar: ')
        if pos in 'qQ':
            exit(0)

        elif pos in '123456789':
                paper[int(pos)-1] = players(flag)
                gon += 1
                flag = not flag

        else:
            print('Dígito inválido! Tente novamente.')

    if gon == 9:
        print('\n Empate!')


paper = [' '] * 9 # copie do hkotsubo

print('Bem-vindo ao Jogo da Velha!')
print('Cliente é X;')
print('Servidor é O.')

play()
```

Eu achei melhor mudar o nome da sua variável de controle n para flag, que significa bandeira em inglês pois é isso o que a variável flag faz.

Ela trabalha como um flip-flop mudando o seu estado cada vez que a linha ( flag = not flag ) é executada.

Acrescentei a instrução os.system('clear') para que a tela seja limpa e os print's saiam sempre nas mesmas posições do terminal.

Também inclui uma opção permitindo que o usuário encerre o programa digitando q ou Q.

Por fim concordo com o hkotsubo sobre o fato de que ainda falta verificar se a posição já esta ocupada ou não e outras coisas mais.

Mas você esta no caminho certo, continue assim...

E seja Feliz

Comment: Só um detalhe, se digitar a posição `12`, ou `23` ou `3456` etc, vai dar erro: https://ideone.com/NTmyJd

Comment: Você tem razão. Então para resolver este problema basta colocar as instruções try except praticamente nas mesmas posições que o hkotsubo colocou

Comment: Obrigado, Washington Luis!