# Garantir que a entrada não se repita, seja numérica e dentro de um range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

Estou programando um joguinho da velha. Quando o usuário escolhe a casa onde fará a marcação de seu símbolo (X ou O), preciso garantir que:

1. O valor de entrada seja referente a uma casa vazia (que não tenha sido selecionada anteriormente para marcação);
2. O valor de entrada seja um número inteiro;
3. O valor de entrada seja referente a uma casa existente `range(0,9)`;

Enquanto o valor de entrada não cumprir esses três requisitos ao mesmo tempo, quero continuar repetindo o pedido de valor com o comando `input`.

**O que eu tentei:**

```
casa = ''

while tabuleiro[casa] != VAZIO:
    casa = input("Escolha onde quer jogar: ")
   
   while type(casa) != int:
        casa = input("Escolha onde quer jogar: ")
       
       if casa.isdigit():
            casa = int(casa)
        
        while casa not in range(0, 9):
            casa = input("Escolha onde quer jogar: ")
           
            if casa.isdigit():
                casa = int(casa)
```

Comment: Tem algumas opções [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446286/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439913/112052)

Answer (score 2):

É sempre melhor dividir uma tarefa grande ou com diversas etapas em tarefas menores. Olhe essa estrutura de código que utiliza funções para fazer as tarefas que você estabeleceu:

```
def casa_eh_numero_valido(casa): 
    return casa.isdigit() and 0 <= int(casa) <= 8

def casa_esta_vazia(casa, tabuleiro): 
    return tabuleiro[int(casa)] == 'VAZIA'

def casa_eh_valida(casa, tabuleiro): 
    return casa_eh_numero_valido(casa) and casa_esta_vazia(casa, tabuleiro)
```

Aqui temos uma função `casa_eh_valida` que é responsável por checar se uma dada `casa` (presumivelmente o input do usuário) é válida para um dado `tabuleiro` (aqui assumo que `tabuleiro` é uma lista de tamanho 9, já que não ficou explícito no seu código). Ambos são parâmetros da função, e essa função realiza esse trabalho chamando outras funções.

A função `casa_eh_numero_valido` checa se a casa é um dígito entre 0 e 8. Já a função `casa_esta_vazia` checa se a casa está vazia no tabuleiro. Note a conversão para número, já que índices são do tipo `int`, não `str`. Essa conversão é segura justamente por causa da função `casa_eh_numero_valido` que chamamos imediatamente antes. Se o retorno da primeira funão for `False`, o Python nem perde tempo chamando a segunda função, já que `False and ...` sempre retorna `False`.

Lembre-se: **divida tarefas grandes em tarefas pequenas** para facilitar a sua vida.

No seu código principal, dá pra fazer algo do tipo:

```
tabuleiro = ["VAZIA"] * 9

while True:
    casa = input("Escolha onde quer jogar: ")
    if casa_eh_valida(casa, tabuleiro):
        print("A casa é válida.")
        # mais código continua aqui...
        # modificar tabuleiro, etc
    else:
        print("A casa é inválida.")
    if jogo_acabou(tabuleiro):
        break
```

Já deixei aqui uma outra ideia para dar continuidade ao seu jogo: uma função `jogo_acabou` que pega o tabuleiro e checa se o jogo chegou ao fim - seja porque alguém ganhou (quem?), ou porque não há mais casas vazias. Deixo essa ideia pra você complementar :-)

Answer (score 2):

Se quer verificar se uma string contém um número e depois validar se esse número está entre determinados valores, não precisa usar [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) e depois converter para [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Claro que se o usuário sempre digitar valores corretos, não haverá problemas, o problema é que há vários caracteres para os quais `isdigit` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `int`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/XX3U7V).

Tudo bem que é um *corner case* e "provavelmente o usuário nunca digitará esses caracteres". Mas o melhor - e mais garantido - seria fazer logo a conversão com `int(entrada)` e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) para saber se não foi digitado um número (mais ou menos [assim](https://ideone.com/pMJ7Ph)).

Enfim, no seu caso, basta fazer um *loop* infinito e só interrompê-lo se todas as condições estiverem satisfeitas:

```
tabuleiro = [ '' ] * 9

while True:
    try:
        casa = int(input('Escolha onde quer jogar: '))
        if 0 <= casa <= 8: # valor válido
            if tabuleiro[casa] == '':
                break # valor válido, encerra o loop
            else:
                print(f'Casa {casa} está ocupada')
        else:
            print('Valor deve estar entre 0 e 8')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')

# usar tabuleiro[casa]...
```

Ou seja, eu leio o dado e tento transformar em número com `int`. Se não foi digitado um número, ele lança o `ValueError` e cai no bloco `except`.

Se for número, eu verifico se está na faixa de valores correta e se a casa está ocupada (e em cada caso eu imprimo a respectiva mensagem). Se estiver tudo OK, eu encerro o *loop* com `break`.

Como não foi colocado o restante do programa, não ficou claro se o *loop* deve ser interrompido ou se algo deve ser feito com a `casa` ali mesmo. Se for esse o caso, basta fazer o que precisa com a posição `casa` dentro do `if tabuleiro[casa] == ''` (em vez do `break`, faça o que precisa ali dentro do `if`).

---

Claro que você até poderia separar cada verificação em uma função específica, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/457577/112052). Mas acho que nesse caso nem compensa, as verificações são simples demais - sem contar que cada função sugerida lá está chamando `int` novamente (ou seja, ele converte para `int` duas vezes, **desnecessariamente** - fora o problema do `isdigit` já mencionado, que nem sempre garante que a conversão para `int` funcionará).