# Dúvida print lista jogo da velha Python

Tags: python, jogos

Estou desenvolvendo o jogo da velha, que ainda está no início. Eu estou com problemas ao tentar printar a primeira linha da lista. Quando eu printo a lista, ela sempre está vazia.

Podem ser dois erros:

- ou não estou adicionando corretamente o símbolo na lista;
- ou o `print` está errado.

Como vocês podem ver na imagem que eu postei, a linha 1 não printa nada, mas a linha 2 sim.

obs: a função `player2` eu ainda não atualizei, por isso está diferente.

```
import numpy as np

positions = [0,1,2]
velha = [ ["","",""] , ["","",""] , ["","",""] ]

def player1():
    global velha

    print(velha[0])
    print(velha[1])
    print(velha[2])

    linha = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
    coluna = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
    if linha and coluna in positions:
     if velha[linha][coluna] == "":
        try:
            velha[linha][coluna] = 'X'
        except:
            print("essa posição está ocupada")

    else:
        print("Por favor digite uma posição válida")
        player1()

def player2():
    global velha
    print(velha[0])
    print(velha[1])
    print(velha[2])
    try:
        linha = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
        coluna = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
        if linha and coluna in positions:
            try:
                if velha[linha][coluna] == " ":
                    velha[linha][coluna] = 'O'
            except:
                print("essa posição está ocupada")

    except:
        print("Por favor digite uma posição válida")
        player2()

while True:
    player1()
    player2()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não parei para olhar todo o código, mas em todo caso, se quiser tem implementações de jogo da velha [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446286/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439913/112052)

Comment: vlw cara, obrigado. dei uma olhada aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está aqui `if linha and coluna in positions:` o Python não vai varrer a coluna positions 2x porque usou o operador `and` sei que na cabeça faz maior sentido pensar como se fosse um "E". Mas o Python vai verificar se linha e coluna são `True` e vai continuar. Tanto que se você colocar um valor maior que o que está no position ele vai continuar e dar um IndexError:

Nesse caso você tem que fazer 2 verificações

```
if linha in positions and coluna in positions:
```

Comment: Vlw Rodrigo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro passo para compreender o seu algoritmo é o colocar para funcionar.
Para isso corrigi algumas atribuições indevidas e depois reescrevi comparação:

```
if linha and coluna in positions:
```

para:

```
if all(p in positions for p in {linha, coluna}):
```

onde a função built in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que retorna `True` apenas se todos elemento de um iterável são `True`, testa todos o elemento da [expressão geradora](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) se para elemento do [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) `{linha, coluna}` está contido em `positions`.

Então pude rodar esse código:

```
positions = range(3)  #Range ao invés de lista
velha = [["","",""] for p in positions] # List comprehension ao invés do literal

def player1():
    global velha

    print(velha[0])
    print(velha[1])
    print(velha[2])

    linha = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
    coluna = int(input("Escolha uma coluna: "))
    
    # Se todo elemento p contido no set {linha, coluna} estiver em positions... 
    if all(p in positions for p in {linha, coluna}):
     if velha[linha][coluna] == "":
        try:
            velha[linha][coluna] = 'X'
        except:
            print("essa posição está ocupada")

    else:
        print("Por favor digite uma posição válida")
        player1()

def player2():
    global velha
    print(velha[0])
    print(velha[1])
    print(velha[2])
    try:
        linha = int(input("Escolha uma linha: "))
        coluna = int(input("Escolha uma coluna: "))
        # Se todo elemento p contido no set {linha, coluna} estiver em positions...
        if all(p in positions for p in {linha, coluna}):
            try:
                if velha[linha][coluna] == "": #Troca de " " para ""
                    velha[linha][coluna] = 'O'
            except:
                print("essa posição está ocupada")

    except:
        print("Por favor digite uma posição válida")
        player2()

while True:
    print('Jogador X...')  #Mostra de quem é a vez.
    player1()
    print('Jogador O...')  #Mostra de quem é a vez.
    player2()
```

Depois de compreender o algoritmo fiz algumas alterações, removendo a redundância, removendo os tratamentos de exceções desnescessários, quebrando o código em ações mais especializadas e criando uma função `jogada()` que faz a jogadas de ambos os jogadores, a função `vencedor()` que testa o tabuleiro a procura de um vencedor e um [closure](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) `flag()` que é uma função biestado previsível, a cada leitura ela alterna o valor entre `0` e `1` e valor inicial é `0`, usado para itera sobre caracteres da string `"XO"` visando alternar os jogadores a cada `jogada()`:

```
positions = range(3)  #Define a dimensões do tabuleiro.

#Essa função apenas exibe o tabuleiro.
def exibir_tabuleiro(tabuleiro):
    for p in positions: print(tabuleiro[p])
    
#Essa função apenas valida se a entrada s é um dos valores no iteravel p.
def validar_entrada(s, p):
    return s.isdigit() and (int(s) in p)

#Pede para o usuário entrar com um valor de acordo com o rotulo.
def selecionar(rotulo):
    while True:
      e = input(f"Escolha uma {rotulo}: ")
      if not validar_entrada(e, positions):
          print(f"Erro: {rotulo} inválida!{tuple(positions)}")
          continue
      return int(e)
    
#Retorna a célula (linha, coluna) selecionada pelo usuário.
def selecionar_celula():
    return tuple(selecionar(r) for r in ["linha", "coluna"]) 
    
#Informa qual o jogador da vez.
def informar_jogador(s):
    print(f"Jogador {s}...")
    
#Verifica se uma jogada é ou não válida.
def validar_jogada(l, c, t):
    return all(p in positions for p in {l, c}) and (t[l][c] == "")
   
#Efetua uma jogada para o jogador no tabuleiro. O comportamento do interpretador é iniciar o default apenas na primeira chamada da função.
def jogada(jogador, tabuleiro=[[""]*len(positions) for p in positions]):
    valida = False
    exibir_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)
    while not valida:
        informar_jogador(jogador)
        linha, coluna = selecionar_celula()
        valida = validar_jogada(linha, coluna, tabuleiro)
        if valida:
            tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = jogador
        else:
            print(f"{'-'*3} A posição {(linha, coluna)} já está ocupada, jogue novamente {'-'*3}")
            
    return tabuleiro
    
#Testa um vetor para saber se tem todos os caracteres iguais e se sim retorna o caractere senão retorna None 
def vetor_vencedor(v):
    if v.count(v[0]) == len(v):
        if v[0] != "" : 
            #print(f"Vencedor jogador {v[0]}.")
            return v[0]
    
#Testa cada uma das linhas do tabuleiro para saber se tem todos os caracteres iguais e se sim retorna o caractere senão retorna None    
def verificar_linhas(tabuleiro):
    for linha in tabuleiro:
        if vetor_vencedor(linha):
            return linha[0]

#Testa cada uma das colunas do tabuleiro para saber se tem todos os caracteres iguais e se sim retorna o caractere senão retorna None 
def verificar_colunas(tabuleiro):
    for c in positions:
        coluna = [linha[c] for linha in tabuleiro]
        if vetor_vencedor(coluna):
            return coluna[0]
    
#Testa a diagonal principal do tabuleiro para saber se tem todos os caracteres iguais e se sim retorna o caractere senão retorna None    
def verificar_diagonal_principal(tabuleiro):
    diagonal = [tabuleiro[p][p] for p in positions]
    if vetor_vencedor(diagonal):
        return diagonal[0]

#Testa a diagonal secundária do tabuleiro para saber se tem todos os caracteres iguais e se sim retorna o caractere senão retorna None
def verificar_diagonal_secundaria(tabuleiro):
    diagonal = [tabuleiro[positions[-1] - p][p] for p in positions]
    if vetor_vencedor(diagonal):
        return diagonal[0]
        
#Testa o a procura de um vencedor, se houver um vencedor o retorna senão retorna None.
def vencedor(tabuleiro):
    v = (verificar_linhas(tabuleiro) or 
         verificar_colunas(tabuleiro) or
         verificar_diagonal_principal(tabuleiro) or
         verificar_diagonal_secundaria(tabuleiro))
    if v: 
        print(f"{'-'*10} Jogo encerrado {'-'*10}")
        print(f"Vencedor jogador {v}.")
        exibir_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)
        return v
  
#Closure biestado, a cada execução da função seu retorno alterna entre 0 e 1.
def flag():
    f = True
    def __flag():
        nonlocal f
        f = not f
        return int(f)
    return __flag
    
flag = flag() #Obtém o closure

while not vencedor(jogada("XO"[flag()])):
    print(f"{'-'*10} Jogada encerrada {'-'*10}")
```

Comment: Oi Augusto, muito obrigado! Me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Augusto, seu código é meio avançado para mim. Está difícil de ler e entender. hahaha, mas lendo código mais avançado é que a gente progride.

Comment: @PedroIvo, está com dificuldade em que?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem essa ideia de "rótulo".
não entendi na função validar_jogada, o que o and( t[l][c] == "" ) faz. 
Por hora é isso, depois vou ler com mais calma e envio outras dúvidas.

Comment: A coleta de dado é a mesma tanto para linha quanto para coluna, só muda o rótulo e o algoritmo original pede ao jogador que entre primeiro com a linha e depois com a coluna.