# Por que não o método jogado_escolhe e o computador_escolhe não conseguem acessar as posições [0][0],[1][0] e [2][0]?

Tags: python

```
import random

class Mapa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapa = [["_ ","_ ","_ "],["_ ","_ ","_ "],["_ ","_ ","_ "]]
        self.livres = 9

    def imprime_mapa(self):
        for i in range(len(self.mapa)):
            for j in range(len(self.mapa[0])):
                print(self.mapa[i][j],end=" ")
            print()

    def jogador_escolhe(self,L):
        print("Sua vez... ")
        l = int(input("Escolha a linha: ")) - 1
        c = int(input("Escolha a coluna: ")) - 1
        print("l =",l,"e c = ",c)
        while l < 0 or l > 2 or c < 1 or c > 2 or self.mapa[l][c] != "_ ":
            print("Escolha uma posição válida... ")
            l = int(input("Escolha a linha: ")) - 1
            c = int(input("Escolha a coluna: ")) - 1
            print("l =",l,"e c = ",c)
        self.mapa[l][c] = "x "
        L = L -1
        if L == 0 or self.checar_se_ganhou():
            self.imprime_mapa()
            self.fim_de_jogo()
        else:
            self.imprime_mapa()
            self.computador_escolhe(L)
        

    def computador_escolhe(self,L):
        print("É a vez do computador...")
        l = random.randrange(3)
        c = random.randrange(3)
        print("l =",l,"e c = ",c)
        while l < 0 or l > 2 or c < 1 or c > 2 or self.mapa[l][c] != "_ ":
            l = random.randrange(3)
            c = random.randrange(3)
            print("l =",l,"e c = ",c)
        self.mapa[l][c] = "0 "
        L = L - 1
        if L == 0 or self.checar_se_ganhou():
            self.imprime_mapa()
            self.fim_de_jogo()
        else:
            self.imprime_mapa()
            self.jogador_escolhe(L)

    def fim_de_jogo(self):
        print("Fim de jogo.")

    def checar_se_ganhou(self):
        #status = False
        if [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[0][1], self.mapa[0][2]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[0][1], self.mapa[0][2]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[1][0] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[1][2]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[1][0] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[1][2]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[2][0] , self.mapa[2][1], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[2][0] , self.mapa[2][1], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[1][0], self.mapa[2][0]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[1][0], self.mapa[2][0]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][1] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][1]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][1] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][1]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][2] , self.mapa[1][2], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][2] , self.mapa[1][2], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][0] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][2]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][2] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][0]] == ["x ","x ","x "]:
            print("Você ganhou!")
            return True
        elif [self.mapa[0][2] , self.mapa[1][1], self.mapa[2][0]] == ["0 ","0 ","0 "]:
            print("O Computador ganhou!")
            return True
        else:
            return False


jogo = Mapa()
print("Bem vindo ao Jogo da velha!")
print("Vamos sortear quem começa....")
jogo.imprime_mapa()
if random.randrange(0,2) == 0:
    print("Você  começa!")
    jogo.jogador_escolhe(9)
else:
    print("Computador começa!")
    jogo.computador_escolhe(9)
```

Comment: detalhe melhor o problema. ocorre um erro ou simplesmente não faz algo que você esperava? se é um erro, qual a mensagem de erro? e em que trecho do código? Acho que você colocou informações demais no título da pergunta mas faltou explicação no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Outro dia estava com insônia e fiz em python um [jogo da velha(completo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486511/137387). Talvez o ajude. [Teste no COLAB](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Api3DXJ7Nmqc0akqgdJdi1TccS-L79rd?usp=sharing)

Comment: ao tentar selecionar as posições citadas no título ele simplesmente não aceita e solicita nova escolha. Não há mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na validação da coluna 0. Toda vez que selecionar ela, seu código continuará pedindo para o usuário informar a posição novamente.

Note que na linha 19, você tem a comparação `c < 1` que deveria ser `c < 0`.

```py
while l < 0 or l > 2 or c < 1 or c > 2 or self.mapa[l][c] != "_ ":
```

Sugiro usar o mesmo código para as linhas 19 e 39:

```py
while (l < 0 or l > 2) or (c < 0 or c > 2) or self.mapa[l][c] != "_ ":
```

ou também pode fazer de um jeito um pouco mais *pythônico*, usando o operador de between:

```py
while not ((0 <= l <= 2) and (0 <= c <= 2) and self.mapa[l][c] == "_ "):
```