# Como fazer um programa de tabuadas com restrição de estruturas de comando?

Tags: java

Esse programa é para axiliar uma pessoa a ver as tabuadas, a intenção é oferecer 2 opções:

Caso 1: É devolvido a tabuada de 1 a 10;
Caso 2: No a tabuada de um número específico.

Entretanto o programa não realiza as operações.

Detalhe adicional: somente é permitido usar as seguintes estruturas: `java.util.Scanner`, `while`, `if`/`else` e `switch case`.

```
package Estruturas_de_Repetição_I;
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Tavanna {//Programa de auxilio ao estudo da tabuada

    private static Scanner ler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declaração das variáveis
    int valor = 0, option; 

    //Configurar leitor de dados
    ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Mensagem ao usuário + Data input
    System.out.printf("Digie 1 para ver todas as tabuadas. \n"
            + "Digite 2 para ver a tabuda de um número.", option);

    //Ler opção
    option = ler.nextInt();

        if (option == 1){//Caso seja 1
            while(valor <= 10);{ //condição para sair do laço
            for (int i=0; i<=10;i++) {
                System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor*i));//Teoricamente era passar o valor de todas as tabuadas de 0 a 10
                valor = valor++;
                break;
            }
            }
        } else if (option == 2) {//Caso seja 2
        for (int i=0; i<=10; i++);{ //laço para repetição
        System.out.printf("Qual tabuada você prescisa saber", valor);
        valor = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor * i));//Teoricamente seria para passar a tabuada de valor escolhido       
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Havia erros de digitação no código, por isso não funcionava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns erros nesse código.

O primeiro é o ponto-e-vírgula logo depois do `while` e `for`:

```
while(valor <= 10);{
                  ^ aqui
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++);{
                         ^ aqui
```

Quando você coloca esse `;` logo depois do `while` ou `for`, ele é interpretado como um bloco vazio (ou seja, dentro do `for` e do `while` não tem nada a ser executado).

E aí o `{` logo em seguida abre um bloco de código, mas que não faz parte do laço. Então a primeira coisa é remover esse `;`.

Outro problema é essa linha:

```
valor = valor++;
```

Isso não incrementa o `valor`, muito pelo contrário, ele continua valendo sempre a mesma coisa ([veja aqui a explicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564625)):

```
int valor = 0;
valor = valor++;
System.out.println(valor);
valor = valor++;
System.out.println(valor);
```

O código acima imprime `0` duas vezes, [veja](https://ideone.com/lxBS6I). Se quer incrementar o valor, faça simplesmente `valor++` (ou `valor += 1`, tanto faz).

O `break` dentro do primeiro `for` não faz sentido, pois `break` interrompe o laço, mas você não quer interrompê-lo. Enfim, tem outros erros de lógica que poderiam ser detectados fazendo um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052).

Não ficou claro se pode usar métodos, então uma versão sem usá-los ficaria assim (a pergunta não menciona que pode usar `for` - somente `while` - mas como você usou, então também vou usar):

```
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite 1 para ver todas as tabuadas.\nDigite 2 para ver a tabuada de um número.");
int option = ler.nextInt();
if (option == 1) {
    int valor = 1;
    while (valor <= 10) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor * i));
        }
        valor++;
    }
} else if (option == 2) {
    System.out.printf("Qual tabuada você quer saber?");
    int valor = ler.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor * i));
    }
}
```

---

Se puder usar métodos, crie um para imprimir a tabuada de um número específico, assim você pode reaproveitá-lo:

```
public class Tabuada {
    static void tabuada(int valor) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor * i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite 1 para ver todas as tabuadas.\nDigite 2 para ver a tabuada de um número.");
        int option = ler.nextInt();
        if (option == 1) {
            int valor = 1;
            while (valor <= 10) {
                tabuada(valor);
                valor++;
            }
        } else if (option == 2) {
            System.out.printf("Qual tabuada você quer saber?");
            tabuada(ler.nextInt()); // nem precisa da variável, pode passar o valor direto para o método
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amabas soluções deram certas aqui, acredito que o principal erro, seja a minha má digitação do código, extendo um pouco mais. Existe algo que eu posso acrescentar para que as tabuadas do opção 1 apareçam lado a lado.

Comment: @PatrikRufino Aí vc tem que mudar um pouco a lógica dos loops, e primeiro imprimir todos os números multiplicados por zero, depois todos multiplicados por 1, etc. Algo assim: https://ideone.com/mNjTkt

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Reformulei o programa, da uma olhada em como ficou, está funcionando do jeito que eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Após as dicas o programa ficou da seguinte forma, a única coisa, que não consegui foi tabular em sequência, mas pula de linha a cada nova tabuada na option 1.

```
 package Estruturas_de_Repetição_I;
 import     java.util.Scanner;
 public class Tavanna {//Programa de auxilio estudo da tabuada

private static Scanner ler;

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declaração das variáveis
int option = 0; 

//Configurar leitor de dados
ler = new Scanner(System.in);

//Mensagem ao usuário + Data input
System.out.printf("Bem vindo ao Tavanna!\n"
        +"\nAqui você pode ver as tabuadas, escolha sua opção:\n"
        + "\nDigie 1 para ver todas as tabuadas de 1 a 10. \n"
        + "Digite 2 para ver a tabuda de um número específico. \n"
        + "\nDigite sua opção aqui =>"
        + "", option);

//Ler opção
    option = ler.nextInt();

    if (option == 1){ //Caso seja 1
        int valor = 1;
        while(valor <= 10) {  //condição para sair do laço
            for (int i=0; i<=10;i++) {
                System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor*i));
            }
            valor ++;
            System.out.println("\t");
        }
    } else if (option == 2) {//Caso seja 2
            System.out.printf("\nQual tabuada você prescisa saber?\n"
                    + "\nEssa é a tabuada do =>");
            int valor = ler.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(valor + " X " + i + " = " + (valor * i));        
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ele pula linha porque `System.out.println` sempre insere uma quebra de linha no final. Se não quer que pule de linha, use `System.out.print`, como eu fiz [aqui](https://ideone.com/mNjTkt) <<< repare também que o `\t` deve ficar dentro do laço mais interno, e não fora como vc fez. De qualquer forma, a ideia do site não é ficar colocando códigos para discussão ou avaliação. Aqui vc coloca um problema específico e as pessoas respondem (como fizemos acima). Se vc tem outra dúvida - mesmo que relacionada - então é o caso de [fazer outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)

Comment: Se bem que nesse caso, acho que o link que passei (https://ideone.com/mNjTkt) já resolve o seu problema, então não precisaria fazer uma nova pergunta...