# Por que acha o valor maior?

Tags: python, algoritmo

```
x=0

quantos=0

valor=int(input())

while valor>0:

    if valor>x:

        x=valor #Se aqui ele define o X pro valor inserido, por que ele armazena o maior número?
                #não deveria armazenar o último? 
        quantos=1

    elif valor==x:

        quantos+=1

    valor=int(input())

print('X=', x, 'quantos = ', quantos)
```

Não entendi como o x armazena sempre o número maior. Se eu der input 1, 5, 3, x printa 5, se der 1, 3, 5, printa 5 também...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele não armazena o maior magicamente, isto é um algoritmo, então há vários passos sendo executados com uma coleção de dados que vai sendo entrada.

Em um passo desses ele vai analisar se o que foi digitado é maior que `x`, então se for, nesse momento o que foi digitado é o maior valor, e dentro do `if` ele diz então que `x` é esse valor que foi digitado. A primeira vez qualquer número que foi digitado será maior que `x` porque essa variável vale 0 e só entra no laço se o que foi digitado é maior que 0.

Aí ele vai executar mais uma vez a mesma coisa, essa é a função do `while`. E novamente terá que verificar se o novo valor digitado é maior que `x`, que desta vez vale o valor anteriormente digitado. Mais uma vez só entrará no `if` se foi digitado um valor maior, e aí o `x` passaria ter um novo valor. Se não for uma valor maior ele ignora esse dado (na verdade se for igual tem algo a fazer ali no `elif`, mas isso não é o foco da pergunta).

E ele vai fazendo isso até que seja digitado 0 ou valor negativo. Então o valor de `x` será o último maior valor digitado, não importa se ele foi digitado por último, porque se você digitar valores menores depois de digitar um maior nunca entrará no `if` e não mudará o valor de `x`.

O segredo é o `if` que determina quando o valor de `x` será mudado ou não. E junto reinicia a quantidade de número repetidos sem interrupção tiveram pela última vez. Ele não guarda todos repetidos ou as outras vezes que ocorrem inclusive o maior e quantos foram repetidos não tem relação alguma, por isso não sei se era para acontecer isso ou é erro do algoritmo.

Eu aconselho aprender e fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101) e/ou aplicar a execução usando um sistema de *debug* para ver os dados sendo mudados passo a passo.

Eu acho que `x` é um nome ruim para o que essa variável faz e prejudica o entendimento. Ainda que o exercício fale em `x`, seria um nome melhor para entender o algoritmo.

Eu odeio ter que fazer a leitura de dados em dois lugares diferentes e acho mais legível fazer cada coisa na ordem certa, não parece ser um código tão *clever*, não estou dizendo que é necessariamente melhor, mas acho mais fácil de entender assim:

```
maior = 0
quantos = 0
while True:
    valor = int(input())
    if valor < 1:
        break
    if valor > maior:
        maior = valor
        quantos = 1
    elif valor == maior:
        quantos += 1
print('X =', maior, 'quantos = ', quantos)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZzGPlw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Greatestpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Greatest.py).

Note que eu preferi colocar uma condição de fim do laço dentro dele, logo depois que digita um número ele decide se é para continuar ou quebrar (`break`) o laço.

preferi não fazer a validação de dados digitados, mas se digitar algo que não seja um número quebrará a aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

Repare que `x = valor` está dentro do `if`. Ou seja, `x` só recebe o `valor` **se** o `valor` for maior que `x` (ou seja, se `valor` foi maior do que o maior número encontrado até agora, `x` passa a ser esse maior).

Então se você digita 1, 5 e 3, nessa ordem:

- `x` começa com valor zero
- quando `valor` for `1`, é maior que `x` (que é zero), então entra no `if` e `x` passa a ser `1`
- quando `valor` for `5`, é maior que `x` (que agora é `1`), então entra no `if` e `x` passa a ser `5`
- quando `valor` for `3`, **não** é maior que `x` (que agora é `5`), então não entra no `if` e `x` continua sendo `5`

Repare que `x` sempre contém "o maior valor lido até o momento". E quando o *loop* terminar, ele terá o maior valor lido dentre todos os que foram lidos.

---

Vale lembrar que só funciona com números positivos, já que `x` começa em zero. Se quiser algo mais genérico, que aceite também números negativos, basta fazer com que `x` comece com "menos infinito", assim qualquer número digitado será maior que ele:

```
x = float('-inf')
qtd = 0
while True:
    try:
        valor = int(input())
        if valor > x:
            x = valor
            qtd = 1
        elif valor == x:
            qtd += 1
    except ValueError:
        break # sai do loop

print(f'O maior valor é {x}, e ocorre {qtd} vezes')
```

Nesse caso estou interrompendo o `while` quando for digitado qualquer coisa que não seja número (podendo ser "nada" - somente um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), ou um texto qualquer, como "abc". Mas você pode colocar o critério de parada que quiser.

---

Aprenda a fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) e a [debugar o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052), vai te ajudar muito a entender qualquer código.