# Números Primos com While e For

Tags: python, algoritmo

Não entendi como um comando encontra os valores primos:

```
for i in range(2,30):
    j = 2
    counter = 0
    while j < i:
        if i % j == 0:
            counter = 1
            j = j + 1
        else:
            j = j + 1

    if counter == 0:
        print(str(i) + " é um número primo")
        counter = 0
    else:
        counter = 0
```

Resultado:

```
2 é um número primo
3 é um número primo
5 é um número primo
7 é um número primo
11 é um número primo
13 é um número primo
17 é um número primo
19 é um número primo
23 é um número primo
29 é um número primo
```

Existe alguma forma para eu ver o código funcionando passo a passo (ver as váriáveis assumindo os valores) para que eu possa entender como o código se comporta?

Até o número 3 eu acredito que entendi como é feito, mas no número 4 não. Se o `j` na execução anterior assumiu o valor de 3 o contador não iria mudar e o número 4 seria considerado primo?

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre os comandos do Python ou é uma dúvida de matemática sobre o que são números primos? Especificamente sobre o ponto (2): 4%2 resulta em zero (o resto da divisão de 4 por 2 dá 2 com resto 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ver o código funcionando passo a passo, [use um *debugger*](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+debugger)  neste link tem várias opções, escolha um e use (se estiver usando IDE's, como o PyCharm por exemplo: [elas já costumam vir com um *debugger*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html)). Como é um código relativamente pequeno, você também pode fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), além de seguir [estas dicas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052).

---

O que acontece quando `i` é igual a 4?

- `j` recebe o valor `2` e `counter` recebe o valor `0`
- entra no `while j < i`
- `if i % j == 0`: a operação `i % j` neste caso é `4 % 2` (o resto da divisão de 4 por 2), que é zero, então entra no `if`
- dentro do `if`, `counter` recebe o valor `1` e `j` é incrementado para 3
- continua executando o `while`
- agora `i % j` é `4 % 3`, que é `1`, então entra no `else`, que incrementa `j` para 4
- como `j` e `i` valem 4, `j` não é menor que `i`, então encerra o `while`
- `counter` vale 1 então não entra no `if counter == 0`. Ele entra no `else`, que só zera o `counter`

Basicamente, se o número `i` não for primo, uma hora vai entrar no primeiro `if` (pois haverá algum valor de `j` para o qual o resto da divisão será zero) e mudará o valor de `counter` para 1 (indicando que não é primo). E depois que o `while` terminar, não entrará no segundo `if` e portanto não imprimirá a mensagem de que o número é primo.

E se `i` for um número primo, nunca entra no primeiro `if` (pois o resto da divisão nunca será zero), então `counter` será zero e entrará no segundo `if`.

---

Mas sinceramente, o código está meio redundante. Por exemplo, dentro do `while`, o `j` sempre é incrementando (tanto dentro do `if` quanto no `else`), então na verdade o incremento é algo que sempre é executado, independente do caso. Sendo assim, ele poderia ser executado apenas uma vez, fora do `if`/`else`.

No segundo `if`, a mesma coisa: `counter` é setado para zero em ambos os casos. Mas nesse caso é mais redundante ainda, porque sempre zeramos o `counter` antes do `while`, então zerar o `counter` ali é desnecessário. E na verdade, como `counter` é uma variável que indica apenas uma condição "sim" ou "não" (é primo ou não é), ela poderia muito bem ser um *booleano*.

Enfim, uma alternativa um pouco melhor seria:

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    j = 2
    primo = True
    while j < i:
        if i % j == 0:
            primo = False
            break
        j = j + 1

    if primo:
        print(f"{i} é um número primo")
```

Ou ainda:

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    primo = True
    for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1): # só preciso ir até a metade do número
        if i % j == 0:
            primo = False
            break

    if primo:
        print(f"{i} é um número primo")
```

Repare que usei `break`, que serve para interromper o *loop* (pois se eu já descobri que o número não é primo, não preciso continuar testando, posso parar ali mesmo). Também mudei o nome da variável, pois `counter` dá a entender que é um contador, mas a variável não está contando nada, ela só serve para indicar se o número é primo ou não. E no segundo exemplo, fiz o *loop* até a metade de `i`, pois [não precisa ir até `i`](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2800656).

Na verdade, dá para fazer assim também:

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(f"{i} é um número primo")
```

Sim, em Python [um *loop* pode ter um bloco `else` associado](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), que só é executado se o *loop* não foi interrompido por um `break`.

Claro que dá para melhorar mais: com exceção do 2, todos os outros números primos são ímpares, então não preciso testar todos os números; e em vez de ir até a metade do número (como feito no segundo exemplo), posso ir até a raiz quadrada do mesmo que já é suficiente, etc, mas aí já foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta ([se pesquisar](https://www.google.com/search?q=prime%20number%20algorithm), vai encontrar muitos algoritmos mais eficientes para determinar se um número é primo).

Comment: Muito Obrigada. Sua explicação foi crucial para que eu entendesse o código!

Answer (score -2):

Eu resolvi uma tarefa parecida com essa usando estrutura while, veja:

````
div=2
cont=0
resto=1
while resto!=0:
    if numero<2:
        resto=0
        break
    resto=numero%div
    cont+=1
    div=(2*cont)+1
    if div==numero:
        break
if resto==0 and numero!=2:
    print("Nao e primo")
else:
    print("E numero primo")```
````

Comment: A dúvida é *...como um comando encontra os valores primos...* ela não pediu outro código, ela quer entender como o programa apresentado por ela funciona.