# Associando posições com elementos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Faça um programa que leia duas listas com 10 elementos cada e calcule outra lista contendo, nas posições pares os valores do primeiro e nas posições ímpares os valores do segundo.

Por favor me ajudem estou tendo dificuldade pra implementar o código.

```
a = []
b = []
c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

print('Lendo o vetor A: ')
for i in range(10):
    a.append(int(input(f'Digite o {i + 1}° valor: ')))
print('\nLendo o vetor B: ')
for j in range(10):
    b.append(int(input(f'Digite o {j + 1}° valor: ')))

for k in range(len(c)):
    for n1, n2 in zip(a, b):
        if k % 2 == 0:
            c[k] = n1
        if k % 2 != 0:
            c[k] = n2
print(c)
```

Comment: Por que fazer `for n1, n2 in zip(a, b)`?

Comment: Vi que vc desmarcou a minha resposta abaixo. Faltou alguma coisa nela?

Answer (score 3):

Para entender o que aconteceu no seu código, uma dica seria fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052). Mas basicamente, o problema é que você fez um *loop* dentro de outro. Ou seja, para cada índice `k`, você faz outro *loop* pelas listas `a` e `b`, atualizando os índices e sobrescrevendo o valor que vai na posição `k`.

Por exemplo, na primeira iteração, quando `k` é igual a zero:

- você faz um `for` por `a` e `b`:

  - como `k` é par, ele recebe o primeiro elemento de `a`
  - na próxima iteração, o índice `k` recebe o segundo elemento de `a`
  - na próxima iteração, o índice `k` recebe o terceiro elemento de `a`
  - e assim por diante, até o último elemento de `a`

Na próxima iteração do `for` externo, `k` será igual a 1, e portanto ímpar. Sendo assim, o índice `k` receberá o primeiro elemento de `b`, depois o segundo, etc, até receber o último.

No fim, todas as posições pares de `c` terão o último elemento de `a` e todas as posições ímpares terão o último elemento de `b`.

---

Em Python, listas são dinâmicas e você pode ir acrescentando elementos à medida em que for necessário. Não precisa criar uma lista `c` com 20 elementos só para ter os índices. Você só precisa percorrer `a` e `b` e ir adicionando os elementos em `c`:

```
c = []
for n1, n2 in zip(a, b):
    c.append(n1)
    c.append(n2)
```

Só isso. A lista `c` começa vazia, e a cada iteração eu adiciono um elemento de `a` e outro de `b` - o primeiro elemento inserido estará no índice zero e o segundo no índice 1. Depois, na iteração seguinte, o terceiro elemento estará no índice 2 e o quarto no índice 3, e assim por diante. Nem preciso ficar testando os índices.

Vale lembrar que ao iterar com [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), o *loop* só vai até a menor das listas terminar. Mas como nesse caso ambas têm o mesmo tamanho, não há essa preocupação.

Outra alternativa é pegar a tupla retornada por `zip` e inserir ambos de uma vez:

```
c = []
for values in zip(a, b):
    c.extend(values)
```

---

Outra forma de fazer é usar o módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), juntamente com uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
from itertools import chain
c = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
```

Se eu fizesse apenas `c = list(zip(a, b))`, seria criada uma lista de tuplas, mas usando [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) eu garanto que cada elemento de cada uma das tuplas será um elemento da lista.

---

Se quer **mesmo** criar a lista `c` com o tamanho final e usar os índices (embora as alternativas acima sejam mais [*pythônicas*](/q/192343/112052)), uma solução seria:

```
# cria a lista com o tamanho de a + tamanho de b
c = [ '' ] * (len(a) + len(b))

for i in range(len(c)):
    # os índices de a e b correspondem à metade do respectivo índice de c
    if i % 2 == 0:
        c[i] = a[i // 2]
    else:
        c[i] = b[(i - 1) // 2]
```

Mas como já disse, eu acho desnecessário criar uma lista com vários valores que serão descartados em seguida, só para tê-la com o tamanho certo e poder iterar pelos índices. As soluções acima que inserem os elementos à medida em que são percorridos me parecem bem mais simples.

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava pensando muito na linguagem C na hora de fazer esse problema. Não sabia que em python as listas eram dinâmicas. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Opa, beleza?

Fui brincar aqui e fiz esse código:

Sou novato no Python também.

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []

print('Lendo o vetor A: ')
for i in range(10):
    a.append(int(input(f'Digite o {i + 1}° valor: ')))
print('\nLendo o vetor B: ')
for j in range(10):
    b.append(int(input(f'Digite o {j + 1}° valor: ')))

c = zip(a,b)
for item, item2 in c:
    d.append(item)
    d.append(item2)
print(d)
```

Agora ele imprime os valores que você quer.

Espero ter ajudado!