# Como faço para dar um merge em dois array, porém alternando eles. (python)

Tags: python, array

array0 = [1,2,3]
array1 = ['a','b','c']

tendo os dois arrays acima, como retorno esse valor que está em baixo?

//[1,'a',2,'b',3,'c']

Comment: Apesar do título da pergunta sugerida acima como duplicada ser diferente, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/457014/112052) que tem lá serve para o seu caso também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira é inicializar o array resultado como vazio e dar um append alternado de cada elemento dos arrays iniciais.

```
array0 = [1,2,3]
array1 = ['a','b','c']
array2 = []
for i in range(3):
    array2.append(array0[i])
    array2.append(array1[i])
print(array2)
```

Note que esta solução não trata arrays de tamanhos diferentes.