# Checar se existe um valor especifico dentro de um array bi dimensional java

Tags: java, array

Preciso checar se existe um valor específico no caso o valor 1 dentro de um array bi dimensional para
o código retornar se um valor é verdadeiro ou falso. O código que eu utilizei foi o seguinte :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                            if (tabelaUser[i][j] == 1) {
                                ganhador2 = false;

                            } else {
                                ganhador2 = true;

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

porém não funcionou, imagino que minha lógica esteja errada porém não sei como resolver

Comment: especifique melhor o que está querendo encontrar, primitivo, objeto... qual tipo?

Answer (score 0):

o que você está fazendo de errado é usar esse `else`. E vou te mostrar porque.

Suponhamos que sua array toda tem 3 números `1`  `0`  `1`, quando o `for` passar pela primeira posição do array, ele vai verificar que aquele não é o ganhador, pois o número ali é 1, na segunda posição ele já determina que aquele é o ganhador pois o valor nessa posição é 0, contudo na terceira posição ele determina que aquele não é o ganhador pois o valor na última posição é 1.

Observe a representação deste fluxo na variável ganhador 2: `false` -> `true` (é o ganhador) -> `false`

A solução para isso é retirar o `else` e inicializar sua variável como `true`,
caso o `for` encontrar o valor `1` ela terá seu valor trocado.

Seu código deverá ficar assim:

```
 boolean ganhador2 = true;

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          if (tabelaUser[i][j] == 1) {
              ganhador2 = false;
          }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta lógica está errada (sugiro que faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), ficará claro o que está errado).

Basicamente, você percorre (acredito eu) todos os elementos, e se for igual a 1, seta a variável `ganhador2` para `false`, e se for diferente, seta para `true`.

Então na verdade o que importa é o valor do último elemento encontrado. Se o último for 1, a variável será `false`, senão ela será `true`, **independente de todos os outros valores que verificou antes**.

Se está buscando por um elemento, você começa indicando que não encontrou, e só muda esta indicação caso encontre. Em linhas gerais, seria algo como:

```
boolean encontrou = false; // antes do loop eu ainda não encontrei o elemento
for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    if (elementos[i] == valorQueEstouProcurando) {
        encontrou = true;
        break; // encontrei, posso parar de procurar
    }
}
```

Ou seja, se encontrei o elemento, eu indico que encontrei (mudo o valor da *flag*) e posso até interromper o *loop* com `break` (pois se já encontrei, não faz sentido continuar procurando).

Mas no seu caso há dois *loops* aninhados, e o `break` por padrão interrompe o mais interno, então se quiser interromper o `for` externo basta usar um *label*:

```
boolean ganhador2 = true;
busca: for (int i = 0; i < tabelaUser.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tabelaUser[i].length; j++) {
        if (tabelaUser[i][j] == 1) {
            ganhador2 = false;
            break busca; // encontrei, interrompe a busca
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que usei `length` em vez de um valor fixo como `10`. Assim o código funciona para arrays de qualquer tamanho.

E se você só quer percorrer os valores, não precisa iterar pelos índices, pode fazer assim (assumindo que `tabelaUser` seja um `int[][]`):

```
boolean ganhador2 = true;
busca: for (int[] linha: tabelaUser) {
    for (int n: linha) {
        if (n == 1) {
            ganhador2 = false;
            break busca; // encontrei, interrompe a busca
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Aqui está um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito:

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
int value = 5;

boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if (array[i][j] == value) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (found) {
  System.out.println("O valor foi encontrado no array.");
} else {
  System.out.println("O valor não foi encontrado no array.");
}
```