# ajuda em ex de python!

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

travei em um exercício. no código precisa ter um número n entre 0 e 100 e nas próximas linhas uma variavel representando quanto de dinheiro cada um tem e ser imprimido a quantia mínima pra que cada um tenha 2000. ex de entrada: 2,999, 1050; saída: 1001, 950. 2, 0, 2000;saída: 2000. 1, 900; saída: 1100.
eu consigo fazer ele retornar a saída mas apenas um. tipo:
não consigo descobrir o erro, se puderem me ajudar...

```
n = 0
q = 0
d = 0
while 0 <= n <= 100:
    n = int(input())
    while d<2000:
        d = int(input())
        q = 2000-d
        break
print(f'{q}')
```

Comment: E qual o significado deste número `n` que você lê logo de cara? Note que você lê e esquece, não usa para nada.

Comment: o n é o número de pessoas, se o n for igual a dois o d deveria receber dois valores, mas não consegui, só consegui fazer ele devolver 1

Comment: Olá, @Luiza. O problema é apenas lógica: 1 - você quer ler os valores de d antes de efetuar o calculo; 2 - escrever a resposta... Vou arrumar aqui.

Comment: Este post é relevante para problemas deste tipo: [O que é o Teste de Mesa? Como aplicar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações para arrumar a lógica. Existem muitas maneiras de fazer, optei pela mais simples.

```
arr_valores = []
arr_falta = []

# essa varíavel só interfere no if
# para impedir a leitura que mais de 100 valores
n = int(input("Numero de pessoas: "))  # lendo o número de pessoas
if 0 <= n <= 100:
    # lendo os valores
    for _ in range(n):
        arr_valores.append(int(input("valor: ")))
    
    # fazendo o processamento
    for i in range(n):
        arr_falta.append(2000 - arr_valores[i])
    
    # escrevendo o resultado
    for i in range(n):
        print(f'pessoa {i} falta {arr_falta[i]} para 2000')
```

Comment: muito obrigada!!