# Porque o "0" não aparece? Uma vez que a lógica do "do while" é: faça-se depois verifica-se

Tags: php, lógica, do-while

Se você analisar literalmente o laço `do while`, faz todo sentido já que se faz algo enquanto isto é verdadeiro, mas pragmaticamente não tem lógica.

Por exemplo, no código abaixo, ao chegarmos no valor `1` (lembrando que ele entra a partir do `9` no `do while` então não sei por que tem um `10` ali) ele imprime dentro do laço e verifica se ele (`1`) é maior que `0`, o que de fato é, e se de fato é, deveria ser impresso o `0` logo em seguida, já que a condição foi atendida anteriormente e depois logicamente deveria se encerrar o laço já que `0` não é maior que `0`.

```
<?php
    $valor1 = 10;

    do {
        echo 'O valor ' . $valor1-- . ' é maior que 0';
        echo '<br>';
    } while ($valor1 > 0);

    echo 'fim do script';
?>
```

Resultado:

```
O valor 10 é maior que 0
O valor 9 é maior que 0
O valor 8 é maior que 0
O valor 7 é maior que 0
O valor 6 é maior que 0
O valor 5 é maior que 0
O valor 4 é maior que 0
O valor 3 é maior que 0
O valor 2 é maior que 0
O valor 1 é maior que 0
fim do script
```

Comment: Porque 0 não é maior que 0, aí a condição avalia para falso. Zero é igual a zero. Portanto, você deve utilizar o operador maior ou igual que (`>=`).

Comment: sim mas o do executa antes de avaliar essa condição. Ele primeiro imprime o valor 0 para depois verificá-lo e ao verificar ele vai dar falso nesse caso, correto, mas ele já imprimiu antes, pelo menos era isso o esperado. A não ser que o do seja anulado se o while verificar falso mas aí a estrutura não seria ela mesma seria um simples while

Comment: Não estou nem entrando no mérito resultado, tlgd que isso é o esperado, mas... ainda sim não faz sentido praticamente só teoricamente. Mas enfim, vou deixar essa passar rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo o equivoco se dá nessa premissa:

> ... (*lembrando que ele entra a partir do 9 no `do while`* então não sei porque tem um 10 ali...

Errado, a variável `$valor` entra no laço do-wile valendo `10` e então:

- é impressa.
- subtraída de 1.
- comparada com 0...

  - Se `$valor` for maior que `0` reitera.
  - Se `$valor` não for maior que `0` abandona o laço de iteração.

Isso porque o [operador de decremento](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.increment.php#language.operators.increment) que usa, `$valor--`, é conhecido como operador Pós-decremento que é regido por essa tabela:

| Exemplo | Nome | Efeito |
| --- | --- | --- |
| --$a | Pré-decremento | Decrementa $a em um, e então retorna $a. |
| $a-- | Pós-decremento | Retorna $a, e então decrementa $a em um. |

Ou seja primeiro será impresso o conteúdo da variável `$valor` e só então após a impressão `$valor` será decrementado.

Com essas informações o equivoco pode ser facilmente desfeito através de um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo).
Para o teste será utilizado uma simplificação do seu código:

```
<?php

$valor = 10;   

do{
    //Aqui é aplicado em $valor o operador de pós-incremento ou seja 
    //primeiro é obtido o valor da variável e só então que é decrementada.
    echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;
    
} while($valor > 0);

echo 'finalizado';
```

Onde no teste:

- A coluna **código** mostra o código que está sendo executado.
- A coluna **$valor antes** mostra o conteúdo da variável `valor` antes do código ser executado.
- A coluna **$valor após** mostra o conteúdo da variável `valor` após o código ser executado.
- A coluna **stdout** mostra o que foi impresso na saída padrão após o código ser executado.

| código | $valor antes | $valor após | stdout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<?php` | - | - | - |
| `$valor = 10;` | - | 10 | - |
| `do{` | 10 | 10 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 10 | 9 | o valor 10 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 9 | 9 | - |
| `do{` | 9 | 9 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 9 | 8 | o valor 9 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 8 | 8 | - |
| `do{` | 8 | 8 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 8 | 7 | o valor 8 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 7 | 7 | - |
| `do{` | 7 | 7 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 7 | 6 | o valor 7 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 6 | 6 | - |
| `do{` | 6 | 6 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 6 | 5 | o valor 6 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 5 | 5 | - |
| `do{` | 5 | 5 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 5 | 4 | o valor 5 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 4 | 4 | - |
| `do{` | 4 | 4 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 4 | 3 | o valor 4 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 3 | 3 | - |
| `do{` | 3 | 3 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 3 | 2 | o valor 3 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 2 | 2 | - |
| `do{` | 2 | 2 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 2 | 1 | o valor 2 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 1 | 1 | - |
| `do{` | 1 | 1 | - |
| `echo 'o valor '. $valor-- .' é maior que O.'.PHP_EOL;` | 1 | 0 | o valor 1 é maior que 0. |
| `} while($valor > 0);` | 0 | 0 | - |
| `echo 'finalizado';` | 0 | 0 | finalizado |

Answer (score 1):

Você está confundindo alguns conceitos do `while` e `do while`, bem como do incrementador "i++" (e "i--").

> lembrando que ele entra a paritir do 9 no "do while" então não sei porque tem um 10 ali kk

É atribuído o valor `10` a `$valor1`, portanto, ao entrar no `do`, o valor dessa variável `É MESMO 10`.

Ao chegar no `1`, já foram impressos os valores 10 a 2. Isso porque, ao fazer `$valor1--`, antes é feita a "avaliação" e depois o decremento. Sendo assim, na 1a iteração é impresso o valor `10` e em seguida decrementa-se e faz-se `while(9 > 0)`.

Portanto, a iteração iniciada por `1`, ainda vai imprimir `1`, decrementar a variável e usar `0` na comparação do while.