# Encontrar e alterar dicionário específico em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Tenho que realizar uma busca dentro de uma lista com dicionários dentro, procurando pelo CPF específico da pessoa, para confirmar seus dados, e assim, alterar algum item específico do dicionário.
Minha lista é:

```
cadastro_mec = [
    {'CPF': '123.456.789-10', 'Nome': 'Guilherme Flavio', 'Data de Nascimento': '01/04/1989', 'Salário': 'R$1045.0',
     'E-mail': 'gui_flavio0104@bol.com', 'Telefone': '(19) 89765-4326'},
    {'CPF': '123.456.789-11', 'Nome': 'Marco Machado', 'Data de Nascimento': '09/11/1990', 'Salário': 'R$1648.0',
     'E-mail': 'marquinho_preyboy@yahoo.com.br', 'Telefone': '(11) 3665-4899'}]
```

O código que eu fiz até agora foi:

```
for dic in lista:
        for cont, (key, value) in enumerate(dic.items()):
            if confirmar_cpf == value:
                print(f'{cont} -> {key}: {value}') #Aqui eu queria mostrar todos os dados do dicionário, para que o usuário possa escolher qual dado ele deseja alterar especificamente
                break
            else:
                print('CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO!')
                break
```

Porém, ao executar o código, eu recebo isso:

```
CPF: 12345678910 #input
123.456.789-10
0 -> CPF: 123.456.789-10
CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO!
```

Eu recebo a mensagem de que o CPF não foi encontrado, sendo que o mesmo está em um dos dicionários.
Além de que, não é mostrado todas as keys e values do dicionário específico.

Answer (score 3):

Para entender porque seu código não funciona, bastaria fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), mas de qualquer forma, vamos entender o que acontece.

Os `break`'s que você colocou interrompem o `for` mais interno (o que está iterando pelas chaves do dicionário), então o `for` mais externo vai continuar iterando por todos os dicionários. Ou seja:

```
for dic in lista: # primeiro for
    for cont, (key, value) in enumerate(dic.items()): # segundo for
        if confirmar_cpf == value:
            print(f'{cont} -> {key}: {value}')
            break # este break interrompe o segundo for
        else:
            print('CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO!')
            break  # este break interrompe o segundo for
```

Ou seja, na primeira iteração do primeiro `for`, a variável `dic` será o dicionário que contém o CPF `123.456.789-10`. Então ele entra no segundo `for`, iterando pelas chaves deste, e encontra o CPF (ou seja, entra no `if`, imprime o CPF e o `break` interrompe o segundo `for`, então ele para de iterar pelas chaves do dicionário).

Mas o `break` só interrompeu o *loop* interno, porém o *loop* externo não, então ele continua iterando pela lista. Aí na segunda iteração `dic` será o dicionário que contém o CPF `123.456.789-11`. O segundo `for` itera pelas chaves deste, na primeira iteração vê que o valor não é igual ao CPF sendo buscado e entra no `else`, imprimindo a mensagem de "CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO" e o `break` interrompe o `for` interno.

E como a lista só tem 2 elementos, o `for` externo se encerra.

---

Se a ideia é comparar uma chave específica, não precisa iterar por todas, basta acessá-la diretamente (no caso, seria  `dic['CPF']` para acessar o valor do CPF diretamente). E só se o CPF for encontrado, aí sim você itera pelas chaves deste:

```
cadastro_mec = [
    {'CPF': '123.456.789-10', 'Nome': 'Guilherme Flavio', 'Data de Nascimento': '01/04/1989', 'Salário': 'R$1045.0',
     'E-mail': 'gui_flavio0104@bol.com', 'Telefone': '(19) 89765-4326'},
    {'CPF': '123.456.789-11', 'Nome': 'Marco Machado', 'Data de Nascimento': '09/11/1990', 'Salário': 'R$1648.0',
     'E-mail': 'marquinho_preyboy@yahoo.com.br', 'Telefone': '(11) 3665-4899'}]

confirmar_cpf = '123.456.789-10'

for dic in cadastro_mec:
    if confirmar_cpf == dic['CPF']: # acessar o CPF diretamente
        # se encontrou o CPF, aí sim imprime todas as chaves do dicionário
        for cont, (key, value) in enumerate(dic.items()):
            print(f'{cont} -> {key}: {value}')
        break # interrompe o for externo
else:
    print('CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO!')
```

Repare que só se o CPF for encontrado, eu faço o outro `for` que itera pelas chaves do dicionário. E dentro do `if` tem o `break`, que neste caso interrompe o `for` externo (pois se eu já encontrei o CPF, não preciso mais iterar pelo restante da lista).

E o `else` é do `for`, e não do `if` (sim, [em Python isso é possível](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)). No caso, ele entra no `else` se o `for` **não** for interrompido por um `break`. E como eu só uso `break` se encontrar o CPF, então ele só entra no `else` se o CPF não for encontrado.

Answer (score 3):

Se a lista de cadastros é uma lista curta e apenas uma busca sendo feita nessa lista as outras soluções em  tempo linear, onde os códigos iteram todos os dados a cada consulta, resolvem o seu problema.

Porém caso a lista seja longa, por exemplo uma lista contendo um milhão de cadastros e caso haja a necessidade de sucessivas buscas tornariam uma solução em tempo linear, *O(n)*, impraticável pois a cada consulta essa lista será percorrida item por item os testando até encontrar aquele cujo a chave `CPF` seja igual ao valor procurado tornando o processo pouco eficiente com relação ao tempo de processamento.

Uma possibilidade de realizar buscas mais performática em dados robustos é criando um [índice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) que é um artifício que melhora a velocidade das operações de recuperação na fonte de dados ao custo do espaço gravação em memória de uma segunda estrutura de dados projetada para minimizar o tempo de acesso aos dados.

Em *Python* uma maneira simples de criar índices para uma lista de dicionários cuja as chaves os valores sejam únicos(não se repetem) e que sejam [hasheáveis](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) é utilizando uma [tabela de dispersão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) que é é uma estrutura de dados, que associa chaves de pesquisa a valores em [tempo constante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo#Tabela_de_complexidade_de_tempo_comum). Em *Python* a tabela de dispersão é implementada como um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Exemplo:

```
cadastro_mec = []                #Lista que armazenará os cadastros.
indice_cpf = {}                  #Dicionário que funcionará como índice para cadastro_mec 
     
print("Aguarde o carregamento dos dados...")
# Gera um milhão de cadastros de teste na memória com CPFs(fakes) variando de 000.000.000-00 até 000.009.999-99
for r in range(1000000):
    cpf = f'{r:011d}'
    cpf = f'{cpf[0:3]}.{cpf[3:6]}.{cpf[6:9]}-{cpf[-2:]}'
    novo = {'CPF': cpf, 'Nome': 'xxxxx xxxx', 'Data de Nascimento': '01/01/1900', 'Salário': 'R$0.0',
     'E-mail': 'xxx@xxx.com', 'Telefone': '(xx) xxxxxxx'}
    cadastro_mec.append(novo)     #Adiciona a lista cadastro_mec a referência a um novo cadastro.
    indice_cpf[cpf] = novo        #Indexa, na chave cujo é numero do cpf, a referência ao cadastro recém criado.

while True:
    confirmar_cpf = input('Digite um CPF para pesquisa ou enter para sair: ' )
    if confirmar_cpf == "": break
    #Testa se o dicionario indice_cpf contém a chave inserida pelo usuário...
    if confirmar_cpf in indice_cpf:
        print(indice_cpf[confirmar_cpf])     #Se a chave existir imprime o seu valor.
        #indice_cpf[confirmar_cpf]['Nome'] = `Ultimo bom nome` #<-- Exemplo prático de como mudar os valores no cadastro referenciado por meio do índice.
    else: 
        print('CPF não cadastrado.')         #Se a chave existir emite um aviso.
```

O algoritmo acima funciona inicialmente definindo as estruturas de dados `cadastro_mec` que é a lista que conterá os cadastros e `indice_cpf` que será o índice para os dados armazenados em `cadastro_mec`.
Depois cria um milhão de registros de teste(fakes) e a cada elemento criado o indexa.

Inicializa um loop de duração indeterminada, onde o usuário insere o número de um CPF e em tempo constante, *O(1)*, é verificado no índice sua existência e imprimindo o cadastro caso esse seja localizado.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa do loop `for` mais interno. Aqui está uma solução mais simples:

```
cadastro_mec = [
{'CPF': '123.456.789-10', 'Nome': 'Guilherme Flavio', 'Data de Nascimento': '01/04/1989', 'Salário': 'R$1045.0',
 'E-mail': 'gui_flavio0104@bol.com', 'Telefone': '(19) 89765-4326'},
{'CPF': '123.456.789-11', 'Nome': 'Marco Machado', 'Data de Nascimento': '09/11/1990', 'Salário': 'R$1648.0',
 'E-mail': 'marquinho_preyboy@yahoo.com.br', 'Telefone': '(11) 3665-4899'}]

for dic in cadastro_mec:
    if confirmar_cpf == dic["CPF"]:
        print(f'CPF: {dic["CPF"]}')
        break
else:
    print('CPF NÃO ENCONTRADO!')
```

O `for` tem uma clausula `else`. Se o loop for completamente percorrido a condição `else` do loop `for` é acionada