# Imprimir lista de numeros primso em um intervalo

Tags: python

Estou tendo problemas em criar um programa que peça ao usuário dois valores e imprima todos os primos nessa sequência (incluindo os números digitados)

Aqui vai o código:

```
number_range1=int(input('Digite o primeiro número do seu intervalo:'))
number_range2=int(input('Digite o segundo número do seu intervalo:'))

i=0
number=number_range1
numbers=[]

while i<=(number_range2-1):
    numbers.append(number)
    number=number+1
    i+=1

i=1
k=0
r=0
primes=[]
j=len(numbers)

while k<j:
    while i<=numbers[k]:
        d=numbers[k]%i
        if d==0:
            r+=1
        i+=1

    if r==1 or r==2:
        primes.append(numbers[k])
        
    k+=1

print(primes)
```

Comment: Da maneira que está, seu código dá erro de sintaxe na linha 4 devido ao `\`` que há no final dela. Tem certeza que é esse o código? A indentação está fiel ao seu código original?

Comment: a aspa deve ter sido um erro na postagem mas o código é esse mesmo =/

Comment: Ok, então recomendo que você tente fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) explicando o seu código, pois há muitos trechos que não fazem muito sentido e imagino que não ficou claro nem para você, então o teste de mesa irá te ajudar a entender o seu próprio código.

Comment: E busque responder coisas como "*por que se eu informar os valores 10 e 20, a variável `numbers` vai de 10 até 29?*"

Comment: muito obrigado Woss

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço muito Woss realizar um teste de mesa com as variáveis foi um aprendizado que vou levar para a vida ,consegui refazer o algoritmo e realmente como você disse muitas coisas não faziam sentido algum minha base lógica ainda é muito fraca aqui vai o resultado:

```
n=int(input())
c=int(input())

k=c-n+1

numbers=[]

for x in range(0,k):
    numbers.append(n)
    n+=1

primes=[]
for y in range(0,len(numbers)):
    i=1
    t=0
    while i<=numbers[y]:
        d=numbers[y]%i
        i+=1
        if d==0:
            t+=1
    
    if t==1 or t==2:
        primes.append(numbers[y])

print(primes)
```